# Print invisible text

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string as input, output a number of whitespace characters (0x0A and 0x20) equal to the length of the string.

For example, given the string `Hello, World!` your code would need to output exactly 13 whitespace characters and nothing else. These can be any mix of spaces and newlines.

Your code should not output any additional trailing newlines or spaces.

### Testcases:

```
     Input      -> Amount of whitespace to output
"Hello, World!" -> 13
"Hi"            -> 2
"   Don't
Forget about
Existing
Whitespace!   " -> 45
""              -> 0
"             " -> 13
"
"               -> 1
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes wins!

Comment: I don't get what you mean with that “0x0A”. Where should that be output? Should that be kept, so “a␠b␊c” becomes “␠␠␠␊␠”?

Comment: @manatwork `0x0A` and `0x20` are the hexadecimal values for the Newline and Space characters respectively

Comment: “output a number of whitespace characters (0x0A and 0x20)” – Where in the output should those newline characters be?

Comment: `These can be any mix of spaces and newlines`
Your output can be any mix of spaces and newlines, you can just output spaces if you want, like everyone else, or you can just output newlines. It's up to you

Comment: Can we assume the input will only have printable characters?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes you can.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106992/neutralize-data)

Comment: Can we replace existing line breaks with spaces or do we need to retain line breaks?

Comment: @ThomasWard you don't need to retain anything but the length of the input string

Comment: If we print the correct number of spaces, is a trailing newline acceptable (as this is how the language outputs)

Comment: ͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: This seems related to _[output with the same length as the code](/q/121056)_, the difference: There the input is static, here it is not static.

Comment: Isn't this answered in whitespace?

Answer (score 153):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>311</s> <s>150</s> <s>77</s> <s>68</s> <s>65</s> <s>46</s> <s>41</s> 38 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen</sup>
<sup>-27 bytes thanks to Ephphatha</sup>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#@8@loABECpxAyKUA5nByATmcIFKBixMswsX1/39JanEJl6GRMQA)

A visible format

```
'\n  \n   \t \t \n \n  \n \t\n\t \t\t\t\n\t  \n\t\n  \n \n\n'
```

Explanation (s = space, t = tab, n = new line)

```
nssn     # label(NULL) - loop start
ssststsn # push 10 in the stack -> [10]
sns      # duplicate the top of the stack -> [10, 10]
sns      # duplicate the top of the stack -> [10, 10, 10]
tnts     # read a single char from input, pop the stack and store at that address -> [10, 10] [10:<char that was read>]
ttt      # pop the stack and put the value at that adress on stack -> [10,<char>] [10:<char>]
ntssn    # jump to label(0) - since label(0) is not defined, the interpreter jumps to the end of the program - if the top of the stack (char) is 0 -> [10] [10:<char>]
tnss     # pop the top of the stack and print as ascii -> [] [10:<char>]
nsnn     # go back to the label(NULL)
```

Comment: Assuming this does actually work, this definitely wins my vote for most creative answer

Comment: Wait where is the answer? Is it invisible too?

Comment: WHAT BLACK MAGIC IS THIS. Your code is not even there! -1

Comment: @Christopher more like WHITEspace MAGIC

Comment: @Rod That was just a horrible pun.

Comment: I knew someone would answer this question with a whitespace program

Comment: This should be a meta.ppcg meme.

Comment: [You can remove the three ending newlines.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48464/52210)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I tried without, but it was crashing :c

Comment: @Rod Hmmm.. Probably depends on the compiler, as it stated in the tip-answer I've linked. I have used the TIO compiler for Whitespace in the past and there I was able to remove the three trailing new-lines. Btw, why did you state it doesn't work on TIO? Your test case of `1234` does output four spaces. ;) Hmm, your code [does work in TIO without the three trailing new-lines](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#JYvbDQBAEAG/qUIL9@i/NcdtJGRnsSSQNcWZhAAURzmG9KnSdPCLnJnstc99).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen indeed, I was too focuses on the Debug tab @.@

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#@6@goMAJhFxcQAYXEHJycYIYnJwgBidEBCIDUsLJ9f9/SWpxCVdicRoA) edit: can't add newlines in comments apparently. This pushes the value 10 (ascii newline) to the stack, duplicates the value to use as the heap address for reading input, checks input wasn't a null byte, duplicates the 10 and outputs a newline then loops to the first duplicate command

Comment: Turns out you can use a null label, that saves two bytes for 46 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#@6@goMAJhFxcQAYXEHJycYIYnJwgBkQAIgFSwfX/f0lqcQlXYnEaAA "Whitespace – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @Ephphatha wow, that's awesome

Comment: This is the first time I interact with this community, but... I absolutely had to upvote this...

Comment: Turns out the TIO interpreter handles jumping to an undefined label as jumping to the end of the program. This lets us drop one of the define label statements and after redefining the remaining jumps/labels it ends up saving 5 bytes for a total of 41 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#@6@goMAJhFxcCgpcQMjJxQlicHJCGSARMM31/39JanEJl6GRMQA "Whitespace – TIO Nexus")

Comment: There's actually no need to preseed the stack outside the loop. if we move the push after the label, we can just copy it as many times as needed for a full loop which removes one of the duplicates. [38 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#@8@loABECpxAyKUA5nByATmcIFKBixMswsX1/39JanEJl6GRMQA "Whitespace – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 61):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 byte

```
ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@394@f//Sh6pOTn5Ogrh@UU5KYpKAA)

Comment: Does japt seriously have a builtin for this? Damn...

Comment: @Mayube well it has a builtin to replace all characters in a string with another, and the default replacement is a space ;)

Comment: Very nice! For those running the program, you can add the `-Q` flag into the input to put quotes around the output. [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@394@f//Sh6pOTn5Ogrh@UU5KYpKuoEA)

Answer (score 40):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 7 bytes

```hs
(>>" ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgoqBhZ6ekoKSpoOSRmpOTr6MQnl@Uk6Ko9P8/AA) Usage: `(>>" ") "Hello, world!"`.

Given two lists (and strings are lists of characters in Haskell) the `>>` operator will repeat the second list as many times as the first list has elements. Setting `" "` as second argument means we concatenate as many spaces as the input string is long.

---

**Alternative** (same byte count):

```hs
(' '<$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgoqChrqBuo6KpoOSRmpOTr6MQnl@Uk6Ko9P8/AA) Usage: `(' '<$) "Hello, world!"`.

Given some value and a list, the `<$` operator replaces each value in the list with the given value. Thus `5 <$ "abc"` results in `[5,5,5]`, and `' ' <$ "abc"` in `"   "`.

The function can equivalently be written as  `(<$)' '`, in case you want to find some more marine creatures in my code.

Comment: Its like an adorable little finless fish

Comment: dang this blows my haskell answer out of the water haha

Answer (score 21):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 18 bytes

```
++++++++++>,[<.>,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw7sdKJt9Ox0Yv//90jNycnXUSjPL8pJUQQA)

Prints one newline for each byte of input.  Printing spaces instead would add 4 bytes.

Comment: For posterity: Mika Lammi posted a clever [16-byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122942/3852) that got buried. `,[>++++++++++.,]`

Answer (score 20):

## Python, 19 bytes

```py
lambda s:' '*len(s)
```

Answer (score 18):

## Brainfuck, 16 bytes

Prints newlines.

```
,[>++++++++++.,]
```

Answer (score 17):

## Retina, <s>3</s> 4 bytes

```
S\`.
```

Old version, doesn't work because Retina prints a trailing line feed.

```
.
```

(The second line contains a space).

Comment: The retina TIO is quite easy to use.  Here is [your answer](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6/HpfD/v0dqTk6@jkJ4flFOiiIA)

Comment: Unfortunately, Retina prints a trailing linefeed by default. You'll need to prepend `\\`` to avoid that. Then it's shorter to use `S\\`.` though, which replaces each character with a linefeed (because it splits the input around each character).

Comment: @MartinEnder Ahhh wasn't sure if that was  a Retina or TIO thing. Thanks for the help on saving a byte there though!

Answer (score 14):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 7 bytes

```
s/./ /g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@1@sr6evoJ/@/79Hak5Ovo5CeH5RTooiAA)

Answer (score 12):

## C#, <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```c#
s=>"".PadLeft(s.Length);
```

Old version using the `string` constructor for 28 bytes:

```c#
s=>new string(' ',s.Length);
```

Comment: Wanted to do exactly the same

Comment: @StefanDelport Gotta be quick with C# when I'm around :) There's Linq approaches to do the same but they're all a LOT longer...

Comment: Given adequate type context, couldn't this just be `s=>new(' ',s.Length)`?

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript ES6, 22 bytes

```
a=>a.replace(/./g," ")
```

```js
f=a=>a.replace(/./g," ");

var test = f("Hello, World!");
console.log(test, test.length);
```

Comment: Huh, I thought "oh darn, it'd have to be `s=>s.replace(/[^]/g," ")`, a byte longer than the other solution". It didn't occur to me that newlines are allowed in the output :P

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 5 bytes

```
\`.
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@ToMd1aNv//woKCi75eeolXG75RempJQqJSfmlJVyuFZnFJZl56VzhGZklqcUFicmpikCVAA) Changes everything into newlines. The `` \` `` suppresses the extra newline Retina would normally output.

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
StringReplace[_->" "]
```

Comment: If charlist input was allowed, this could be `#/._->" "&`. Sadly, the input is a string and Characters[] makes it one byte longer than your solution :(

Comment: Doesn't this need a `#` and a `&` in it? E.g. `StringReplace[#,_->" "]&`

Comment: @IanMiller Not in Mathematica 10.4 or 11. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html

Comment: Ah ok. I only have 10.3. Maybe time to upgrade...

Answer (score 8):

## C, 31 bytes

```
f(char*c){puts(""),*c++&&f(c);}
```

Comment: How does this differ from [your other C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122762/42561)? Clearly this one is shorter, but should you have simply edited the other one? Should it just be one answer with two solutions?

Comment: @Tas First of all, I guess in some sense I feel this is not as good as the other one eventhough it's shorter, because it doesn't actually compile as-is. It's just a function so you need to write some main routine around it. However, it _is_ shorter and others seems to post just functions. Clearly it's two very different solutions. One is not the refinement of the other, so to me it makes sense that it should be two different answers. However, I'm new to this community. Is the consensus that one user only posts one answer? If so I will do that next time.

Comment: Should the comma really be a comma and not a semicolon?

Comment: @OskarSkog well, in this case it doesn't matter that much because there is no lhs

Comment: @OskarSkog Yes, it should be a comma. As @cat says, it doesn't really matter in this case but I chose comma for variation :) The comma operator evaluates two expressions (e.g. `i++, j++` in a for loop) and returns the rightmost one. An important detail is that the recursion has to stop somehow. `&&` doesn't evaluate it's rhs if it's lhs is false. `*c++` evaluates false when it points to the null-termination of the string.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
vð?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@192eIP9//8eqTk5@ToK4flFOSmKAA)

```
v   # For each character...
 ð? #    Output a space without a newline
```

#### Other 3 byte solutions (Thanks [Magic Octopus Urn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/magic-octopus-urn) and [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for most of these)

```
v¶? # For each character print a newline (without adding a newline)
võ, # For each character print the empty string with a newline
gð× # Get the length, concatenate that many copies of space
g¶× # Get the length, concatenate that many copies of newline
Sð: # Split, push a space, replace each char in input with a space
ðs∍ # Push ' ', swap, make the string of spaces as long as the input was
võJ # For each char, push a space and ''.join(stack)
v¶J # For each char, push a newline and ''.join(stack)
€ðJ # For each char, push a space. Then ''.join(stack)
€¶J # For each char, push a newline. Then ''.join(stack)
```

Comment: Other solution: `gð×`, the rest I came up with were above 3 like: `õ‚.B¤`

Comment: Another fun one: `Sð:`

Comment: More fun: `ðs∍`

Comment: Some more alternative 3-byters: `võJ`/`v¶J`; `€ðJ`/`€¶J`. And since a sequence of characters as I/O is allowed by default when strings I/O is asked, some 2-byte versions are possible: [`€ð`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UdOawxv@/49W8lDSUUoF4hwozgdiEFQA4nAovwgqlwLEikqxAA)/`€¶`/`εð`/`ε¶` and `ð:`/`¶:`. Although since this is a pretty old challenge and all other answers use actual strings, I could understand if you kept it as string I/O.

Answer (score 7):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>17</s></sub> 15 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window funtion that takes input from cell `[A1]` and outputs spaces of length of the input to the VBE immediate window

```vba
?Spc([Len(A1)])
```

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 28 Bytes

```php
for(;a&$argn[$i++];)echo" ";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVfJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFUsv6fll@kYZ2oBpaNVsnU1o611kxNzshXUgBK/gcA)

## PHP, 29 Bytes

```php
<?=str_pad('',strlen($argn));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVfJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFUsuayt/tvY29bXFIUX5CYoqGurgNk5qTmaYCVa2pa//8PAA)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

```
s=>" ".repeat(s.length)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Octave, 14 bytes

```
@(a)["" 0*a+32]
```

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes

```
q,S*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#PcpBCoMwFEXReVbxxEFBXEbtBlpwKFq@yS8l3yZP2t3H0IGzc@GWT3/vytRDWjyCZqxmlISq154JGraksSII3hI9A2z91zcoJW/zUwqAq8UL3c2SF2JebKcbfpqp0bvxPJt6Hg)

#### Explanation

```
q     e# Read input
 ,    e# Length
  S*  e# Repeat space that many times
```

Answer (score 6):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 2 bytes

```
Ò
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394ksL//x6pOTn5CuX5RTkpAA)

Note the trailing space!

Answer (score 6):

## C, 45 bytes

Using main. Compile with gcc, ignore warnings.

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{while(*(v[1]++))puts("");}
```

Usage:

```c
$./a.out "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't put `char**v` in `main(c,v)`?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline At least GCC 6.3.1 compiling simply with `gcc main.c` doesn't seem to allow mixing ANSI function definition with K&R function definition, so `main(c,char**v)` won't compile. I either have to do `main(int c,char**v)` or `main(c,v)char**v;` of which the latter is 3 bytes shorter. You wouldn't by chance know any flag or something which allows mixing these styles?

Comment: No, you can't mix 'em. There's no flag that allows that. K&R style is long obsolete, used only for code golfing and obfuscation purposes.

Comment: And I'm guessing removing `char**v` entirely doesn't compile either.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline If you omit `char**` entirely the compiler will interpret it as `int`. If I'm not mistaken you get an error trying to dereference an `int` and even if you didn't the program wouldn't do what you expected it to do since an `int` consumes several `char`s and therefore you never get a `NULL` value.

Comment: I think you could just do `main(char**v){...}`, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: How would you be able to do that, @conor? The first parameter to `main` is an `int`. Your declaration is missing the first parameter!

Comment: @CodyGray my mistake. I thought I remembered reading that using only argv as a parameter was valid somewhere

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 25 bytes

```
exec'print;'*len(input())
```

-2 bytes thanks to Loovjo
-2 bytes in the invalid code thanks to totallyhuman :p
-3 bytes

Comment: You can remove the parens after `exec` since it's a keyword in Python 2

Comment: @Loovjo Oh right, Python 2. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old and stuff but `exec'print;'*len(input())` works.

Comment: @totallyhuman oh true, thanks :P

Comment: Oh, my bad, didn't think of that.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work. `input()` in python2 evaluates the contents. So this errors with ```SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing``` for `Hello, World!`. You need to use `raw_input()`.

Comment: @TheMatt Actually, thanks for pointing that out; thanks to current policies, that actually does work (and allows newlines) because you can request for input to be enclosed in quotes or whatever is required for the language specs in that respect

Comment: Ah ok, can you please point out where it says enclosed in quotes is valid. I am just not seeing it. Also, for what it is worth, `print' '*(len(input())-1)` is also 25 bytes.

Comment: @TheMatt it's probably not in the problem specs but it's one of the default acceptable input methods. Try looking on meta, I don't want to go looking for it right now

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 7 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@Xcali](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72767/xcali)*

6 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
y// /c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6yoUABkKOgW/K/U11fQT/7/3yM1JydfR6E8vygnRREA)

Quite straight forward : replaces every character with a space.

Comment: `y// /c` is one byte shorter.

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 18 bytes

```
=REPT(" ",LEN(A1))
```

Pretty boring and one byte longer than [the VBA answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122722/38183).

Answer (score 5):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 7 bytes

```
i0(?;ao
```

The program is a loop

```
i         //Push a character from the input onto the stack
 0        //Add a 0 to the stack
  (       //Pop the top two values of the stack, and push a 1 if the second is less than the first (In this case, the input has all been read), else push a 0
   ?      //Pop the top of the stack. If the value is a 0, skip the next instruction
    ;     // Terminate the program
     a    // Add a newline to the stack
      o   // Pop the top character of the stack and print it
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
*dl
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2adl&input=%22ab%22&debug=0)

Python equivalent: `len(input())*" "`

```
jmk
```

[Try this!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jmk&input=%22abc%22&debug=0)

Python equivalent: `"\n".join(map("", input()))`

```
smb
```

[Try that!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smb&input=%22abcd%22&debug=0)

Python equivalent: `"".join(map("\n",input())`

```
VQk
```

[Try!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQk&input=%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22&debug=0)

Python equivalent: `For N in input():print("")`

Comment: @StanStrum: It outputs newlines. Newlines are also allowed per the challenge description above. You can see this better from [this example input](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQk&input=%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 5):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)

```
,<.;.M@.>~8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/1/HRs9az9dBz67O4v9/BQUFl/w89RIut/yi9NQShcSk/NISLteKzOKSzLx0rvCMzJLU4oLE5FRFBQUA)

Here is the expanded hex:

```
  , < . 
 ; . M @
. > ~ 8 .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

While there is input, this code runs:

```
,        # Get input
 <       # Turn right (SE) if we didn't get EOF
  M8     # Set the memory edge to 778 which is 10 (mod 256)
    ;    # Print as a character (newline)
     >   # Redirect East
      ~  # Multiply by -1. This makes the pointer go to the top when it runs off the edge
       8 # Effectively a no-op.
```

When EOF is reached:

```
,    # Get input
 <   # Turn left (NE)
  8  # Effectively a no-op
   @ # End program
```

Comment: You can print a linefeed in three bytes with `M8;` (which gives 778 = 10 (mod 256)). That should allow you to move the `~` where the `;` is right now, saving a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 36 bytes

```
<?=str_repeat('
',strlen($argv[1]));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29jb1tcUhRflFqQmliioc6lrgPk5qTmaagkFqWXRRvGampa////3yM1JydfRyE8vygnRREA)

Outputs newlines because spaces are too mainstream

Comment: `$argn` instead of `$argv[1]` save 4 bytes. Run with the `-F` option

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
⁶ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R47aHOxv///@v5AEUyNdRCM8vyklRVAIA)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 31 bytes

I opted to output newlines since it's shorter...

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s++;puts(""));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-tcc#@5@mkZyRWKRVrFmdll@kYa1VrK1tXVBaUqyhpKSpaV37PzcxM09Dk6uaSwEICooy80rSNJQ8UnNy8hXC84tyUhSVNOHqrcGKMOW5av9/zcvXTU5MzkgFAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 6 bytes

Wahoo a 6 byter!

```
wi?@oS
```

Cubified

```
  w
i ? @ o
  S
```

- `i` gets input
- `?` test top of stack

  - if negative (EOI) redirect onto `w` lane change which umps to the `@` halt
  - if 0 (null) halt this shouldn't be hit
  - if positive `Sow` push space to the stack, output and change lane onto `i`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@1@eae@QH/z/v4KCgkt@nnoJl1t@UXpqiUJiUn5pCZdrRWZxSWZeOld4RmZJanFBYnKqIlAlAA)

Comment: Sweet, it's not too often a Cubix program is this short :-)

Answer (score 4):

## C, 32 bytes

[**Try Online**](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkZyRWKRVolmtoVViq1Vib2xkZaCpppamUaJtqGldy5WbmJmnkaxTpglWp1VmXZ2mURZtGKtpXVCUmVcC49T@//9fySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVEJAA) modifying characters into spaces

```c
f(char*t){(*t=*t?32:0)&&f(t+1);}
```

#### C, 37 bytes

[**Try Online**](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkZyRWKRVolldUJSZV5KmoaSqlaykU1xSlJOap1GiqWOgaV3LlZuYmaeRrFOmCVasVWZdnaZRFm0YC5T7//@/kkdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqISAA) Left-padding the end-of-string with its length

```c
f(char*t){printf("%*c",strlen(t),0);}
```

Comment: [29](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirRLNaq8RWq8Q@TaNE21BTx9jIysC69j9XbmJmnkayTpkmWJVWmXV1mkZZtGGspnVBUWZeCYxT@/@/kkdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqISAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/) 13.2, 1 byte

Prints only spaces.

`∊` prototype (numbers become zeros, characters become spaces)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qr8@jtgkGCo965yqk5RcpGBrrGSkkpWYklmXmlxYplOalpAIFTfUM/qcB1T3q6Pr/P01B3SM1JydfRyE8vygnRVGdCySSCaYUFBRc8vPU1UvUdTSAhoc6BysYGmjqqLvlF6WnligkJuWXoku5VmQWl2TmpaMJh2dklqQWFyQmpyoCDQUbDrMBAUAicE0A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe/), <s>46</s> 37 bytes

```
REEeRREeeeREEEEErEeeEeeeeerEEeeeEreee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#T-!d-j!8g_aG)

**Explanation:**

```
REEe       # Input (string) in R
RREeee     # Push reverse pointer position, or length of input - 1
           # R flag: push in beginning
REEEEE     # ...add 1
rEeeEeeeee # Push space in r
rEEeeeE    # ...R times
reee       # Output whole stack
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 81 bytes

```
the berenstein bears
i remember a series i spelled wrong
o m gee,i do remember it
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?RcoxCsAgEETR3lNMeg@SG6RWHMyCumFXyPGNXbrP582byDQOn0nGzmQeBMbOvj8SnCZ0CPxhayx4TUcNio5KRkHRn8tc51Yacam1cqycygc)

The misspelling is intentional. (...or *is* it?)

Answer (score 3):

## Gema, 4 characters

```
?=\
```

(There is a space at the end of code.)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ echo -n 'Hello, World!' | gema '?=\ '
             bash-4.4$ echo -n 'Hello, World!' | gema '?=\ ' | wc
      0       0      13
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

Prints only newlines.

```apl
0/⍪
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wQD/Ue9q4BMBXWP1JycfIXw/KKcFEV1AA)

`⍪` table (makes string into column matrix)

`0/` replicate each column zero times

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 15 bytes

```scala
s=>" "*s.length
```

Comment: I created a [Try it online](https://tio.run/##TcyxCsIwEIDhPU9xPSg2In0AwUFQNycH57Q9m0hIQu7EovjsMZuuPx8/j8abEoc7jQJn4wLQIhQmhn1K8C4T3dqOtxfJLsx6h4Br7tm9qKRaxIeu7dCS93EDz5j91KDuPYVZrFZ/BBEADjGsRJ1inknADPEh6rg4lrpWV@uEOJmRmiqr/20@5Qs) for your program.

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>25</s> 18 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [brhfl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58230/brhfl)

```
Z[1-d0<L32P]sLd0<L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b/8/KtpQN8XAxsfYKCC22AfE@v8/OikxDwhj/wMA)

Explanation:

```
Z[1-d0<L32P]sLd0<L
                    Implicit input
Z                   Get length
 [         ]sL      Create a funcion and saves in L
              d0<L  If length > 0, call L
  1-                Subtract 1 from the length
    d0<L            If length > 0, call L
        32P         Print space
```

Comment: Woah! It's worse than German. It would be neat if you explained how it works ;)

Comment: @NieDzejkob there :D

Comment: @Felipe You can shave off one byte by using the ASCII code point for a space instead of a string containing a space: `32P` instead of `[ ]P`. I doubt it can be golfed down much further...

Comment: @brhfl didn't know i could do that, thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 16 bytes

```
f(C*a){W*a++)P'
```

Note the trailing space at end of code.

Conversions in this program:

- `C` -> `char`
- `W` -> `while(`
- `P` -> `putchar(`

The resulting program looks like this:

```
f(char *a){while(*a++)putchar(' ');}
```

How *that* works:

- `while(*a++)` loops until it reaches the last index of the string `a`.
- `putchar(' ');` prints a space for each index of `a`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/p@bmJmnoVmdpqHkkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiqKRpXfs/TcNZK1GzOlwrUVtbM0Bd4f9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 24 bytes

```
s->s.replaceAll("."," ")
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#lVDNSgMxEL7vU0xzMWFrXqAoCCpe7MVDD66HNE23gXSyJFNRZJ99nZUFXStCcgiZ@f5mYoPJGR6Nx48KwCO5tDfWwXosAZ4oeWzByumR1Yr7fcVXJkPewhoQrmDIl9dZJ9cFFt@EIIUWSwFCDauR2522gbmT5DX6HRw5cnJ9fgGjprz3TO6o44l0xxAFlKitFA8uhLiETUxhtxAKahBS1H9BOjhs6SBVLZT4mvYfV//LypfpGbqNeEEN3sfUOgKzZU6Dd28@Ey/W4ObgyeWOP2XB5HlaubpktnlW8V7f52zon1CJa4Nzq7E@1/dVP3wC)

## Java 7, 49 bytes

```
String c(String s){return s.replaceAll("."," ");}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#lZDBasMwDIbvfQpVl9mk@AV2Kmxjl5166KHZwXVNalDlYCtjpeTZMxcCzVYYjU4Wv/7vl@zI5gwflwVAFivBwbCRFLgBp8ZH1pfkpUsM2STfknV@TaTQ4AoB9XM/ALTdnop3RHzFcICTDTwidp9g9TUCYHPO4k8mdmLaIgmxcgrfPVFcwTYmOixRQwWosLoXDHlu5Kh0hbok/0cMvzBhjrcIL5GfpOa3mBovYPdloubX75ClnFPz9hjE57b8xLIMT5Pmex/fa5oz855b/Vl2KjxOrHmKuXb33n7RDz8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 2 bytes

```
*f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/chip#@6@V9v@/R2pOTr6OQnl@UU6KIgA)

Chip reads in a byte, does whatever calculations are in the code, and writes a byte. So, for each byte of input, we ignore the input and write `0x20` instead. The empty Chip program would replace each byte of input with a null byte of output.

```
*    Source element, activates any neighbor elements
 f   Output element for the bit 0x20, when active this bit is set in the output
```

Transposing the two characters would result in the same thing. I opted to use spaces, since `0x20` requires only one bit to be set. `0x0a` requires setting two bits. Code for that could be:

```
b*d
```

Answer (score 3):

## Shell utils, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
tr ' -~' ' '
```

tr translates characters in the first parameter, into the corresponding one in the second parameter. (space)-~ is a range for space (32) to tilda (126), the first and last printable ASCII characters. They are mapped into a space; tr duplicates the last character in the output list if it is shorter than the input list.

Comment: You could shave off a couple of bytes with different quoting styles (`\ -~` instead of `' -~'`) and you could even get away without quoting the first parameter at all if you use a control-character byte.

Comment: That brings it down to 9 bytes: `tr ␁-~ \ ` (␁=^A)

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, <s>18</s> 12 bytes

-6 bytes thanks @Julian

```powershell
$args|%{' '}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LDoIwEEX38xVDUwWSanxuTEhcqPEPXBrECiQN1bZEE@DbcSgunNXNmXvn8dRvaWwhler5AxNsep6a3LaTJsSw6zuAfQQiWq4FsjO5tMCLNuoesJjwaqCll5staUQ86Cp0cNImlw7Tm64dHD@ldWWVw6UonbTPNJMBOX1sQSkv/Ab8rxELBiRibHGCDQycK1kJbnVtMpnw68gM3T6lD/Yj/xkTbubkzl3hAeMRVzP5GibEO@oz6Pov)

Testscript (use `LF only` mode in your editor):

```powershell
$f = {
$args|% t*y|%{' '}
}

@(
,(13, "Hello, World!")
,(2, "Hi")
,(45, "   Don't
Forget about
Existing
Whitespace!   ")
,(0, "")
,(13, "             ")
,(1,"
")
) | % {
    $len,$source=$_
    $r = &$f $source
    $l=$r.length
    "$($l-eq$len): $l"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 13
True: 2
True: 45
True: 0
True: 13
True: 1
```

### Powershell + Regex, 20 bytes

```powershell
$args-replace'.',' '
```

Comment: You can go down 6 bytes using splatting ?
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LDoIwEEX38xVDUwWSanxuTEhcqPEPXBrECiQN1bZEE@DbcSgunNXNmXvn8dRvaWwhler5AxNsep6a3LaTJsSw6zuAfQQiWq4FsjO5tMCLNuoesJjwaqCll5staUQ86Cp0cNImlw7Tm64dHD@ldWWVw6UonbTPNJMBOX1sQSkv/Ab8rxELBiRibHGCDQycK1kJbnVtMpnw68gM3T6lD/Yj/xkTbubkzl3hAeMRVzP5GibEO@oz6Pov "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks. Three years ago we didn't use splatting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) -p, 10 bytes

```ruby
$_=$/*~/$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyvrFgEpBR0C/6rxNuq6GvV6avo//@fkZqTk69Qnl@UkwIA)

Explanation:

```
$_=          Output equals
   $/        the output separator (defaults to newline)
     *       repeated a number of times equal to
      ~      the index in the input of the first match of
        /$/  the regular expression for "end of line"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 11 bytes

```
i7#'@"o.:2L
```

Unfolds to this:

```
    i
   7 #
  ' @ "
 o . : 2
L . . . .
```

This has to be the most creative way I've used `@` yet: when hit in one direction, it ends the program; when hit in a different direction, it's divided by 2 to get a space.

Roughly equivalent to this C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL, <s>11</s> 6 bytes

*5 bytes saved thanks to @Adám*

```
' '⍴⍨≢
```

Uses the Dyalog Classical character set.

Comment: You can golf this significantly. First, swap the arguments of *rho* to remove the parentheses:  `{' '⍴⍨⍴,⍵}`, then use *tally* rather than *rho* to remove the comma: `{' '⍴⍨≢⍵}`, and finally, make it into a train to remove the braces and *omega*: [`' '⍴⍨≢`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wR1BfVHvVse9a541LkIKKKg7pGak5OvEJ5flJOiqA4A "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online").

Comment: @Adám thanks! never seen the *tally* before

Comment: No problem. I'll be happy to teach you more over in [the APL chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/apl).

Comment: How is this 5 bytes?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer fixed, thanks. it counts 6 with the Dyalog char set

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 21 bytes

```powershell
[char[]]"$args"|%{""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@x@dnJFYFB0bq6SSWJRerFSjWq2kVPv///@M1JycfAA)

prints newlines.

Comment: .....I like it!

Comment: @briantist thanks for the TIO link, need to get into the habit of doing them myself.

Comment: can't go wrong, it creates the whole post for you. [That's why I use it even when the code itself can't run in TIO ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105139/30402)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 10 bytes

```
{S:g/./ /}
```

Basic string substitution.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES8), 22 bytes

```
s=>"".padEnd(s.length)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 2 bytes

```
,*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PK0ut@P9fR@v///8eqTk5@ToK5flFOSmKAA)

Simply takes the length of the input and multiplies by newlines (which are at the bottom of the stack)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 16 bytes

```bash
printf %*s ${#1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUFVq1hBpVrZsPb///8eqTk5@ToK5flFOSmKAA)

Uses parameter expansion count the length of the argument `${#1}`, and then `printf` to output an empty string space-padded to that same length.

Comment: `printf %${#1}s` is 14 bytes; `tr -c '' \ ` (with input from the standard input stream) is 11

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 6 + 1 = 7 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag.

```
y// /c
```

`y///` is the transliteration operator: the first list is translated to the corresponding character in the second list. Without the `c`, this does nothing, but the `c` complements the first list, so all characters are transliterated to a space.

Answer (score 2):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 5 bytes

Trivial in Aceto:

```
p
,'O
```

Reads a character, pushes a space, prints it, and goes back to the start.

Answer (score 2):

## q/kdb+, <s>14</s> 9 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{" "}each
```

**Example:**

```
q){" "}each"Hello, World"
"            "
```

**Explanation:**

Returns " " for each character of the input.

**Notes:**

I've made a shorter version (7 bytes) that does something similar:

```
{y}'" "
```

... but you have to prepend the input rather than append:

```
q)"hello world"{y}'" "
"           "
```

Comment: Using one of the k's, 2 bytes is possible as `""`, e.g. this [ngn/k version](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NSkmJS0lJySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVHpv6GxgpGCiamCgQKQZVinrJ6mroGmxlrJIxNIKCgouOTnqZfE5LnlF6WnligkJuWXAnmuFZnFJZl56TF54RmZJanFBYnJqYpAxUAtEF0IAOTH5Clp/gcA).

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 32 bytes

```
SELECT SPACE(LEN(a+'x')-1)FROM t
```

Microsoft SQL's `LEN` function ignores trailing spaces, so this hacky workaround is required.

Input is stored in `varchar` column **a** in pre-existing table **t**, per [our input rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/70172).

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 13 bytes

```
For(I,2,length(Ans
Disp "
End
```

Loop starts at 2 because an additional newline is printed before `Done` at the end of the program.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>3</s> 4 bytes

```
nqZ"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P68wSun/f3WP1JycfIXy/KKcFHUA)

Today I learnt that MATLAB has a function for creating a string of spaces!

`n` - count the number of bytes in input string
`q` - decrement by 1, because the implicit `disp` at the end adds a newline (so the number of spaces required is `string length - 1`)
`Z"` - `blanks` command: create a string with the specified number of spaces in it
(Implicit output at end, with trailing newline.)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>37</s> 23 bytes

```r
gsub("."," ",scan(,""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P724NElDSU9JR0lBSac4OTFPQ0dJSVPzv5KhkbHSfwA)

14 bytes saved by ngm.

Comment: apart from using `gsub`, `strrep` exists as well, so `strrep(" ",nchar(scan,"")))` would work (even though it's longer than @ngm 's suggestion)

Comment: @Giuseppe Is this a recent function? I can't believe I'm hearing about it for the first time.

Comment: It appears to have been added in `3.3.0`. I haven't really found a great use for it; usually the first thing I do when I see a string is to `utf8ToInt` it and then I can just use `rep` for mostly the same purpose, and `rep` has finer control beyond just `times`, with `each`, `length.out`

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 4 bytes

```
LF"0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuo2CgYAXEunrOQTo@bv993JQM/mtyFYMlXfLz1NVLFNLyi9JTS9SB0jrqiUn5pSUKqRWZxSWZeekK5RmZJanFBYnJqYrqXKnJGfkKysUQOk0BylABsv4DAA)

Converts each cell (each character in this case) to the linefeed character. `LF` is a built-in noun for `'\n'`. `"0` attached to a noun converts it to a verb with the given rank.

Answer (score 2):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 9 bytes

```
" "il͍*@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19JQSkz52yvlsP//x6pOTn5OjEK4flFOSmKAA)

Note that spaces and newlines need to be escaped in the input, as input is automatically split otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), <s>14</s> <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
? .'
,^\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/315BT51LJy7m/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

-1 byte thanks to Jo King realizing it's shorter to just turn into two lines

Since the program never uses the return values of anything other than `,` and `'`, and the order spaces are printed in doesn't matter (since they're indistinguishable), `^` can be used backwards: instead of printing a space then recurring, this recurs then prints a space.

Ungolfed, this looks something like:

```
 @
 ?
 |\
 , \
    ^
   / \
  /   .
 |    \
 |     '
 |
```

If tabs are legal whitespace alongside spaces and newlines:

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 7 bytes

```
? .
,^9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/315Bj0snzvL/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUA)

thanks to Jo King.

Comment: Note that this uses `?` over `_` because end of input returns -1, and `?` tests for a positive center, but `_` only tests for a left not equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 5 bytes

```
iEH~a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P9PVoy7x/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

**Explanation**

```
i      Push 1 char from the input to the stack
 E     If EOF was reached execute next, else skip 1
  H    Output the entire stack as chars and halt
   ~a  Discard the last read char and push 0x0a to the stack
```

Since Gol><> is actually a 2D language the programm counter loops back to the other side when it hits a border.
This is used to loop back to the beginning after the discard & 0x0a push step.

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 6 bytes

```
 ,
\"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fQYcrRsnh/3@P1JycfB2F8vyinBRFAA)

A character input command, a newline-printing command, a halt command, and a three-way junction for branching. I don't think we can do better than that. (A conditional halt without a three-way junction should involve division by zero, which gets unnecessarily verbose)

```
    Start at the first valid command
,   Take a character input (-1 on EOF)
"   A no-op at 3-way junction: turn left if negative, turn right if positive
    (we can assume the input string consists of printable ASCII, which is > 0)

\   If positive: print a newline, turn backwards
"   3-way junction: top > 0, so turn right (which is reflected to left by a wall)
,   Repeat from the start of the program until it hits EOF

@   If EOF, halt
```

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 3 bytes

```
,n*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/XydP6/9/Q0NDAA)

pretty self explanatory, and I don't think there is a way to make it smaller unless there is some really weird thing with % or /.

Comment: It's not “self-explanatory” for those who don't know GolfScript…

Comment: @xigoi well, it is as far as golfscript programs go. The comma gets the length of the input, the n is a newline, and the * repeats the string.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
{x,(1+#x)#""}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qu0NEw1Fau0FRWUqrl4kqLVvJIzcnJVyjPL8pJUVSKBYtkQmgFZAAVUooFAGiUEHQ=)

*-1 byte thanks to ngn!*

Dead simple.

Explanations:

```
{x,(1+#x)#""}    Main function. Takes x as input
 x,              x concat with
          ""     An empty string (Implicit whitespace)
         #       Duplicate with the amount of
   (  #x)        Length of x
    1+           + 1 times
```

Comment: reshaping a space `" "` is the same as reshaping the empty string `""`

Answer (score 2):

## [str](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/str), 1 byte

```
s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4p@v@/@P//xOKUNC6P1JycfEUA)

Since str manipulates streams byte-by-byte, this outputs 1 `s`pace for each input character.

Answer (score 2):

## [makina](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Makina), 28 bytes

```
v>>>n0;
>wPH
vO*OL
ti ^C
> ;
```

Uses a few clever tricks, like using the space literal to stop the input instruction. Sadly, it's pretty difficult to explain makina, but you can look at the [esolangs.org page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Makina) if you want to figure out how this program works.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
S
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=Uw&input=IkludmlzaWJsZSBUZXh0IgotUQ)

```
S     :Implicit map of each character in input string
S     :Literal space
```

### Less Trivial (w/o flag), 3 bytes

```
r.S
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ci5T&input=IjEyMyIKLVE)

```
r.S     :Implicit input of string
r       :Replace
 .      :RegEx /./g
  S     :With space
```

### Even Less Trivial, 6 bytes

```
©SißUÅ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=qVNp31XF&input=IjEyMyIKLVE)

```
©SißUÅ     :Implicit input of string U
©          :Logical AND with
 Si        :Space prepended with
   ß       :  Recursive call with argument
    UÅ     :    U with first character removed
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC 3, 22 bytes

Asks for a string from the console as input, then prints *length* spaces. `PRINT` (or `?` here) adds a trailing newline by default, so we use the `;` to disable it.

```
LINPUT A$?" "*LEN(A$);
```

Comment: This technically isn't valid since LINPUT doesn't accept newlines, so you'll have to define a function (also ; isn't required because PRINT doesn't really output newlines)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
Row@Table[" ",StringLength@#]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 25 bytes

```lua
for i=1,#...do
print()end
```

Same length as:

```lua
io.write((' '):rep(#...))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@5@WX6SQaWuoo6ynp5eSz1VQlJlXoqGZmpfy////pMQ8IAQA)

Comment: Test output length [here](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S03OyFdQ@p@WX6SQaWuoo6ynp5eSz1VQlJlXoqGZmpfyX0mhRiGnNFFBV0E9KTEPCNWBAuXJCrrJ//8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 19

```
regsub -all . $s \
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/BJFDA29728)

To test it, click "Run it" button and then select the white space on the white bottom area. A better test is to add a space and a letter before the `]` as I describe:

```
puts [regsub -all . $s \  x]    
                        ^^ Two spaces here
```

and it will output the count of characters of each string exactly equal to the ones on the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 23 bytes

```
|s|" ".repeat(s.len());
```

First time using Rust so not 100% sure I've got everything correct, let me know if I need to change anything. I couldn't work out how to test this, as I'm still new to it, but judging from the documentation it should work. Also any improvements are more than welcome!

Comment: Hi fellow newbie! I tried to rig up enough surrounding code to make a Try It Online link for this answer (and any similar Rust entries). [I did get somewhere](https://tio.run/##Zc29CoMwFIbhPVdxdLAJlEDXiFvbW@goqY0aSI8hOfYH9drTlI4dP3g/njBHSj3CXVvkAhbmDIEOAzQQ6aaUwYdSeUcuJNLID0LO@Azac1H/2o5m7dphcn1rkMIbmrRGVUUKawmlDMYbTTxKZzIg6uSDRSp4uWzl/v/Nq4wJwbaUAOA44Y7YeQrDV7pOM7HTy0ayOLDLaMlErztT5PID) but I needed to add a type declaration at the cost of an extra 5 bytes (for a total of 28 bytes) to get it to compile.

Answer (score 1):

## ZX80 (4K ROM version with sanity check)

~58 bytes (listing)

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 IF A$="" THEN GO TO 1
 3 PRINT " ";
 4 LET A$=TL$(A$)
 5 IF A$="" THEN STOP
 6 GO TO 3
```

Line 2 can be removed to save RAMs. However, if an empty string is entered without line 2 then it will `PRINT` one space.

Comment: It is now later.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 28 bytes

```
{{}<>((()()()()()){})<>}<>{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@19dXWtjp6GhoQmDmtW1mjZ2QMHq2v//M1JzcvIVyvOLclL@6yYDAA)

```
{{}                    }     # For every input character...
     ((()()()()()){})        #    Push 10...
   <>                <>      #    on the other stack
                        <>   # Switch to the stack with all of the newlines
                          {} # Pop a newline because the interpreter prints a newline :(
```

Answer (score 1):

## [pb](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pb) - 17 bytes

```
^w[B!0]{>}<vb[32]
```

Goes to the last character of the input and puts a space on the canvas cell representing it. Because output in pb is 2D, the empty cells before it are automatically filled in with spaces when it's outputted.

Answer (score 1):

## x64 ASSEMBLY (linux nasm) - 131 bytes

```
mov r8, [rsp+16]
mov rdi, 1
mov rdx, 1
mov rax, 1
mov rsi,n
l:syscall
inc r8
cmp byte [r8],0x00
jnz l
mov rax,60
syscall
n: db " "
```

build and run with:

```
nasm -felf64 invisible_golfed.asm
ld invisible_golfed.asm
./a.out
```

This will give the warning

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000000400080
```

warning free version below

**without warnings - 152**

```
global _start
_start:mov r8, [rsp+16]
mov rdi, 1
mov rdx, 1
mov rax, 1
mov rsi,n
l:syscall
inc r8
cmp byte [r8],0x00
jnz l
mov rax,60
syscall
n: db " "
```

Comment: When I give the program "When I give the program" on STDIN, it only prints a single space. I suggest your read the [I/O defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and revise your answer. Essentially, revise your code to take input from STDIN.

Comment: My bad I have it reading from the command line. I'll fix that tomorow when I get the chance.

Comment: Your byte-counting is not correct. With assembly language, we count th bytes of the *machine code* that is generated, not the characters in the instruction mnemonics. Beyond that problem, there's lots of room for optimization here. Save several bytes by changing instructions of the form `MOV Rxx, x` to `MOV Exx, x`, where *x* is an immediate value <= 32 bits, taking advantage of the fact that the upper 32-bits of a 64-bit register are implicitly cleared. I also don't know why you define `n` separately, instead of embedding it into the instruction: `MOV ESI, ' '`. That gets me down to 48 bytes.

Comment: You can save even more by changing all but the first instruction in the `MOV reg, 1` sequence to a reg-reg move, which has a much shorter encoding: `mov eax, 1`+`mov edx, eax`+`mov edi, eax`. That's only 36 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>57</s> <s>33</s> 30 bytes

-3 thanks to Tas.

```
f(int*a){while(*a++)puts("");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUgrUbO6PCMzJ1VDK1FbW7OgtAQkqmFspGldy5WbmJmnoVmdpqHkkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiqASU@///PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 18 bytes

```powershell
' '*"$args".Length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@uoK6lpJJYlF6spOeTmpdekvH///@M1JycfAA)

Answer (score 1):

**Python, 23 bytes**

```
print(''*len(input()))
```

First time

Comment: Assuming where input comes from is usually frowned upon here. You need to wrap the code in a program/method or ask the user for input.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder fixed!

Comment: You don't need the space between `,` and `'` in your second version. However, that second version isn't a full program - you need a `print` call, and you need to fix your `str.replace` call (not enough arguments).

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 17 Bytes

`s=s:gsub("."," ")`

Simple regular expression substitution, replaces any character found with a space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 5 bytes

```
#@~a,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XdqhL1Pn/X0FBwSU/T72Eyy2/KD21RCExKb@0hMu1IrO4JDMvnSs8I7MktbggMTlVEagSAA)

For every character in the input (`#@~`), this prints a new line (`a,`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 9 bytes

```
00000000: d5cd 0380 3001 763e 20                   ....0.v>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBRSTJNTFAyMLQwUjA0MDBXMzYxTFYwMFDCBHhAY6JXZ/f/vkZqTk68IAA)

Disassembly:

```
  push de     ; push $0000
  call $8003  ; getchar(A)
  jr nc, k    ; jump if not EOF
  halt
k:ld a, ' '   ; replace A with space
              ; memory from $000a through $7fff is $00=NOP...
              ; PC reaches $8000=putchar(A) and RETs to pushed address.
```

(If you remove the last two bytes, this is a `cat` program.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 15 bytes

```julia
s->" "^endof(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@79Y105JQSkuNS8lP02jWPN/bmKBRkFRZl5JTt6jjhlpOgoaSh6pOTn5Ogrh@UU5KYpKOgpKiSAiLT09Lb0kIw0IUzLKUrLTUyqTUtKBKCM5pSQjOU1JU/M/AA)

`^` applied to strings is the repetition operator, and `endof` gives the last index of the string, which is equal to the length of the string (since Julia indexing is 1-based).

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 12 bytes

```
Z256r^25.5/P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@H51YnBL7P8rI1KwozshUz1Q/4P9/AA)

Takes input from the stack, outputs **newlines** to stdin.

I know there's two dc answers here already, but this one uses a different approach, with math! Plus it's 6 bytes shorter, so I guess that's all right.

## Explanation

One of dc's three explicit printing commands is `P`, which takes a number and outputs it as a base 256 (technically base UCHAR_MAX+1, works on my machine) byte stream. So I need to feed it the number (where `n` is the length of the given string, and `10` is the codepoint of the linefeed character):

```
   10*256^(n-1) + 10*256^(n-2) + ... + 10
 = 10 * (256^(n-1) + 256^(n-2) + ... + 1)   (factoring out 10)
 = 10 * (256^n - 1) / (256 - 1)             (geometric series formula)
 = (256^n - 1) / 25.5                       (combining constants)    
~= (256^n) / 25.5                           (because dc's default precision is 0)
```

The code is a straightforward calculation of this number, followed by `P`.

Comment: Argh, doesn't handle the empty string (`P` outputs a `NUL` when it pops a `0`). I guess I could say it's outputting a null-terminated string...seems like a stretch though.

Comment: Also, it's only on TIO that you can tell. On my machine a NUL gets eaten silently so it works. I still feel badly about it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
@(x)repmat(' ',size(x))
```

<sub>Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)</sub>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330GjQrMotSA3sURDXUFdpzizKhUoovk/TUM9MSnZ0MhYXZMLLIgkoPkfAA)

Comment: I think the `f=` is unnecessary; anonymous functions / function handles are perfectly acceptable on PPCG.

Comment: You can also include a link to [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330GjQrMotSA3sURDXUFdpzizKhUoovk/TUM9MSnZ0MhYXfM/AA) for Octave so others can test your answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 84 bytes

```java
static String m(String n){int i=0;String d="";while(i++<n.length())d+=" ";return d;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy7jsIwEEV7f8XgyiaLRW/S01Cl2GJFYbAVJvgR2RNWCOXbgxGpru7rDOZhdoO9LxjGlAmG6tVE6NVWM8au3pQCJ4MRXowBjNPF4xUKGarySGgh1FJ0lDH2f2cwuS/ys@2ehVxQaSI11o5EEPzovE8/8JuytxsupZ7ZsqK@AAgrCaJ81RNgu9drYlvO9f8NvRPYNIeovIs93YSUtmk5cJ0dTTmC1fPC5uUN)

Comment: Updated Sir @JoKing.

Comment: This does not address my other concerns, i.e. initialising `d` and reusing the function. Also, wouldn't it be shorter to use an anonymous lambda?

Comment: Your suggestions are so useful, Thanks @JoKing

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg),`-lp` `-ir`, 3 bytes

```
( ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fXkNB5///vMzkVAA)

This takes input as characters and prints a space for each character
The `-lp` flag makes the `length()` function take input if the stack is empty and the `-ir`  flag ensures that the implicit input is as characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 22 bytes

Multiply the space by the length of the string.

```
Fn.new{|a|" "*a.count}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxEoMgEADAnlecNNEU/MAu@oEU1hfmNMyYIwNHiKO@HXXrzYG4/DDAmNhCW3o2THndcNOg72isTyx7eS5R6GNycEL1VY3Fea41ADw830T1PkwkgC@fRHV/F8XxpIb3@eMXLVXn1E1TDg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 28 bytes

```
{}{{}<>((()()()()()){})<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v7q2urrWxk5DQ0MTBjWrazVt7ICC//97pObk5CuE5xflpPzXTQYA)

```
{}                  pop one input character (because Brain-Flak always outputs a trailing newline
{                   for each input character
  {}                pop that character
  <>                switch to other stack
  ((()()()()()){})  push 10 (newline)
  <>                back to input stack
}
<>                  switch to other stack. This is printed implicitly when the program ends
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 ASM, IBM PC DOS, 11 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: 8a0e 8000 49b8 200a cd10 c3              ....I. ....
```

**Unassembled:**

```
D1 EE       SHR  SI, 1          ; SI to 80H (SI intialized at 100H) 
AC          LODSB               ; load string length into AL
91          XCHG AX, CX         ; put input string length into CX
49          DEC  CX             ; remove leading whitespace from length
AC          LODSB               ; load whitespace delimiter into AL
B4 0A       MOV  AH, 0AH        ; BIOS "write character CX number of times" function
CD 10       INT  10H            ; call BIOS, display to console
C3          RET                 ; return to DOS
```

**Explanation:**

Input is via command line, though all that's important is the length.  Command line input length is always stored at memory address `DS:0080H` in DOS, so put that into `CX`.  DOS includes the space between the executable name and the command line args string in this number.

For example: in `FOO.COM Hello`, length is 6 and command line string is `" Hello"`, or calling as `FOO.COM/Hello`, command line string is `"/Hello"` (Note: those are the the only valid characters for the character immediately after the executable name).  This first character (will be a space when called normally) is what is displayed as the "invisible text" for output.  This builds in a handy little "debug mode" where you can use a slash instead of a space to actually be able to test your output is the right length.

Then, use the IBM PC BIOS's [INT 10H](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tChZv.png) "Write character only at cursor position" (`0AH`) function that writes the same character `CX` number of times.

**Example Output:**

Admittedly, displaying 13 chars of whitespace is not very interesting in a screenshot.  However, by using a slash instead of a space ("debug mode") you can actually see that you are displaying the right number of chars.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz/), 40 bytes

```
2a2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2e0m4a8m1o1f0x1x2f0a0x1f
```

Works for any input string terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
2a2x1v                 # Set variable 1 equal to 2
1x1f1r3x1v2e           # Function 1
                       # Read a byte of input
                       # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
            0m4a8m1o1f # Otherwise, output a space and jump back to the start of function 1
1x2f0a                 # Function 2
                       # Add 0 to the register
1f                     # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 5 bytes

Port of CJam answer.

```
," "*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X0dJQUnr/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 12 bytes

```
S0d3-' \k:W@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/z/YIMVYV10hJtsq3OH/f4/UnJx8hfD8opwUAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 23 bytes

```python
print(' '*len(input()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ11BXSsnNU8jM6@gtERDU1Pz/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 24 bytes

```
s->s.replaceAll("."," ")
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##ZY7BTsMwDIbvfQoTCZFIXR6AaUxcpu0wceBIOYQ26TKypIrdTqjqs5ewRlzmHGzZ///9OatBrc7N91w7hQhHZf1YWE86GlVr2I3vFK1vwfA8oFhPRdd/OVsDkqLUhmAbuCRn1nx8qtiiGIsdGNjMuHpBGXXnEvDVOc4kKxkwMa@LzLS@6wk2wPbauVDCNUTXVH55D5BrH65PCJag8m34s4VBR6CTjrryW/ZPCz0tOCMNv6FFuv0g6YtMN9klFRnODrdUp31Lp2d4TIFvi/N@lWasPCuXn8pFwEWZs@4WKXCa5l8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry) `-bnb`, 42 bytes

```
[]{(){}{}}[]{({})}<((({<({}){}>})){}){}{}>
```

[Try it online!](https://bubbler-4.github.io/Flurry/#!WwBdAHsAKAApAHsAfQB7AH0AfQBbAF0AewAoAHsAfQApAH0APAAoACgAKAB7ADwAKAB7AH0AKQB7AH0APgB9ACkAKQB7AH0AKQB7AH0AewB9AD4A#SABlAGwAbABvACwAIABXAG8AcgBsAGQAIQA=##YgBuAGIA#MQAwADAAMAAwAA==)

#### Run example (using Haskell interpreter)

```
$ printf "Hello World!" | ./flurry -bnb a.flr
          
$ printf "Hello World!" | ./flurry -bnb a.flr | wc -c
12
```

It takes 24 bytes just to construct a single space (32): `<((({<({}){}>})){}){}{}>`. Even worse is that it takes 2 more byets to construct a single newline (10): `(<><<>()>)<(<({}){}>{}){}>`...

The algorithm is: empty the stack, preserving the value of stack height, and then push space that many times.

```haskell
main = height pop-I height push-I 32

// Return self, popping and discarding one item from stack
pop-I = \x. K x pop
// (height pop-I height) returns original stack height with
// the stack emptied as a side effect

// Return self, pushing itself to the stack once
push-I = \x. push x

32 = 2**2 * 2**2 * 2
= <(2 2)(2 2)2>
= <(push ((push (push 2)) pop)) pop pop>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 27 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
say " "*S
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Replace the last line with the below to wrap the output in single quotes.

```
say "'"+" "*S+"'"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
R' L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P0i9wuf///9KHqk5Ofk6CuH5RTkpikoA) (Note: prints `x`s instead of spaces so that the output is visible; change the `x` to   to [not] see the real version)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```
for _ in stdin.readAll:stdout.write" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/Lb9IIV4hM0@huCQlM0@vKDUxxTEnxwrIyy8t0SsvyixJVVJQ@o/CV1YCasvnSkosAgA)

Since Nim is *style-insensitive*, something like this also works:

```
fOr _ iN sTdIn.rEaDaLl:sTdOuT.wRiTe" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/zb9IIV4h00@hOCTFM0@vyDXRJdEnxwrI8y8N0SsPygxJVVJQ@o/CV1b6n5afz5WUWAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
gð×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8//fCGw9P///dIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVEEAA)

```
gð×  # full program
 ð   # a space...
  ×  # repeated...
g    # length of input...
  ×  # times
```

Comment: ...nice, but quite similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122720/95126)...

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
LI
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJMSSIsIiIsIkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkIl0=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `S`, 2 bytes

```
v¤
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJTIiwiIiwidsKkIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8gd29ybGQiXQ==)

#### If we want to port the Jelly answer, then:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `rs`, 3 bytes

```
fð•
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJycyIsIiIsImbDsOKAoiIsIiIsIkhlbGxvIHdvcmxkISJd)

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), <s>50</s> 36 bytes

Totally pays off that `printf` doesn't automatically print a newline.

36 bytes by ceilingcat

```c
f(char*n){for(;printf(" "+!*n++););}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2.5 bytes (5 nibbles)

```
.$' '
```

A function that returns a string of spaces the same length as its argument.
(This won't work as a full program, since [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) will write a newline at the end of its output).

```
.                   # map over
 $                  # characters of the argument
  ' '               # returning a space for each
```

Obviously the output is invisible, but we can call this function from within a program that wraps the output into quotes to see the output string:

```
;~                  # save this function:
  .$' '             # <convert to invisible text>
         :'"'$      # prepend saved function results with a quote
        :     '"'   # and append that with another quote
```

[image]

---

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 3.5 bytes (7 nibbles)

```
>>.$' '
```

Full program.
We can't stop [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) from writing the trailing newline at the end of its output, so we shorten the invisible string by one character.

```
  .                 # map over
   $                # characters of the argument
    ' '             # returning a space for each
>>                  # and then remove the first character
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 36 bytes

```python
lambda x:re.sub('.',' ',x)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqihVr7g0SUNdT11HXUFdp0KTKzO3IL@oRKEo9X9BUWZeiUaahrpHak5OvkJ4flFOiqK6puZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 66 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)string{return Repeat(" ",len(s))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY09CgIxFIT7PcXjNebBurW1WFiKjXVYkxDMH_mpFk9iEwQv4U28jatZBKthhm9mbnfl6zPw8cKVAMu167QNPmYYUNqMj5LlevPatnDAlKN2KmEnixtBsgQtoSZTFLlEB0cRBM8MAXsjHEtE12Vp9y1-jhjB1AEc5t5MrpB-RjLcC2N8DycfzRmJ_rllq9ambw)

As far as I'm aware, you can't multiply strings and numbers to repeat a string in Go - you have to use `strings.Repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

## [(,)](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/in-parens-comma/) <s>40</s> 34 Chars or \$34\log_{256}(3)\approx6.74\$ Bytes

```
(,,,()()()()()()()()()(),((()())))
```

Or, printing spaces (54 Chars or 10.7 Bytes):

```
((),()()()()()()()())(,,,(())(())(())(()),((()())),())
```

Answer (score 1):

## [TI-BASIC](https://education.ti.com/en/products/calculators/graphing-calculators/ti-84-plus-ce-python), 27 bytes

```
Input Str1
For(X,1,length(Str1
Disp "
End
```

I love TI-84 because it completes my parentheses and quotes for me.
At the same time, it is quite annoying indeed how there is no string repeat (as far as I know). <s>Even more annoying is that (as far as I know) all input is int not str and any text passed will result in a single newline. I hope this is still valid despite that.</s> That was my bad. I was using an int variable.

Bytecount on TI-BASIC is kind of complex, the best way that I know of is going to TI Connect [CE] and looking for your program there.

*Explained:*

```
Input Str1                Ask for input and store in string variable

  length(Str1             Length of Str1
For(X,1,...               Loop through following code that many times
Disp "                    Display a blank string (with newline)
End                       End loop, go back to the For.
```

#### Test cases:

Typing on a TI-84 Plus CE is hard.
In these examples "-" is displayed instead of newline so you don't have to count.
[image: That took a while to type.][image]

Answer (score 0):

## REXX 27 Bytes

```
say left("",length(arg(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 22 Bytes

```
' '*(Read-Host).length
```

Comment: Not sure if `Read-Host` counts for input but `" "*"$args".length` is shorter anyway. Also there is not `len` property. That should be printing nulls.

Comment: Length property and Len are same

Comment: `"hello".Len` is null on my system because that is a non-existent property where as `"hello".Length` returns 5. If that works for you then you have an alias or extent that I, and most, do not have.

Comment: Ok...That explains it

Answer (score 0):

TXR Lisp, <s>22</s> 19 bytes:

```
(op regsub #/./" ")
```

Previously:

```
(op mapcar(ret[" "0]))
```

That is a function to which we can pass a string:

REPL:

```
1> (op regsub #/./" ")
#<interpreted fun: lambda #:rest-0164>
2> [*1 "abc"]
"   "

"   "
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojurescript, 27 bytes

```
#(apply str(map(fn[]" ")%))
```

Because it's based on js, clojurescript doesn't care about arity errors. That saves one byte over the clojure eqivalent.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows batch, 115 bytes

```
@set i=%~1
@set p=0
@set/ac=-1
:N
@call set t=%%i:~%p%,1%%
@set/ac+=1
@set/ap+=1
@if "%t%" NEQ "" @goto N
@echo %c%
```

*Re-used code from my answer in* ***Is the checkbox not not unchecked?***

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>12</s> 11+1 = <s>13</s> 12 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag. -1 byte from Martin Ender.

```ruby
gsub /./,$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyvrFgEpBR0C/6nF5cmKejr6euo6P//n5Gak5OvUJ5flJMCAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Check, 6 bytes

```
," "*o
```

Pass the input by the command-line arguments as a list of code points, i.e. `[72,101,108,108,111,44,32,87,111,114,108,100,33]`.

Explanation:

- `,` gets the length of the input.
- `" "` pushes an array containing `32` (for space).
- `*` repeats that array as many times as the length of the input.
- `o` displays the result as a list of characters.

Answer (score 0):

**Bash + Coreutils, 11 Bytes**

`tr -c \  \`

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
' '#~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU67bsJAEOz5isGWGJ90WNSOQEgJFpFcpaF27AUcOXeA11Iqft25gyIp9jGjndn5mpKcR6wL0GKFItQyf/2wVTkRTO/pZGbSnD347i6jYr1BVn/70SmcSCutAYnhUjcyhI0zbR5me@l7b3Hwt76dEy@B6eLICODNO1IJi6oMjaW/nURRf/rxH7v76Qbt3OmPOZw7lceveXChibbRtCqfGUM2JlzYeJvEqFGaXUevAnsHs4iDjBElxTY126NZ5BtoM/0C)

### Explanation

```
' '#~#
   #~    repeat
' '      spaces
     #   for length of input
```

Comment: 4 bytes `''"0` outputs n newlines.

Comment: @FrownyFrog You should make your own answer, it's quite different from mine

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 32 bytes

```
(format t"~va"(length(read))#\ )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jLb8oN7FEoUSprixRSSMnNS@9JEOjKDUxRVNTOUZB8/9/JY/UnJx8HYXy/KKcFEUlAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot/), 12 bytes

```
#^//()/gS" "
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/) (append a `^@^v@` after the code to see the spaces bounded between `@`s)

#### Explanation

```
#^            Set the stack-string to be equal to the input
/             Get matches of this regex
 /()/g         any position (not character) in the string (shorter than /\b|\B/ by 3 bytes)
              If the length of the string is 3, this returns a 4-element array
               consisting of empty strings
S" "          Join on spaces, so the example 4-element array will result in 3 spaces
```

The space can even be replaced with a literal newline or tab for the same bytecount.

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 18 bytes

```
?Zd[9P1-d0<r]sr0<r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@KiXaMsBQN8XApii2uAhI/v8fnZFaqZCbnxsLAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 9 bytes

```
iy[' o,];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zMlpdIV8n1vr//5LU4hIA)

Explanation:

```
iy[' o,];

iy        # push length of input
  [    ]  # while loop
   ' o    # output a space
      ,   # decrement input length
        ; # terminate (avoids implicit output)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 3 bytes

```
L•*
```

Uncreative solution is uncreative.

Just gets the length of the input, and multiplies `•`, which is predefined to be a space, by it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9/nUcMirf///2ek5mUrgAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>69</s> <s>68</s> <s>66</s> 64  bytes

```
def L:length;$x|if L<1then empty elif L<2then""else L-1|.*" "end
```

This is longer then usual to compensate for newline jq normally emits and the odd behavior of `*` with N<2

Sample runs:

```
$ jq -Mrn --arg x 'Hello, World!' 'def L:length;$x|if L<1then empty elif L<2then""else L-1|.*" "end'

$ jq -Mrn --arg x 'Hello, World!' 'def L:length;$x|if L<1then empty elif L<2then""else L-1|.*" "end' | wc -c
      13
$ echo -n 'def L:length;$x|if L<1then empty elif L<2then""else L-1|.*" "end' | wc -c
      64
```

Shout out to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech) for finding 3 superfluous spaces!

Comment: I do not know jq, but as `then""else` is syntactically valid, it seems like you could also omit the space in `" " end`.

Comment: As variables probably cannot begin with a digit, the spaces in `<1 then` and `<2 then` may also be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 4 bytes

```
VGr
```

(a trailing space)

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 37 bytes

Takes input, and outputs as many new lines as the length of the input

```vb
Line Input""s$
For i=1TO Len(s$)?Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3yczL1XBM6@gtERJqViFyy2/SCHT1jDEX8EnNU@jWEXT3i@1ouT//5DU4hKF5MTiVIXyzJIMheL8XCArI7MktbggMTkVAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 84 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write("".PadLeft(a[0].Length));}}
```

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsIwFEbhV7l0SgaD4CSOrhUKDh1Kh0sakwsxgd4fQUqfPSrCmb7heD149a35zKo0bAqGeHpVWejGUoxilRKnme12fyvC011r0ZqDG1dBMF3nBl768IDh6Ti7PpSIZO1l31trSKL0jen/ISTGD05nWiQKlHIt8QM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 20 bytes

```
{" ".repeat(length)}

{" ".repeat           // repeat space
           (length)}  // length of input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY2xCsJAEET7fMVw1V1hPiAQbS3s/IIT17i4bsK5CULIt58XCZZON7zHzKM3Yc1TFLBO/OKLUIOzJdau9gG7/VbQ5tnB1YkGiuaFtLN7WPJtVDwja3HnCiXrlNHb0CJRvJ5YqbBDA@e@fChrJup/d361Q/gH6@2uWvKRRPoP)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
Lð*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?s=?flags=&code=L%C3%B0*&inputs=Hello%20World&header=&footer=)

Command-line usage:

```
python3 Vyxal.py file_name "" input_string
```

### Explained

```
L    # Push the length of the implicit input
  ð  # Push a space character
   * # Multiply that space by the length and output.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 9 bytes

```forth
typewhite
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf@tFNL@l1QWpJZnZJak/rfmKlZS8EjNycnXUQjPL8pJUVRSMEopLVAAKVFILlJIAxIgNViE/wMA)

It is a [gforth built-in](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Displaying-characters-and-strings.html#Displaying-characters-and-strings). A string in gforth is commonly represented as `addr length`, and `typewhite` consumes `addr length` and prints `length` spaces.

Comment: forth golfing language confirmed?!

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 21 bytes

```
D,f,@@,bL*
$f>" ">?
o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HwUEnyUeLSyXNTklByc6eK/////8eqTk5@ToK4flFOSmKAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal), 7 bytes

```
1Â×^c¤E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFhiYxPzqGGRXbx1cWqKgm6mgrphsXWcNVDIWl0hXsHILq80x7qkqDQPqDRVQbdY11Ah3jo1OSNfQTdPQR2oLOnQMuPDW5yP7stQsrPR1tXTiY5VetSw0Evdzg6isEY/v6BEP784MSkzFUopxNslWYOFk4oSM/PSSpOzESyFpP@Gh5sOT49LPrTE9T/Qhv8eqTk5@ToK4flFOSmKAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 12 bytes

```sh
<<<${1//?/ }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpdpQX99eX6H2////iVxJyQA)

- `<<<`: print
- `${1}`: the input,
- `///`: replacing
- `?`: any character
- : with a space

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 20 bytes

```factor
[ [ drop bl ] each ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc09D4JADAbgvb@isLhoIn4smjj5ubgYw0AY8Khw8bzi3ZGYGH87AmEAu/Vp@/aeCMemul5O58MKJeODjCaFll4laUEW1wAf8I@kFI8xZKNSz0cPJxsM5rVLH3vV@gwa27IeOdizychhcuPSwe4trZM6gzCXjmyRCPLqzS5usQR/ENbFTWGove9/k@4ggC9UEUaYGi7wpjBGSkSOcY266QQ/C7bUavUD)

For each character in the input string, drop it from the data stack and output a space.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.292 bytes

```
;M/
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyI7TS8gIiwiSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISJd)

Note the space at the end.

```
;M/<space>
;M         # Replace all in the input
  /<space> # With a space
;          # Print without newline
```

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't output a trailing newline?  [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoJO6.png) is what it looks like when I run it... (I only checked because the same annoying thing was happening for my own attempt in Nibbles...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen ah yes, it does output with a newline. I missed that part of the spec. will update

Comment: If you can use the same code in the context of a function, maybe the returned string would be Ok...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen all the other golflang answers seem to do that too...

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 82 B

This `program` merely requires a processor complying to ISO standard 7185 “Pascal”.
Since it is not guaranteed that `writeLn` produces exactly one character (on some platforms the line separator is `CR+LF`), we’ll have to use `write(' ')`:

```pascal
program p(input,output);begin while not EOF do begin write(' ');get(input)end end.
```

If input was simply a `string` value, when an ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” processor is used the following is the shortest solution (**≥ 24 B**):

```pascal
writeStr(outputStringVariable, '':length(inputMyString))
```

The `:someNonNegativeIntegerValue` after the empty string `''` will (left) pad the given argument to the specified width using space characters (`' '`).
A complete demonstration:

```pascal
program paddingDemo(output); begin write('':length('Hello, World!')) end.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
L1-A_*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLfAx1HeO1IByo2IK1Hqk5Ofk6CuH5RTkpihBBAA)

Note: `A\` will also work instead of `A_` if you want newlines rather than spaces.

##### Explanation

```python
L1-A_*  # Implicit input
L       # Length
 1-     # Minus one
     *  # Multiplied by
   A_   # A space
        # Implicit print
        # with a newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
l⁻ṣ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy3MeNe5-uHPxkuKk5GKo2IK1Hqk5Ofk6CuH5RTkpihBBAA)

##### Explanation

```python
l⁻ṣ  # Implicit input
l    # Length
 ⁻   # Decrement
  ṣ  # Spaces
     # Implicit output with newline
```