# Print the missing characters

Tags: code-golf, string

Simple challenge inspired by the popularity of my previous [print invisible text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122703) and [print real invisible text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123447) challenges, and the [same length different string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123539) challenge.

Given a string consisting of only printable characters (`0x20 to 0x7E`), print every printable character not present in the string.

### Input

A string, or array of characters, consisting of only printable ASCII characters

### Output

Every printable ASCII character not present in the input string, in any order.

### Testcases

```
Input:  "Hello, World!"
Output: ""#$%&'()*+-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ[\]^_`abcfghijkmnpqstuvwxyz{|}~"
========
Input:  "Hi!"
Output: " "#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
========
Input:  ""
Output: " !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
========
Input:  " !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
Output: ""
```

### Scoring

This is code-golf so fewest bytes **in each language** wins

Comment: If returning an array, can we include empty elements in place of the used characters?

Comment: @Shaggy sure, that's fine

Comment: @Rod don't leak my plans D:

Comment: Can the output be a [Set](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Set) object of strings of the characters? `set( 'a', 'b', 'c' )`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills I'd prefer it be either a string or a plain array

Comment: @Mayube it was a joke, because it would be the same problem >.<

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/print-every-character-your-program-doesnt-have)

Comment: Can input/output be array of bytes, i.e. ordinals?

Comment: @MikhailV **only** if your language is unable to output ASCII characters

Answer (score 13):

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 2 bytes

```
ç7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/gs2#@394ufn//x6pOTn5Ogrh@UU5KYoA)

#### How it works

```
    (implicit) Push the sting of all characters in STDIN on the stack.
ç   Push the string of all printable ASCII characters.
 7  Perform symmetric set difference.
    (implicit) Print the result to STDOUT.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda n:{*map(chr,range(32,127))}-{*n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqlorN7FAIzmjSKcoMS89VcPYSMfQyFxTs1a3Wiuv9n9BUWZeiUaahpJHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqikqbmfwA)
Turns input into a set, and remove it from the set containing all ascii characters

Comment: This works after Python 3.5 only.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 29 bytes

```perl6
{[~] keys (' '..'~')∖.comb}
```

Note that the result is random because [Set](https://docs.perl6.org/language/setbagmix)s are unordered.

[Test it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#tc9LWtswEAfwvU4xGIrtYMu8W2KcUt60pVCebfNoHVsEJ7YlJBkIabLmBD0AnIPLcAFWrFPHhI/syAbt5pu/5jeTCALn89izUdSEcY/6BJxuq9gpQ4M0BWgqqBirHVW/v/6HPRpV2900uCSJkOBAGMREaDquccI0q1JZNItOuWDpmFNJuTatY58QFrks30IA@2kC0ohSLuTg4e5Gebi7tSwskqqQXJs0cuaUjtooSVc6SOfbiIVuDBMZZqMTyvuuWQCtFMQskUaJXDLiSeLr0BPS1UqciCTsLZcdk8XstOUHbg2eer0yEP0iOwoLyiWu0yA24Hmi8fQXM8JD1O5u9Yo8gLJJwpAacEx56I8oaCeRWUNRRsfejauanpswsTU5NT0zOzf//sNC3l50Ch@XPi2vrK6tb2x9/vJ1@9vO7ve9/YPDox8/fxVL5crvP27VO6mdBvVGFLMzIZPzi8vmVetvu6Mgp//QywLBIAsvrjE0fDwo@yS1640wiik746/pg/TIcPbma3gwtP625MBtHeUxpqbneqfkPw)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{
  [~]        # reduce using string concatenation
             # (shorter than ｢join '',｣)

  keys       # get the keys from the Set object resulting from the following

  (' '..'~') # Range of printable characters
  ∖          # Set minus (this is not \ )
  .comb      # split the input into individual characters
}
```

There is also an ASCII version of `∖` `(-)`, but it would require a space before it so that it isn't parsed as a subroutine call.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
Ho#_dÃf@bX ¥J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@@Rr1wfn3K4Oc0hKULh0FKv//@VPFJzcvJ1FMLzi3JSFJUA)

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Shaggy and obarakon

Comment: No need for the flag (see answer to my comment on the question). Replace `127` with [`#`](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=I38=&input=) to save a byte and remove the `U` to save another.

Comment: You can use `¦` and rearrange your arguments to save a few bytes. Also, 127 can be shortened [TIO](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=SG8jf0BVYlhkKaZKP1A6WGQ=&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi)

Comment: Got it down to 14 bytes: http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=SG8jf19kw2ZAYlggpUo=&input=ImhlbGxvIi1Q

Comment: @Shaggy Nice! Are you happy with me editing this answer with it or do you want to post your own?

Comment: No, you work away with it, Tom - as you said before, I need to learn to post quicker! :D

Comment: A 10 byte version but unfortunately non-competing: http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=SG8jf19kw2tVcQ==&input=ImhlbGxvIi1Q

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 32 bytes

```
f x=[y|y<-[' '..'~'],all(/=y)x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mUGEbXVlTaaMbra6grqenXqceq5OYk6Ohb1upWRGr8D83MTNPwVahoLQkuKTIJ09BRSFNQckjU1HpPwA)

Boring library function for set difference:

#### Haskell, 31 bytes

```
import Data.List
([' '..'~']\\)
```

Comment: Bottom looks more like an esolang

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
6Y2X~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@28WaRRR9/@/ukdqTk6@OgA)

Thanks to Luis Mendo for [golfing 8 bytes off!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37783520#37783520)

Explanation:

```
   X~   % The symmetric set difference
6Y2     % Between all printable ASCII
        % And the input string (implicit)
        % Implicitly display
```

*Symmetric set difference* will give every element that is present in exactly one of the two input sets. (but not both) This will always give the right answer, since the input set will always be a subset of the second set (all printable ASCII).

Original version:

```
32:126tGom~)c
```

Explanation:

```
32:126          % Push the range 32-126
      t         % Duplicate it on the stack
       G        % Push the input
        o       % Convert it to character points
         m      % Is member (0 for each char that isn't in input, 1 for each char that is)
          ~     % Logical NOT
           )    % Take the truthy elements of this array from the previous array (All Printable ASCII)
            c   % Display as a string
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ẹ;Ṭ↔x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9w107rhzvXPGqbUvH/v5JHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqi0v8oAA)

#### Explanation

```
ẹ          Split the input string into a list of chars
 ;Ṭ↔x      Exterminate the chars from the string Ṭ of printable ASCII chars
```

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

Thanks to @Luis Mendo saved 2 bytes.

```matlab
@(s)setxor(32:'~',s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gUaxZnFpSkV@kYWxkpV6nrlOs@T8xr1hDySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJ8z8A)

Other answer:

```matlab
@(s)setdiff(' ':'~',s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gUaxZnFqSkpmWpqGuoG6lXqeuU6z5PzGvWEPJIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUUnzPwA)

Comment: `@(s)setxor(' ':'~',s)` saves 1 byte

Comment: @LuisMendo Very nice! But I think that is a different thing. I suggest that you post it as a new answer :)

Comment: No, it's really just a minor improvement. I'll be happy that you post it if you want. BTW `@(s)setxor(32:'~',s)` seems to work too --- and same comment for that :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, I agree because (Luis) said.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

I'm sure there's a shorter way to do this!

```
s=>[...Array(95)].map((_,y)=>s.includes(c=String.fromCharCode(y+32))?"":c)
```

---

### Try it

```js
let f=
s=>[...Array(95)].map((_,y)=>s.includes(c=String.fromCharCode(y+32))?"":c)
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value).join``
o.innerText=f(i.value="Hello, World!").join``
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

Comment: Should be `Array(95)` to include the missing `~`

Comment: Was that always there, @Malivil? Could've sworn the last character was `}` when I wrote this up. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Can't believe C# is shorter than JavaScript for this, especially as I have to include my usings.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, `String.fromCharCode` is a git, that's why! :D

Comment: @Shaggy I dunno, I just was looking at your code to see how it worked and I typed literally every symbol on my keyboard and noticed `~` didn't change anything but that it was in the spec. Also, the "Try It" part needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 39 bytes

```
s!.*!"pack(c95,32..126)=~y/$_//dr"!ee
```

Run with `perl -pe`.

Comment: I get the error message 'Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 2, near "y/Hello World!//dr"' when I run this...

Comment: Full command-line: ```echo 'Hello World!' | perl -pe 's!.*!"pack(c95,32..126)=~y/$_//dr"!ee'```. This works for me on both Perl v5.14 and v5.24.

Comment: It's Perl v5.10 that's not working... Must be a change made between 5.10 and 5.14.

Comment: Nice answer, good use of `pack`! You can save a few bytes utilising `-a` too: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rYgMTlbIdnSVMfYSE/P0MjMOrUsMUepUt/BTV8/Ren/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFMV/@QUlmfl5xf91CxIB "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <del>47 43</del> 40 bytes

```bash
printf %x {32..126}|xxd -r -p|tr -d "$1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19QlJlXkqagWqFQbWykp2doZFZbU1GRoqBbpKBbUFMCJFMUlFQMlf7//w8A)

Generates hexa range, inverts hex dump to char an removes characters present in first parameter.

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 13 bytes

```
⍞~⍨⎕UCS31+⍳95
```

Straightforward:

```
       31+⍳95  ⍝ A vector 32 .. 126
   ⎕UCS        ⍝ as characters
 ~⍨            ⍝ without
⍞              ⍝ those read from character input.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
žQsм
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7A4gt7/v/3SM3JyddRCM8vyklRBAA)

```
žQsм  # full program
   м  # remove...
  s   # implicit input...
   м  # from...
žQ    # all ASCII characters
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 42 Bytes

Input as array

Output as string

```
<?=join(array_diff(range(" ","~"),$_GET));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUol3dw2xjVbyUNJRSgXiHCjOB2IQVADicCi/CCqXAsSKSrHWXPZ2/23sbbPyM/M0EouKEivjUzLT0jSKEvPSUzXAOuuUNHXANmhqWv//DwA)

## PHP, 53 Bytes

Input as string

Output as string

```
<?=join(array_diff(range(" ","~"),str_split($argn)));
```

replace `<?=join` with `print_r` for an output as array

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVfJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFUsuayt/tvY2@blZ@Zp5FYVJRYGZ@SmZamUZSYl56qoaSgpKNUp6SpU1xSFF9ckJNZogE2RVNT0/r/fwA)

Comment: Maybe you should make a golf version of PHP :P

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I am sure that exists but it is not really good

Comment: Maybe you should make a good one. Step 1: automatic starting tag.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I have search the link for you. https://github.com/barkermn01/PGP-php-CodeGolf/ I have no interest to make one

Comment: Well, things can get shorter than that.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Making PHP a golfing language destroys what is the fun in golfing with PHP (at least for me): you have to constantly balance between calling functions (which often have long names), using loops, different input methods and so on. `Step 1: automatic starting tag` well `php -r` ... but e.g. in this example it doesn't pay of because `echo` is longer than `<?=`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*Really, 8 bytes? Please, tell me I missed something!*

```
32r126Ọḟ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@29sVGRoZPZwd8/DHfP///@vFJKRqlBYmpmcrZBUlF@ep5CWX6GQVZpbkJqikF@WWqRQApTPSayqVEjJTy/WUwIA)**

#### How?

```
32r126Ọḟ - Main link: list of characters s
32r126   - inclusive range from 32 to 126 = [32,33,...,125,126]
      Ọ  - cast ordinals to characters = list of printable characters
       ḟ - filter discard if in s
```

---

Alternatively

```
“ ~‘r/Ọḟ - Main link
“ ~‘     - code-page indexes = [32,126]
    r/   - reduce by inclusive range = [32,33,...,125,126]
      Ọ  - cast from ordinals to characters = list of printable characters
       ḟ - filter discard if in s
```

---

Since this challenge a new atom which yields all printable ASCII characters, `ØṖ`, has been introduced making the following work for 3 bytes:

```
ØṖḟ
```

Comment: No you didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
'␡,32>q^
```

Where `␡` is a literal delete character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@69er2NsZFcY9/@/R2pOTr6OQnh@UU6KIgA)

```
'␡,       e# The range of all characters up to ~.
   32>    e# Slice it to be the range of all characters from space to ~.
      q^  e# Symmetric set difference with the input.
```

Comment: Just as a note, `-` works instead of `^`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <strike>23</strike> <strike>18</strike> 17 bytes

```
->s{[*' '..?~]-s}
```

Uses a lambda function as per @sethrin's comments.

Previous versions:

```
[*' '..?~]-s.chars

(' '..'~').to_a-s.chars
```

Comment: Doesn't `s` have to be either read from STDIN or supplied as a function argument? The challenge also specifies that the input may be given as an array of characters. Converting to a stabby lambda and dropping `chars` gives a 16-byte solution.

Comment: I wasn't really sure how the input was to be addressed, given that it wasn't explicitly specified. There are a few other answers that assume the existence of the input in a variable. Is there a codegolf convention? I don't do this much.

Comment: @sethrin With a stabby lambda wouldn't it be 20 chars? `->(s){[*' '..?~]-s)}`

Comment: All of the parentheses in your lambda are optional. But I may have miscounted a byte. Other languages either accept input implicitly or have `stdin` bound to a global variable. In Ruby `$<` is a shortcut for `stdin` but lambdas tend to be shorter. The conventions on input and output are [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). I also don't do this much, so if the rules aren't what I think do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 120 bytes

```
+[+[>+<+<]>]>-[[>>]+[<<]>>-],[<+++++[>------<-]>-[>[>>]+[<<]>-]>[>>]<[-]<[-<<]>,]++++++++[->++++<]>[>[-<.>]<[->>+<<]>>+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#RY0xCoBADAS/onUuviBs7Q8slnTaHRz4fzizIjgQwiZDMo1GWFgkEk4CaYxK8GwME4S/hEvB71RWCLpKk5b2QYdaSKnd9mqoV7ptOed@9T7acoy7n@sD)

Wrapped:

```
+[+[>+<+<]>]>-[[>>]+[<<]>>-],[<+++++[>--
----<-]>-[>[>>]+[<<]>-]>[>>]<[-]<[-<<]>,
]++++++++[->++++<]>[>[-<.>]<[->>+<<]>>+]
```

Explained:

```
+[+[>+<+<]>]>-         initialize what we will now consider cell 0 to 95
[[>>]+[<<]>>-]         initialize cells 2 4 etc 95*2 to 1; end on cell 0 at 0
,[                     main input loop (for each char of input)
  <+++++[>------<-]>-  subtract 31 from the input
  [>[>>]+[<<]>-]       lay a trail of (input minus 31) ones in the empty spaces
  >[>>]<[-]<[-<<]>     use the trail to clear the appropriate "print" flag
,]                     keep reading input until it ends
++++++++[->++++<]>     initialize the cell directly before flag 1 to 32
[                      we'll let the accumulator overflow; no harm done
  >[-<.>]              print the accumulator if the flag is still set
  <[->>+<<]>>+         shift over the accumulator and increment it
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 3 bytes

```
α@─
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ohm#@39uo8OjKQ3//0ere6jrqKcCcQ4U5wOxAhCXQ9lFUPEU9dj/AA)

Note: you can also enter your input as a string ([example](https://tio.run/nexus/ohm#@39uo8OjKQ3//3uk5uTkK4TnF@WkKP4HAA)), but it fails for the empty input case.

Answer (score 2):

### [Julia](https://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```
s->setdiff(' ':'~',s)
```

Comment: [TIO link](https://tio.run/##FcnJQsIwFEDRPV/xiNUk2iA4i1JHsM4Dzk1VsEkNxBSbIqjIr1dZ3LO5nb5Wrcowl7W2iJXJLfOsyCIlJcGAq3iMXUtzYaJCIYBeqkymTYkgx3LjEEkshZEHzex/xJQbxhgCCjJJwYIyECBfaJ3AIEl1VEQuIF9NnARFjqa4Mz2DCZ2dc1lpvlxZWFxaXlldW69ubNa8re2d3b39euPAPzw6Pjk9O7@4vGpe39ze3T88BpyHT8/8pdV@jYSM31Snq99N0vtIbdb/HAy/vn9Gv2MUQpj/AQ) for this solution

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

```
PADCa
```

Removes all chacracters in the input from a predefined variable.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/wNHFOfH///8eqTk5@YoA)

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
PARM(X^a)
```

Converts the characters of the input to regex, and removes the characters from the printable ASCII builtin.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/wDHIVyMiLlHz////Hqk5OfmKAA)

Comment: `DC` is your friend for this challenge. ;)

Comment: What a perfect builtin.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>14</s></sup> 10 bytes

```apl
⍞~⍨' '…'~'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@j3nl1j3pXqCuoP2pYpl6nDhL9rwAEaVzqjk7OLq7qAA)

-4 bytes from Adám!(inclusive range)

### Explanation

```apl
   ' '…'~'     range of chars in visible ASCII range
  ⍨            flip the arguments of the function on the left
⍞~             Get all characters not in input
```

Comment: Fixed the mistake..

Comment: [-4](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@j3nl1j3pXqCuoP2pYpl6nDhL9rwAEaVzqjk7OLq7qAA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online"): `⍞~⍨' '…'~'`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes

```
.-srd\
-srd\
```

<strike>`.-`</strike> `-` Subtract the second string from the first:

1. `srd\` Create a range from space char to the delete char
2. *implicitly read input*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X0@3uCglpv7/fyWP1JycfIXw/KKcFEUlAA)

Answer (score 2):

## MUMPS, 35 bytes

```
r r,! f i=32:1:126 w:r'[$c(i) $c(i)
```

**Explanation**

- Assign input to `r` and write a newline (`!`)
- Loop from 32 to 126 and if r doesn't contain (`'[`) the character representation of the ASCII value (`$char()`, can be shortened to `$c()`), write the that character representation.
- You can attach conditionals to commands with a colon. So `w:1>0 "True"` is the same as `if 1>0 write "True"`

[Try the code here](https://tio.run/##yy3NLSj@/18BCMqLMktSFZQ8UnNy8nUUwvOLclIUlf7/BwA)

Comment: Nice answer & nice explanation.  Is there an online interpreter for MUMPS and can you post a link to it so we can play with the code?

Comment: Thanks! I added a link to tio.run. You can change the code / inputs to explore

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>39</s> 32 bytes

```powershell
$a=$args
' '..'~'|?{$_-cnotin$a}
```

Added splatting and case sensitivity

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczNCkBAEADg@z7F0GQveANx9ADu2jTslnY0SPLz6sP961v4IFk9zXMxsJDiCBVciq5CJ9NqLNiytK@96wv7Yoi8hYju0ccYDPG3aRug8ySUg@cDnBCcvCd1arL/akJU/QA)

Inspired by `colsw`'s answer

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kcḍ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS7OTH-7oXVKclFwMFVmw1iM1JydfRyE8vygnRREiCAA)

##### Explanation

```python
kcḍ  # Implicit input
  ḍ  # Symmetric set difference with...
kc   # ...all printable ASCII characters
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

-1 byte by using `∖` from `math.unicode` instead of `diff`, as suggested by @chunes

```ruby
[ 32 126 [a,b] swap ∖ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxZVsIwGIXfu4qfOIFSlKKo4DwBDjggorZVQxtoIE1K2oKK@OwK3IRL8M2luJFa4eUO3z3ntrAVCBnVa5VqqQBdIjlh4JNeSLhFfHBx4GRCTi1hk0mRmLfjgQogfcygqCiM8hggBB1B@ZgmQVX/TyAV6ZDTIKvlQcfppgn@AHvw@/EJZuTGSQf084Vi@Ubgh1KKkNvgScoDMIFgy4mGCgAqE8ZEGhpCMjuBxoROfCyQMNDU9MzsXDI1v5BWM4tLWS23vJJfXVsvFDc2t7Z3dvf2Dw6PSuXK8cnpWfX84vKqdl2/adze3euGYT48PuGmZZNW26GdLnO58HrSD8L@4Pnldfg2ekfK6A8)

TIO uses an old build of Factor; on the latest version, `[a,b]` from `math.ranges` has moved to `[a..b]` from `ranges`.

#### Explanation

| Code | Explanation | Stack |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[ ... ]` | Quotation (anonymous function) | `"Hello!"` |
| `32 126 [a,b]` | Inclusive range from 32 to 126 | `"Hello!" T{ range f 32 95 1 }` |
| `swap` | Swap so range is below input | `T{ range f 32 95 1 } "Hello!"` |
| `∖` | Set difference | `" \"#$%&'()*+,-./012..."` |

This works because in Factor, a string is basically a list of codepoints, and all sequences are `set`s.

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##JYlZWsIwGEXfu4qfOGsFKYoKTjgBDjggorZVQxpopE1K0oqK@OwK3IRL8M2luJHaD17OvefeNiahkHGjXq2VC9ClklMPFO1FlBOqwMehm444I8KhY5GYd5KDCShq2kADQBXqeUKHppCek0KjhY1zBEhZaGJyanpmdm5@QV9MZ5ayRm55Jb@6tl4obmxube@Udvf2Dw7LlerR8clp7ez84rJ@1bhu3tzemZZl3z884hZxaLvjsqeu53MR9KQKo@f@y@vb4H34gbRhbELOgKyRBxPrLRtUHwfw9/kFduwnzQT0@40S/CBQkZQi4g4EkvEQbKCYuPE/ "Factor – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 50 bytes

```r
function(s)intToUtf8(setdiff(32:126,utf8ToInt(s)))
```

returns an anonymous function. Converts the input string to integers, computes the set difference between the printable range and the input values, and then converts them back to a string and returns it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#S7P9n1aal1ySmZ@nUayZmVcSkh9akmahUZxakpKZlqZhbGRlaGSmUwoUC8n3zCsBKtLU/J@moe6RmpOTr6MQnl@Uk6KorvkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

-1 thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)

```
žQsK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X2Cx9///0eoe6jrqqUCcA8X5QAyCCkAcDuUXQeVSgFhRPRYA)

```
žQ   # Push all printable characters
  s  # Swap input to the top
   K # Push a with no b's (remove input characters from all printable character)
```

Comment: @FrodCube Oops... I forgot to update the link. It should work now. [TIO (empty input)](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X2Cx9///0bEA)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>74</s> 71 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>new int[95].Select((n,i)=>(char)(i+32)).Except(s);
```

Old version with creating a range for 74 bytes:

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>Enumerable.Range(32,95).Select(n=>(char)n).Except(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>75</s> <s>72</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

Thanks to Peter -1 byte

```c
i;f(s){for(i=31;++i<127;index(s,i)?:putchar(i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk2jWLM6Lb9II9PW2NBaWzvTxtDI3DozLyW1QqNYJ1PT3qqgtCQ5IxGoQFPTuvZ/bmJmnoYmVzWXAhCkaSh5pObk5OsohOcX5aQoKmlaA1UXaygBGSB5uKJMnFK4xBUUY5SUVVTV1DU0tbR1dPX0DQyNjE1MzcwtLK2sbWzt7B0cnZxdXN3cPTy9vH18/fwDAoOCQ0LDwiMio6JjYmLj4hMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy8/ILCouKS0rLyisqq6prauuQLQZbylX7HwA)

Comment: Can you use `||` to make this work on "standard" C?

Comment: @Neil Yes || also works.  Isn't ?: part of "standard" C?

Comment: I always thought it was a gcc extension.

Comment: @Neil That's correct. `?:` is a GNU extension. It works as well in clang and tcc though.

Comment: You can remove 1 byte by replacing `strchr` with `index`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 53 bytes

```php
for($k=31;$k++<126;)~strstr($argn,$k)?:print chr($k);
# or
for($k=31;$k++<126;)echo~strstr($argn,$k)?"":chr($k);
```

Run as pipe with `-r`.

Comment: I have left no more playground

Comment: @JörgHülsermann You do. You just have to share it.

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 20 bytes

```
òiÎflax
òcH ¬ ~@"<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394U@bhvjTpnMQKrsObkj0UDq1RqJN2ULL5/98jNScnX6E8vygnBQA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: f269 ce66 1b6c 6178 0af2 6348 20ac 207e  .i.f.lax..cH . ~
00000010: 1b40 223c                                .@"<
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>18</s> <s>15</s> <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
Ｆγ¿¬№θιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBI11TITNNQcMvv0TDOb80r0SjUEchU1NTUyGgKBPIy9S0/v/fIzUnJ19HoTy/KCdFkeu/btl/3eIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 3 bytes by ranging over characters instead of integers. Saved a further 5 bytes when I discovered the undocumented `γ` variable which holds the printable ASCII characters. Saved a further 2 bytes when @ASCII-only fixed predefined inputs in verbose mode (the answer is still valid as it stands, it's only the try it online link that wouldn't have worked at the time).

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBI11TITNNQcMvv0TDOb80r0SjUEchU1NTUyGgKBPIy9S0/v/fIzUnJ19HoTy/KCdFkeu/btl/3eIcAA) (unless preinitialized inputs weren't working back then)

Comment: @ASCII-only They weren't working in verbose mode... they would probably have worked in succinct mode, but I like the verbose links.

Comment: It turns out this can be 6 bytes: `Φγ¬№θι`: simply filter out all characters from the (now document) variable `γ` that appear in the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), <del>20</del> 12 bytes

-8 bytes [thanks to coltim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123723/print-the-missing-characters/127111?noredirect=1#comment503438_127111).

```
^[`c$32+!94]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHXAkIAAADAd1@BlAYptLS39p7SRIkoRPvXdafguuK6ErPmtgeEIkNQiuZdCY0wMCGINmFagqzBLiuqqo6Bjm6oAgSwMgQAIAR7EK8P9QeCIQwPE5EoSdGxeCKZYtKZbC5fKJbKlWqtzjaarXan2@sPhqPxZDqbL5bcil9vtrv9QRCl40k@K@pF0683w7TutvN4vt6f7@8P)

Explanation:

```
     32+!94  /list of int values of all printable characters
  `c$        /turn into characters
^[         ] /partial function application of "except"
```

What except `^` does is remove all instances of each of element in the right/second argument from the left/first argument.

Comment: I think this can be trimmed down to [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P80qLjohWcXYSFvR0iT2f5q6hpJHak5Ovo5CeX5RToqikrWSRyaIBCIFxRglZRVVNXUNTS1tHV09fQNDI2MTUzNzC0sraxtbO3sHRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXz//gMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomNi4@ITEpOSU1LT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKquqa2jolzf8odnMBbebiUlCkqaUA) by using `^` except.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
-⁰…" ~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/dR44ZHDcuUFOr@//@v5JGak5OvoxCeX5SToqgEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 66 bytes

```
let s=stdin.readAll
for c in' '..'~':
 if c notin s:stdout.write c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDADAva@IUxfpAwoObv7AWdoUAjGBNOLm12vX44TuMRgd@ta9kiTDq@7MoalBAZIIMaX4xRyA2hRRJ4Ge59bH02vkCGWMA5l1hVON6/ID)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
kQ?F
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrUT9GIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISJd)

##### Explanation

```python
kQ   # Printable ASCII
  ?F # Without the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2.5 bytes

```
--_"\n"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWy3V145Vi8pQgPKjg1milGCWP1JycfB2F8PyinBTFGCWlWKgkAA)

Unfortunately, the printable characters built-in in Nibbles also includes the newline, so we have to explicitly exclude it.

### Explanation

```
--_"\n"
-       List subtract
 -       list subtract
  _       printable characters
   "\n"   newline
         input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Flip](https://github.com/jfioasd/Flip), 21 bytes

```
'  |D '+1<D:|g DX: #
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLSezYMGCpaUlaboWW9UVFGpcFNS16w1tXKxq0hVcIqwUlCFyUCUL1nmk5uTk6yiE5xflpChyQUQB)

ATO is not working right now, but I tested this locally. Contains a raw `\x7F` byte.

This would have been easier if I hadn't removed the `J` builtin, which generates an inclusive range.

### Explanation

```
                             Push printable ASCII onto stack:

'                            Push space character
                             Loop body:
    D                            Duplicate the current char
      ' \x7f                     Push 127
          <                      Less than?
            :                    If so, mirror & do the following:
           D                         Duplicate TOS
         1
       +                             Add by 1
   |                                 Mirror the IP

                             Setwise difference w/ input:

              g              Read 1 char from the input
                D            Duplicate
                  :          Pop, is it nonzero? (i.e. not at EOF)
                             If so, mirror:
                 X               Remove all occurences of
                                 this char in the stack.
             |                   Mirror the IP back

                    #        When loop done, print entire stack as a string.
                             Terminate program.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 17 bytes

```arturo
$=>[--@` `..`~`&]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?PVRAU3)

Takes and returns a list of characters.

```
$=>[         ; a function where input is assigned to &
    --       ; set difference
    @        ; reify range
    ` `..`~` ; the range of printable ascii characters
    &        ; input
]            ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL (SQL Server 2016), 519 bytes

```
with X as(select 32a,char(32)b union all select a+1,char(a+1)from X where a<126),E AS(SELECT n FROM(VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)),F AS(SELECT a.n FROM E a,E b),G AS(SELECT a.n FROM F a,F b),T AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))n FROM G),I as(SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(t,n,1))a FROM T JOIN(select @i as t)S on T.n<=LEN(S.t)where n=0),R as(select b from X where a not in(select a from I))select STUFF((SELECT''+b FROM R FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

... but this assumes the input string is in `@i`, therefore a runnable script will look like:

```
declare @i varchar(101) = 'Test';
    
with X as(select 32a,char(32)b union all select a+1,char(a+1)from X where a<126),E AS(SELECT n FROM(VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)),F AS(SELECT a.n FROM E a,E b),G AS(SELECT a.n FROM F a,F b),T AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))n FROM G),I as(SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(t,n,1))a FROM T JOIN(select @i as t)S on T.n<=LEN(S.t)where n=0),R as(select b from X where a not in(select a from I))select STUFF((SELECT''+b FROM R FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://dbfiddle.uk/zVld4sGJ)

#### How it works

Use CTEs to split the input string into individual characters on separate rows in a result set; use a recursive CTE to generate a result set having individual characters on separate rows for all characters between ASCII values 32 and 126; select all rows from the latter where characters are not found in the former; use `STUFF` with `FOR XML PATH` to aggregate those characters (in lieu of the `STRING_AGG` function, which only arrived in SQL Server 2017).

#### Legible version

```
declare @input varchar(101) = 'Test';


with X as (
    select 32a, char(32)b
    union all
    select a+1, char(a+1) from X where a < 126
),
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
),
INPUT_STRING as (
    SELECT ASCII( SUBSTRING(term, n, 1)) as [ASCII Code]
    FROM cteTally t
    JOIN (select @input as term) S on t.n <= LEN(S.term)
    where n = 0
),
DATA_RESULTS as (
     select b from X where a not in (select [ASCII Code] from INPUT_STRING) 
 )
 
 select STUFF( (SELECT '' + b FROM DATA_RESULTS FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '' ) 
 ;
```

#### Why?

Because I can.

#### Can it be shorter?

Almost certainly!

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
20~CharacterRange~126~Complement~#&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a list of characters as input and returns a list of characters as output.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```
f=(s,i=95)=>i?f(s,i-1)+(s.includes(c=String.fromCharCode(i+31))?'':c):''
```

This builds the string recursively, excluding characters found in the input.

**Snippet:**

```js
f=(s,i=95)=>i?f(s,i-1)+(s.includes(c=String.fromCharCode(i+31))?'':c):''

console.log(f('Hello, World!'));
console.log(f('Hi'));
console.log(f(''));
console.log(f(' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 78 bytes

```
s=io.read()for i=32,126 do c=string.char(i)io.write(s:find(c,1,1)and""or c)end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 38 bytes

```
cC|d
dXpc
=`I&
LM-1I
d@7F&
€92-
r4*2
```

#### Explanation

We first `r`ead the input string and explode it (`€`, put the characters on the stack). Next, we push the numbers 34 (`94*2-`) and 127 (`27F1-`). The second value is then removed from the stack and memorized (`M`):

```
 M-1
  7F
€92-
r4*2
```

We then first set a catch mark so we can jump back to this place, and then `d`uplicate the number on the stack (the 34). We load the 126 from the quick memory and test for equality, in which case we exit:

```
 X
=`
L
d@
```

Otherwise, we duplicate the value again, convert it to a character of that number and check whether that character is already on the stack (`dcC`). If it is, we mirror to the right side:

```
cC|
d
```

Otherwise, we duplicate the value and convert it to a character again, print that character, increment the value and raise an exception, jumping back to the catch mark.

```
   d
  pc
  I&
```

If we mirrored, we just increment and raise an exception, too (`I&`).

Answer (score 0):

## C, 57 bytes

```
i=32;f(char*s){for(;i<127;i++)!strchr(s,i)?putchar(i):0;}
```

How it works:

- Initially sets `i` to 32, the ASCII character code for the space (the first printable ASCII character).
- The function `f` takes a string `s`, the "input".
- Loops, incrementing `i` until it reaches `~` (126), the last printable ASCII character.
- `!strchr(s,i)` checks if `i` is *not* in `s`. If `i` is not in `s`, print `i`. Otherwise, do nothing.

I'm sure this can be golfed.

Comment: +1 to neutralize the downvoter, but isn't it currently excluding the `~`? Shouldn't it be `<='~'` or (not sure if this is possible in C) `i<127`)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh huh, missed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>48</s> 45 bytes

```
^
95$*~¶
+T`p`_p`(.)(?=\1)
s`(.)(?=.*\1)|¶.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP47L0lRFq@7QNi7tkISChPiCBA09TQ172xhDTa5iKFtPC8irObRNT4vr/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFLo9MRS4uBUUlZRVVNXUNTS1tHV09fQNDI2MTUzNzC0sraxtbO3sHRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXz//gMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomNi4@ITEpOSU1LT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKquqa2joA) Includes test cases. Works by prepending a line of 95 `~`s, translating them into the printable ASCII characters, then deleting duplicate characters and the original input. Edit: Saved 3 bytes by matching the characters to be translated individually.

Answer (score 0):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 33 bytes

```
i;AOi=31;++i<'~';strchr(*@,i)?:Pi
```

Conversions made in this program:

- `A` -> `int main(int argc, char **argv) {`
- `O` -> `for(`
- `@` -> `argv`
- `P` -> `putchar`
- Auto-inserted closing `));}`

The resulting program looks like:

```
i;int main(int argc, char **argv){for(i=31;++i<'~';strchr(*argv,i)?:putchar(i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v8/09rRP9PW2NBaWzvTRr1O3bq4pCg5o0hDy0EnU9PeKiDz/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), 17 bytes

```
Vr32 127I!}CNzpCN
```

The naive approach.

### Explanation:

```
Vr32 127I!}CNzpCN
Vr32 127             For N in [32, 127[
           CN        Get the ASCII character for the code N
        I!}  z       If it is in the input string...
              pCN    ...then print it
```

[Test it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Vr32+127I%21%7DCNzpCN&input=Hello%2C+World%21&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 60 or 49 bytes

```
#(apply str(sort(apply disj(set(map char(range 32 127)))%)))
```

These "apply"s are killing me :/ Oh, if returning a list is fine then this is a bit shorter.

```
#(sort(apply disj(set(map char(range 32 127)))%))
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 32 bytes

```
[32,126|X=chr$(a)~instr(;,X)|\?X
```

Time to implement `chr$` and `instr` in QBIC...

```
[32,126|    Loop from 32 to 126
X=chr$(a)   Make X$ to be the character with Ascii value a (a is our loop counter)
~instr(;,X) If our input string (read from cmd line) contains cjar X$
|           THEN (empty, no-op)
\?X         ELSE, print char X$
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 68 bytes

```
s->{for(char c=31;++c<127;System.out.print(s.contains(c+"")?"":c));}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jZBZV8IwEIXf@RVD3VoLVUBFKYu7uIALKiqghrRAICS1CShi/es1LE8@cU7mYWbu3PuddNEQxbnnsq7TCzFFQkAJETaOABAmXb@FsAvlSQsw5MQBrFekT1gbhGGraaBKPSGRJBjKwCAHoYjnxy3u67iDfMC5VMI2TZxNJNN2ZSSk27f4QFqecpG6sDBnUiUKHZuaZhQ0LYMNww5CO6J8vUGTKt@5/RSgr8RzhloDkDFjYxbWtaJLKY9BlfvUiWpTPoD/kZTp883shiyqXFAG0bq2tLyyuqYb62Ysbm1sJpKpre2d9O5exs7m8oX9g8Oj45PTs@L5xeVVqXx9c3tXuX94rD49v9Tq9cbr2ztqYsdttTuk26N9xr0PX8jB8PNr9D3@CX4VxyRs@vlB@Ac)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 4 bytes

```
~KR-
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7EKR-&input=Hello%2C+World%21)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 52 bytes

I feel like there ought to be a shorter way to grab all the unicode characters than this set comprehension, but I haven't found it yet.

```
lambda s:''.join({chr(i+34)for i in range(93)}-set(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 44 Bytes

```
[char[]](32..126|?{$_-notin[char[]]"$args"})
```

creates an array of the numbers `32` through `126` (printable char codes)

finds the char codes not present in the input `$args` and then converts them back to a `char` array.

apparently the `1..5 -gt 3` trick doesn't work for `-in` or `-notin`, which would save a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 79 bytes

```
(defun f(s)(dotimes(x 95)(let((y(code-char(+ 32 x))))(or(find y s)(princ y)))))
```

Very straightforward code.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;EkU1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0VrVTE&input=WwoiSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISIKIkhpISIKIiIKIiAhIyQlJSYnKCkqKywtLi8wMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ojs8PT4/QEFCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaW1xdXl9gYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXp7fH1%2bIgonICEjJCIlJSYoKSorLC0uLzAxMjM0NTY3ODk6Ozw9Pj9AQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVpbXF1eX2BhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ent8fX4nCl0tbVI) - includes all test cases

Note that quotation marks in input strings cannot be escaped in Japt and `%`s must be escaped with `%%`.