# Same length, different string

Tags: code-golf, string

### Challenge

Given a non-empty string *S* of length *L* consisting entirely of printable ASCII chars, output another string of length *L* that consists entirely of printable ASCII chars, but is not equal to *S*.

For the purposes of this challenge, a printable ASCII char is one between U+0020 and U+007E, inclusive; that is, from   (space) to `~` (tilde). Newlines and tabs are not included.

For example, given `"abcde"`, some valid outputs could be:

- `"11111"`
- `"abcdf"`
- `"edcba"`

But these would be invalid:

- `"abcde"`
- `"bcde"`
- `"abcde0"`

#### Test cases

```
"asdf"
"1111"
"       "
"~~~~~"
"abcba"
"1"
" "
"~"
" ~"
"~ "
"  0"
"!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGhijklmnop1234567890"
" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
```

#### Rules

- You may assume the input consists entirely of printable ASCII chars.
- You may not assume that the input does not contain all 95 printable chars.
- You may assume the input contains at least one character and is less than 256 chars long.
- The output must also consist entirely of printable ASCII chars. You could not, for example, output the byte \x7F for input `"~"`.
- The output must be different than the input with probability 1; that is, you may generate random strings until one is different than the input, but you can't just output *L* random characters and hope it's different.
- Newlines are disallowed in the output, but you may output one trailing newline which is not counted toward the string.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.**

Comment: Note that "positive" excludes the empty string. For extra clarity, maybe replace "positive" with "nonzero"?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline But that would include negative-length strings /s

Comment: ...Those don't exist.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Better now?

Comment: ....really? -_- Also yes.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122703/38550)

Comment: Another simple but not trivial challenge.

Answer (score 36):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 21 bytes

```python
lambda s:`s`[:len(s)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PYzJDoIwFEXX7VeUOpS6EmdJmjj7EVZDEQgoIGkx7vh17JPEu7j3Dee9RMg2V0UYKWL8wAQXP49L1/Br@0mzPCaej5ERWVm9a5djpEVilxgpY2JdE@0I82/gUHMhugcYVTorLdJSZaKEYupZ2SCdbNWAbKrwHioAYAtzSLCG/PixdWfT6w9uw5HLt7v94Xg6p9njmRflq/Im09l8sVytAWMUM8owkxKMSsa@)

Takes the string representation of the input string and truncates it to the length of the input string. For a typical string, this puts it in `'` quotes and chops off the end:

```
abc  ->   'abc'  ->  'ab
     rep        chop
```

Note that the new string starts with `'`. Let's show that the output always differs from the input.

- If the input has no `'`, then the output starts with `'` and the input does not.
- If the input contains a `'` and but no `"`, then Python will use `"` for the outer quotes, giving a first character `"` that's not in the input string.
- If the input has both `'` and `"`, then the outer quotes are `'` and each `'` is escaped as `\'`. Wherever the first `"` appears in the input, it's shifted right by the initial `'` in the output and by any possible escaping. This means it cannot match with a `"` in the corresponding position in the output.

Finally, note that quoting the input and possibly escaping characters always increases the number of characters, so truncating the output makes it the same length as the input.

Note that it was crucial that Python adaptively switches to `"` in the second case. If it didn't do so, it would fail on the three-character input `'\'`. Or, any longer prefix of the [fix show string](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@ZW5BfVKLgkliSqOdWmpdckpmfx5WbmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgopCWWaFQnJFf/v8/AA) using `'`. So, this method won't work for most languages.

Comment: What's the reasoning for indexing 'til `len(s)` rather than `-2`?

Comment: @JulianWolf For an input containing both `'` and `"`, more than 2 characters will have been added because the quotes need to be escaped.

Comment: Makes sense; hadn't considered that. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `[2:]` instead of `[:len(s)]` to get down to 16 chars.

Comment: @xbarbie That doesn't always give the same length, if there are characters needing escaping.

Comment: @xnor Oh, I see now, `'\"\''` is such example... Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ÇÈJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4/XCH1///CopKyiqqauoamlraOrp6@gaGRsYmpmbmFpZW1ja2dvYOjk7OLq5u7h6eXt4@vn7@AYFBwSGhYeERkVHRMbFx8QmJSckpqWnpGZlZ2Tm5efkFhUXFJaVl5RWVVdU1tXUGhgA)

```
Ç   # Convert to ASCII values
 È  # is even? (0 is 48 and 1 is 49 therefore 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0)
  J # Join
```

Comment: Nice, very clever

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>37</s> <s>33</s> <s>36</s> <s>29</s> <s>26</s> <s>18</s> <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
s=>s.slice(1)+ +!+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9X2FrV6FXnJOZnKphqKmtoK2oXfE/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTUPJUElTkwtNzACLWGJuUmpRTmJuQTE2DQbYjDGsAAr@BwA)

-4 bytes thanks to ETHProductions

-7 + -5 + -2 bytes thanks to CalculatorFeline

-3 bytes thanks to Rick Hitchcock

Moves the first character to the end and sets it to 0 if it's numeric and non-zero, and 1 otherwise.

#### Explanation

```
s=>                    anonymous function with parameter s
                 +s    convert s to a number
                !      not (converts to boolean; relevant: 0->true,1->false)
               +       convert !+s back to number (true->1, false->0)
   s.slice(1)+         prefix the rest of the string
              ␣        needed to avoid the +s combining
```

#### Proof

Because the second char becomes the first, the third char becomes the second, etc. all chars would have to be identical. The last remaining char can only be a 0 or a 1, so the repeated char would have to be either 0 or 1. But any string of 0s produces a 1 at the end, and vice-versa; therefore, it is impossible to create an input that is equal to its output. -ETHProductions

See edits for former versions and explanations.

```js
f=
s=>s.slice(1)+ +!+s

console.log(f("000"))
console.log(f("111"))
console.log(f("001"))
console.log(f("110"))
console.log(f("~"))
console.log(f("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"))
console.log(f("Hello world!"))
console.log(f("23"))
console.log(f(" "))
console.log(f("1x"))
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
~Ṿṁ
```

Output is a string of digits, commas and hypen-minus characters, whose first character will differ from the first character of the input string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@1/3cOe@hzsb/x9uf9S0JlLh4Y7tjxrmKPgmFiiUZKQq5GTmZesoFKcWJBYllqQqJFWCRFLTUlNTivX@/4/mUlBKLE5JU9IBMgyBAMxQgAAwuw4EwKzEpOSkRIhCiCqIPIQNoeoUoPoNwLSig7KKapyaloamo5Ozi6ube0ZmVnZObl5@gaGRsYmpmbmFJUShgmKMElCpmrqGppa2jq6evgFcgZW1ja2dvQPUAA9PL28fXz//gMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomJjYuPgEoOtSUtPS4TYUFhWXlJaVV1RWVdfU1ilxxQIA)

#### How it works

```
~Ṿṁ  Main link. Argument: s (string)

~    Map bitwise NOT over the characters c in s.
     This attempts to cast c to int and then apply bitwise NOT, mapping
     '0', ..., '9' to 0, ..., 9 (before ~), then -1, ..., -10 (after ~).
     For non-digits, the attempt fails, mapping c to 0.
 Ṿ   Uneval, yielding a comma-separated string of integers in [-10, ..., 0].
     The first character will be '-' if s starts with a digit and '0' if not.
  ṁ  Mold; truncate the result to the length of s.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 20 bytes

```hs
map$head.show.(<'M')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mm5tYoJKRmpiiV5yRX66nYaPuq675P8c2WilESUfJDYhDwAwwC0S4gbiJxSlpQMoQCICUAgQAWXUgAJJPSk5KBCkAyYLEQTSIqFMAqzcAkooOyiqqcWpaGpqOTs4urm7uGZlZ2Tm5efkFhkbGJqZm5haWBkqxXFy5iZl5CrYKQHf6KmgUlJYElxT55OmlaSrk/AcA)

Converts to a string of `F` and `T`. What matters is that the characters `F` and `T` converts to each other. This is done by checking if the character is less than `M` to get `True` or `False`, then taking the first character of the string representation.

---

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 23 bytes**

```hs
q '~'=' '
q _='~'
map q
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@1@ooF6nbquuoM5VqBBvC2RzpdnmJhYoFP7PsY1WSixOSVPSUTIEAiClAAFAVh0IAOnEpOSkRJACkCxIHESDiDoFsHoDIKnooKyiGqempaHp6OTs4urmnpGZlZ2Tm5dfYGhkbGJqZm5haaAUy8WVm5iZp2CrALTcV0GjoLQkuKTIJ08vTVMh5z8A)

Replaces every character with `~`, except `~` becomes a space.

Comment: What is the significance of the space in `q '~'`? Why can't it be removed?

Comment: @Cyoce Haskell permits `'` as a character in identifiers, so `q'~'=' '` would be parsed as `q' ~ '=' '` (reporting a lexical error because the last `'` is unmatched.)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
Qo!V!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x@Yrxim@P@/uoFBcYpCaoqhoToA)

#### Explanation

```
Q     % Implicitly input a string. Add 1 to each code point.
o     % Parity: 0 if odd, 1 if even. Note that '0' has ASCII code 48, so after
      % having added 1 it now gives 1. Similarly. '1' has ASCII code 49, so it
      % now gives 0. All other chars give 0 or 1. 
!V!   % Convert each number to the corresponding char. Implicitly display
```

Comment: That's 5 in CJam: `l'0f=` (if it does what I think it does)

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, it's exactly that :-) I've just added an explanation

Answer (score 5):

## Whitespace, 59 bytes

Visible representation

```
NSSNSSSTSSSSSNSNSSNSSNSTNTSTTTTSSTNTTSNSNSTSSSNSSSNTNSSNSNN
```

What it does:

For every character it reads it prints a space, except when it's a space, then it prints a @.

Disassembly:

```
loop:
    push 32
     dup
      dup
       dup
        ichr
       get
       sub
      jn not_32
     dup
      add
not_32:
     pchr
    jmp loop
```

Comment: Always nice to see a solution in Whitespace. Especially when you normally are unable to actually *see* it. +1

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 19 bytes

An anonymous function which takes and returns a `String`. Use as `(map$(!!1).show.succ) "1111"`.

```hs
map$(!!1).show.succ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mm5tYoKKhqGioqVeckV@uV1yanPw/xzZaKURJR8kNiEPADDALRLiBuInFKWlAyhAIgJQCBABZdSAAkk9KTkoEKQDJgsRBNIioUwCrNwCSig7KKqpxaloamo5Ozi6ubu4ZmVnZObl5@QWGRsYmpmbmFpYGSrFcXLmJmXkKtgpAZ/oqaBSUlgSXFPnk6aVpKuT8BwA) (Using @xnor's testing harness.)

- For each character in the input string, increments the character, then converts that to character literal format, then takes the second character of the literal, which is the character just after the starting `'` quote.
- For nearly all printable characters, this results in simply the incremented character. The exceptions are `&` and `~`, which instead give `\`, because their successors `'` and `\DEL` get escaped in character literals.

Comment: pretty sure `head` can be used in place of `(!!1)` for an extra byte

Comment: No, `head` is `(!!0)`, not `(!!1)`. It would fail on the character `'`.

Comment: Ah, right. I'd just been reading the python answer and forgot that quotes usually needed special treatment.

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>9</s> 3 bytes

```
5%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/31Q17////7rFhkbGJgA)

Takes input through the `-s` flag. Mods each digit with 5 and prints the integer, ending when the stack is empty. This results in only 5 possible output characters, 0-4. Each of those numbers when inputted will produce themselves plus 3, as the ASCII value of 0 is 48, which mod 5 is 3. While the output is reversed, no number is equivalent to another.

Both 7, 9 and `a`(10) also work as they are not factors of 48 and print single digits.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
žQDÀ‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X6DL4YZHDQv//1d0UFZRjVPT0tB0dHJ2cXVzz8jMys7JzcsvMDQyNjE1M7ewNAAA)

**Explanation**

Replaces each char with the next printable ascii char, wrapping from tilde to space.

```
žQ     # push a string of printable acsii chars (space to tilde)
  D    # duplicate
   À   # rotate left
    ‡  # translate
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda s:`s<'T'`[0]+s[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrJDoIwFEXX8BUFB0A3gDOxibM/4A4xFIGAQmn6MMaNv15bTbyLe95w2KstGuqLHJ9FReokJQiCGJbWyYpDNxpC6AWReBZllSEv0DXAJWWP1nZ0jePcBkkCkPEWcQPDf6kyanMHY0XlMF5SqQiTQJqbuunJSKBf5PRWkSTJNSFKUF91V1T1Rl/flW2sOt3epT@wnfVmu9sfjkV5u1c1bZjnj8aT6Wy@kNoH)

Anders Kaseorg saved a byte by extracting the first character from `True` or `False`.

Comment: I'd suggest changing `'?'` to a 2 digit charcode, but Python isn't one of those languages where you can do that :(

Comment: Variants saving a byte (but dropping Python 3 compatibility): ``lambda s:`+(s<'1')`+s[1:]`` or ``lambda s:`s<'T'`[0]+s[1:]``

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 7 bytes

```
íÁ/a
g?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3947eFG/USudPv//xOLU9IA) or [Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3947eFG/USudHuP//8Ti1PSuAyBgEsBArjqQIArMSk5KZELKMpVx6VQx1WnAJQ34FJ0UFZRjVPT0tB0dHJ2cXVzz8jMys7JzcsvMDQyNjE1M7ewNOBSUIxRAipTU9fQ1NLW0dXTN4BLWlnb2NrZO0A1e3h6efv4@vkHBAYFh4SGhUdERkXHxMTGxScAbU9JTUuHm15YVFxSWlZeUVlVXVNbBwA)

How does it work?

Consider all strings consisting of printable ASCII. Every string must either 1) Contain alphabetic characters, or 2) Contain no alphabetic characters.

So the way this program works is by first converting one non-alphabetic character into `'a'`, and then performing ROT13 on the input string.

```
í       " Substitute:
 Á      "   A non-alphabetic character ([^a-zA-Z])
  /     "   with
   a    "   the letter 'a'
g?      " Perform ROT13 on...
        "   (Implicit) the current line.
```

Comment: This breaks if you have a number like `9` alone, where incrementing it adds another character to the string

Comment: @nmjcman101 Ah, that's a good point. I've reverted

Comment: I like the ROT13 thing though, I didn't know V(im) could do that

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + coreutils, 13

```
tr \ -~ ~\ -}
```

Transliterates the characters   to `~` (0x20 - 0x7e) with `~`, then   to `}` (0x7e, 0x20 - 0x7d).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19SpBCjoFunUAcka///TyxOSeMyBAIuBQjgqgMBrsSk5KRELqAoVx2XQh1XnQJQ3oBL0UFZRTVOTUtD09HJ2cXVzT0jMys7Jzcvv8DQyNjE1MzcwtKAS0ExRgmoTE1dQ1NLW0dXT98ALmllbWNrZ@8A1ezh6eXt4@vnHxAYFBwSGhYeERkVHRMTGxefALQ9JTUtHW56YVFxSWlZeUVlVXVNbR0A).

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 22 bytes

```c
f(char*s){*s=65+*s%2;}
```

Takes a string pointer and modies the first char in place.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkZyRWKRVrFmtVWxrZqqtVaxqZF37PzOvRCE3MTNPQ5OrmosTpEShODpWwVZBSaFOyZqLM02jWBNIFRQBFaZpKKkWK@kogERq/wMA)

Comment: Shorter: `*s=159-*s`. Always changes the last bit, therefore never gives the same character. Note that `159 = ' ' + '~'`

Comment: I think you mean 158 = ' ' + '~'.  159-32 = 127, which would be a character out of scope.  But good idea.

Comment: @celtschk Involutions cannot work, as there's an odd amount (95) of printable chraracters, so at least one of them will map to itself.

Comment: @Computronium: Oops, you're right, I got the character code of `~` wrong.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 20 bytes

Saw Dennis's answer, thought of a 2 byte essential improvement.

```c
f(char*s){*s^=*s/3;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkZyRWKRVrFmtVRxnq1Wsb2xd@z8zr0QhNzEzT0OTq5qLE6RAoTg6VsFWQUmhTsmaizNNo1gTSBUUARWmaSipFivpKIBEav8DAA) (Footer by Dennis.)

Like the original, modifies the first character of the string in place, but xors it with its value divided by 3 (the smallest number that works. 2 fails on the single character `'U'` which gives 127, not printable.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>10</s> 6 bytes

*4 bytes golfed thanks to @Neil*

```
T`p`~p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JKEgoa7g/3@FOq7EpOSUYq6k4uyUPK4Crpys4rRsLmMjS5NSCwdlVa7a6hgjYxMA)

This transliterates  to `~`, `!` to , `"` to `!`, ..., `~` to `}`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```matlab
@(s)['',(s<66)+65]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo1gzWl1dR6PYxsxMU9vMNPZ/moaSo6OjkiYXkJFYnJIGYRkCAYSlAAEQTh0IQNUmJSclQhVDVULVQHlQuk4BZo4BhKHooKyiGqempaHp6OTs4urmnpGZlZ2Tm5dfYGhkbGJqZm5hCVT5HwA)

**Explanation:**

```matlab
@(s)                 % Anonymous function taking a string s as input
         s<66        % A boolean vector with `1` for all characters below ASCII-66.
        (s<66)+65    % Add 65 to this, so that all elements that are 32-65 are now 66.
                     % All other elements are 65 
    ['',         ]   % Implicitly convert the list of 65 and 66 to the letters A and B
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>30</s> 26 bytes

```
f ' '='~'
f c=pred c
map f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@moK6gbqtep86VppBsW1CUmqKQzJVum5tYoJD2PzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvREFFIV1BSUHRyNhE6T8A)

Replaces each char with its predecessor and space with tilde.

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 5 bytes

```
l)iA%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#q/6fo5npqPo/Nq/W0Fjrf2JxShqXIRBwKUAAVx0IcCUmJSclcgFFueq4FOq46hSA8gZcig7KKqpxaloamo5Ozi6ubu4ZmVnZObl5@QWGRsYmpmbmFpYGAA)

Converts the last character to its code point and takes that modulo 10. This is clearly different for non-digit characters in the last position. But the digits start at code point 48, so taking those mod 10 will shift them left cyclically and hence the last character is always changed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
®c v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39oXbJC2f//SoYGdQpKAA)

### Explanation:

```
®c v
®    At each char:
 c     Convert to its ASCII value
   v   Return 1 if divisible by 2, otherwise return 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 10 bytes

```
..@|i?2%)O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@6@n51CTaW@kqun//7@BoZGxCQA) or [Watch it run!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Li5AfGk/MiUpTw==&input=MDEyMzQ=&speed=10)

For each char, prints `1` if the char has an even code point, `2` otherwise; `1` has an odd code point and `2` an even, so the output will never equal the input.

#### Explanation

This code corresponds to the following cube net:

```
    . .
    @ |
i ? 2 % ) O . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

The IP (instruction pointer) starts at the top-left corner of the far-left face, heading east. It follows this series of instructions:

```
i     Grab a char-code from STDIN and push it to the stack (-1 if there is no more input).
?     If the top item is negative, turn left and hit @ which ends the program.
      If it's positive (any printable ASCII char), turn right. The IP runs through a bunch
        of no-ops, then hits:
)     Increment the top item.
|     Mirror the IP's direction horizontally (turns it around).
)     Increment the top item again. The IP then wraps around again until it hits:
?     The top item is positive, so turn right.
2     Push a 2 to the stack.
%     Push the modulus of the top two items (0 for even char-code, 1 for odd).
)     Increment the result (now 1 for even char-code, 2 for odd).
O     Output as a number. The IP wraps back around to the i and the process starts again.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 9 bytes

```
#oi/
t i@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/185P1Ofq0Qh0@H//8TilDQA)

#### Explanation

The idea was taken from Martin Ender's CJam submission.  The first character is taken as a code point, reduced mod 10, and moved to the end of the output.  Since exactly one character was changed, permuting the characters cannot result in getting the same string back.

```
#   skip next command
o   (skipped)
i   push first byte onto stack
    STACK: [97]
/   reflect to SE, switch to ordinal mode (implicit reflect to SW)
i   push remaining input onto stack as string (implicit reflect to NW)
    STACK: [97, "sdf"]
o   output top of stack (implicit reflect to SW)
    STACK: [97]
t   implicitly convert code point to decimal string, and extract last character
    (implicit reflect to NE)
    STACK: ["9", "7"]
o   output this last digit (implicit reflect to SE)
i   push empty string, since there is no more input to take (implicit reflect to NE)
/   reflect to S, switch to cardinal mode
@   terminate
```

Comment: Using `t` for mod 10 is really clever, nice. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 1 byte

```
Q
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z/w////So5OzkoA)**

This converts the given string into list of ASCII character codes, indexes them (modular indexing) into the uppercase alphabet, then prints the result. Essentially, each character `n` is mapped to `chr(ord(n) % 26 + 65)`. You can use **[this program](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/18p3tvITDU@8D@Q6ejkrAQA)** to see how the mapping works.

The output:

- Will always be the same length as the input, as the characters are directly mapped into new ones.
- Will always comprise only printable ASCII characters (as it only contains uppercase letters)
- Will always be different to the input, as there is no possible input character `n` such that `chr(ord(n) % 26 + 65) == n`, as for this to be true there must be an integer `x` such that `26x = 65`, for which there is no solution.

---

## 1 byte

```
q
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/7/w////SolJyUoA)**

This answer is exactly the same, except that it maps to *lowercase* alphabet characters rather than *uppercase* alphabet characters. This is still valid as there is no possible input character `n` such that `chr(ord(n) % 26 + 97) == n`.

Answer (score 3):

### R, 40 bytes

`function(s)substr(shQuote(s),1,nchar(s))`

This uses the shell quoting function `shQuote` to place appropriate quotes around a string and escape quotes within the string (similar to @xnor's answer).  Then take a substring that's as long as the original string (because the string might have multiple escaped characters, we need to take a substring of the correct length, so we can't just use `substring(...,3)`).  `sQuote` is shorter, but converts `‘` to `‘‘’`.

Another approach, using more 'core' R stuff is 46 bytes:

`function(s)sub(".",letters[grepl("^a",s)+1],s)`

Substitute the first character with 'a', unless it is 'a', then substitute it for 'b'.  `sub` only substitutes the first match, so we don't need `^`.  `letters` is constant and a slightly shorter way of doing `c("a","b")`.  `grepl` returns a boolean, and adding 1 converts it to a number that indexes `letters`.  The `^` is needed to correctly convert "ba".

**Code to test**

```
x = function(s)substr(shQuote(s),1,nchar(s))

test = function(t){
  t2 = x(t)
  t2!=t & nchar(t)==nchar(t2)
}

testStrings = c("a","b","ab","ba","aa",
                "'","'\"","\\\\",'"','""',
                '‘','’',"~","asdf",
                "1111","       ","~~~~~","abcba",
                "1"," ","~"," ~","~ ","  0",
                "!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGhijklmnop1234567890",
                " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~")

all(sapply(testStrings,test))
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This answer is not, at the moment, valid, because it assumes input is given as a hard-coded variable `s`. You can either submit this as an anonymous function, `function(s)substr(shQuote(s),1,nchar(s))`, or take input via `scan(,"")`, `readLines()` or similar. I've upvoted this to give you enough rep to post in the [R golfing chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75004/golfr); feel free to ping me there if you have any questions! This is a very well-explained answer :)

Comment: @Giuseppe A ha, thanks! I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 53 bytes

Includes +1 for `-c`

```
([(((()()()()){}){}){}()]({}())){{}(<({}[()()])>)}{}
```

This will decrement the first character unless it is a space, in that case it will increment the first character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68RrQEEmhCoWV0LQRqasRogEigCpGyA7GiQfKymnWZtde3//wqJScn/dZMB)

```
([(((()()()()){}){}){}()]      )                     # Push: input + 1 != 33 on top of...
                         ({}())                      #    input + 1
                                {{}(<          >)}{} # If (input + 1 != 33)
                                     ({}[()()])      #   Push: (input + 1) - 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP<7.1, 31 Bytes

```php
for(;~$c=$argn[$i++];)echo$c^1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zzcrPzNMoSsxLT9VQUlDSUapT0tS05kpNzshXACvQU4rJU7L@n5ZfpGFdp5JsCxaMVsnU1o611gQpU0mOM7T@//9rXr5ucmJyRioA)

Comment: @CalculatorFeline "1"=>0, "10"=>01, "101"=>010 Where fails it?

Comment: `for(;a&$c=$argn[$i++];)echo$c^"\1";` btw this has different output but also works.

Comment: @Christoph Take this as your own approach and I can upvote it

Comment: I'm trying to make an answer without loop. If I fail I might post it :)

Comment: I did it [30 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123624/29637).

Comment: @Christoph I have improve you idea

Comment: Yeah I saw it sadly it doesn't work for my own approach because "101"^1 would be `100` while `"101"^"\1"` is `"0"`.

Comment: PHP 7.1 yields `A non-numeric value encountered`. And You can use `~` instead of `a&`.

Comment: @Christoph `^"\1"` fails for `~` in the input; `^"1"` would fail for `N`. That´d better be `"\2"`, `"\4"` or `"\8"`.

Comment: @Titus I have added the PHP Version must be under 7.1 . Thank You

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
^1Ṿ€
```

Outputs a digit string. No output character will be equal to the corresponding input character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x9n@HDnvkdNa/4fbgeSkQoPd2x/1DBHwTexQKEkI1UhJzMvW0ehOLUgsSixJFUhqRIkkpqWmppSrPf/fzSXglJicUqakg6QYQgEYIYCBIDZdSAAZiUmJSclQhRCVEHkIWwIVacA1W8AphUdlFVU49S0NDQdnZxdXN3cMzKzsnNy8/ILDI2MTUzNzC0sIQoVFGOUgErV1DU0tbR1dPX0DeAKrKxtbO3sHaAGeHh6efv4@vkHBAYFh4SGhUdERkXHxMTGxScAXZeSmpYOt6GwqLiktKy8orKquqa2TokrFgA)

#### How it works

```
^1Ṿ€  Main link. Argument: s (string)

^1    XOR each character c in with 1.
      This attempts to cast c to int, mapping '0', ..., '9' to 0, ..., 9.
      For non-digits, the attempt fails, mapping c to 0.
      After XORing with 1, we get 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8 for '0', ..., '9', 
      and 1 for all non-digits.
  Ṿ€  Uneval each; mapping 0, ..., 9 to '0', ..., '9'. This yields a character
      array, which is Jelly's string type.
      Note that no character is mapped to itself.
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <s>30</s> 27

```
<?=strtr($a=$argn,$a,$a^1);
```

Changes every each char equal to the first char with the char that has the least significant bit flipped.

Comment: Does "~" work?.

Comment: It doesn't actually flip the least significant bit of the first char; it converts it to an integer and flips the least significant bit of *that*. So yes, @CalculatorFeline, `~` does work, outputting `1`.

Comment: Oh. Does `!$a` or `~$a` work?

Comment: @ETHproductions I did the last edit shortly before going to bed and didn't have the time to update it. Of course your right it first converts to integer and therefore might not even change the first char but maybe the second e.g. "12" becomes "13".

Comment: @CalculatorFeline sadly both fail `!$a` turns `"12"` into `"12"` because `false` is converted to an empty string so that nothing gets replaced and `~$a` turns everything into unprintables because `~"12"` doesn't convert to int first but literally flips all bits in the string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 20+1 = 21 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag.

```ruby
sub(/./){$&=~/1/||1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#U1YsKk2qVNAt@F9cmqShr6evWa2iZlunb6hfU2NY@/9/YnFKGpchEHApQABXHQhwJSYlJyVyAUW56rgU6rjqFIDyBlyKDsoqqnFqWhqajk7OLq5u7hmZWdk5uXn5BYZGxiamZuYWlgZcCooxSkBlauoamlraOrp6@gZwSStrG1s7eweoZg9PL28fXz//gMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomJjYuPgEoO0pqWnpcNMLi4pLSsvKKyqrqmtq6wA)

Replaces the first character in the input with a `0` if it is `1`, or `1` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
{¬Ṣ|∧Ịh}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#ASYA2f//e8Ks4bmifOKIp@G7imh94bWQ//8iSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISL/Wg)

#### Explanation

This replaces all chars by a space, except spaces which it replaces with `"0"`.

```
{      }ᵐ      Map on each char of the Input
 ¬Ṣ              The Input char is not " ", and the Output char is " "
   |             Or
    ∧Ịh          The Output char is "0"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Golfscript, 3 bytes

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJUZXN0IGNhc2UiCik1JQ%3D%3D)

```
)5%
```

Take the last character's ASCII value modulo 5, and replace the last character with the result. This obviously works for non-digit characters, but if the last character is a digit, it also changes ("0" mod 5 = 3, "1" mod 5 = 4, etc).

This would also work with 7 or 9 while still keeping the same length.

Also, yay! I have a Golfscript solution as good as the best solutions here!

Answer (score 2):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), <s>26</s> 22 bytes

```
s=>s::gsub("."a=>1&~a)
```

Calculates `~a` which for non-digits will return NaN. Then `1&` limits it to either 0 or 1, for the digit 0, this will be `1`, and for `1` this will be `0`. So this string is always unique.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7v9jWrtjKKr24NElDSU8p0dbOUK0uUfN/QVFmXolGmoaSoaGBYVJOYoaSpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

### C/C++, 29 bytes

```cpp
void m(char*s){(*s%=26)+=65;}
```

Code to test :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#endif

void m(char*s){(*s%=26)+=65;}

int main() {
    std::initializer_list<std::string> test{
        "asdf",
        "1111",
        "       ",
        "~~~~~",
        "abcba",
        "1",
        " ",
        "~",
        " ~",
        "~ ",
        "  0",
        "!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGhijklmnop1234567890",
        " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
    };

    for (auto&a : test) {
        char* t = new char[a.size() + 1];
        std::strcpy(t, a.c_str());
        m(t);
        assert(a != t);
        std::cout << a << " => " << t << '\n';
        delete[] t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## brainfuck, <s>35</s> 27 bytes

Edit: switched to a better way of generating an odd number thanks to the [brainfuck constants page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#85)

```
,[[[>]+<[-<]>]-[>+<---]>.,]
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJzo62i5W2yZa1ybWLlY32k7bRldXN9ZOTyf2//@wsDAA)

Prints out a string of semi-random Vs and Us. If the first character of the input is a V it will print out a U instead and vice versa.

#### How it Works

```
,[ Gets first inputted char 
  [[>]+<[-<]>] Converts the ASCII value to binary
  -[>+<---] Adds 85 to the last digit of that binary, which is the original value mod 2. 
            This converts a V (value 86) into a U (value 85) and vice versa
  >. Print the value
,] Get a new value and repeat. 
   Note that the binary of the previous value is still in memory, 
     so it no longer prints specific chars for odd or even values
```

Another version with the same bytecount:

```
,[[>]+<[-<]>]-[>+<---]>[.,]
```

Only changes the first character to a V or a U, but doesn’t handle empty input (which is still valid)

Comment: Great algorithm--it's tricky to find short algorithms to do things in BF. Don't think the second one works though; shouldn't the last bit be `[.,]`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 42 bytes

```
({}[((((()()()()){}){}){})]<>){{}}([]<>{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6NloDBDQhULO6Fopibew0q6trazWigSwg//9/haTk/7rJAA)

Replaces the first character of the string with a space, or a `!` if the first character is already a space.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
{.ord%7~.chop}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@79aL78oRdW8Ti85I7@g9n9xYqWCSrytukFqTk6@uo6SgpKOWqqGSrymNRdMygy3lDkIYJfywK3LAASwSxmCgLqOuoI6XOo/AA)

Bare block, implicit lambda with input `$_`. The ordinal of the first character `.ord` modulo 7 is a different character: Non-numeric first character becomes numeric, numeric first characters map to a different character. If we append the input sans the last character (`~ $_.chop`), we match the length. It can never match the input because the first character never matches.

#### <s>[Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes</s>

```perl6
{S/./{.ord%7}/}
```

Performs `S///` substitution (which returns the result of substituting on `$_`), matching `.` (any character) once, and replacing it with the ordinal of the first character in `$_` - the same character - modulo 7. Non-numeric first character becomes numeric, numeric first characters map to a different character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@786WF9Pv1ovvyhF1bxWv/Z/cWKlgkq8rbpBak5OvrqOkoKSjlqqhkq8pjUXTMoMt5Q5CGCX8sDU9R8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [str](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/str), 2 bytes

```
XV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4p@v8/Iuz/f4/UnJx8RYW6xOKUNAA)

### Explanation

```
XV
       over each character:
X         increment it  ("~" becomes "\x7f" and "@" becomes "A")
 V        wrap to printable ascii ("\x7f" becomes " ")
```

Alternatively, `YV` to decrement instead of increment.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>37</s> 26 bytes

<sup>Thanks Mazzy for -11 bytes</sup>

```powershell
-join($args|% t*y|%{$_%9})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcu7CsJAEEbhV/kJWbwQG7GxtpE0KXwAWWHJrCQ7sjNhCSbPPoKkOsXH@XAJWSgMg9npzTHta597WRz0OC/uWz/ddT2YWdUypTSjeIHHjcIYRXcC4YTXpNg4ChJj5BwaFPIKClDiqSf9r/dzt/XRXaof)

Does alright. Uses the ToCharArray trick to save some bytes. Through a conversion chain, mods the ASCII value of each character by 9 then joins up the value.

Comment: ? `6+3*($_-eq6)`

Comment: ? `$_%9` :)))))

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 11 bytes

```
i:0(?;'0'=n
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@59pZaBhb61uoG6b9/9/YnGKgZGCYSEA)**

#### Explanation

Like my MATL answer, this transforms character `'0'` into `'1'` and all other characters into `'0'`.

```
i       Input one char, or push -1 if there aren't any more chars
:       Duplicate
0(      Is it less than 0?
?;      If so, end program. Else:
'0'     Push character '0'
=       Is it equal? Gives 1 or 0
n       Output as a number. Go back to the beginning
```

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMPe2lQ17/9/A0MjYxNTAA) if you just print the number modulo 5

Comment: @JoKing Thanks! But U think you should post that as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/./,s[0]^1)
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Changes the first character of the string according to this table:

```
1   0
2   3
3   2
4   5
5   4
6   7
7   6
8   9
9   8
```

Everything else becomes `1`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock As I understand it, only one character needs to be different.

Comment: @RickHitchcock The very first rule states that the string can be assumed to only contain printable characters...

Comment: Head-slap, +1!!

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 5 bytes

```
g*A~a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/chip#@5@u5ViX@P9/naGhoUJicUqagyMA)

Maps all characters to either `@` or `A`, so that the lowest bit always differs from the input:

`0`, `@`, `~`, etc. map to `A`
`1`, `a`, `A`, etc. map to `@`

Answer (score 1):

## x86 Assembly, 19 bytes

Alternates the first character of the string between '@' and 'A'

```
_diffstr:
  00000000: 8B 54 24 04        mov         edx,dword ptr [esp+4]
  00000004: 8A 02              mov         al,byte ptr [edx]
  00000006: 3C 41              cmp         al,41h
  00000008: 75 04              jne         0000000E
  0000000A: B0 40              mov         al,40h
  0000000C: EB 02              jmp         00000010
  0000000E: B0 41              mov         al,41h
  00000010: 88 02              mov         byte ptr [edx],al
  00000012: C3                 ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 49 bytes

```
sub{$_="a"x length $_[0];$_++while $_ eq$_[0];$_}
```

Explanation:

- starts with string of letter "a" as long as input
- keeps incrementing that until it's different from input

Starting from "a"s was to avoid incrementing to point where Perl lengthens the string; with only one strings to avoid being same as, it couldn't overflow.

This is shamelessly cribbed (and simplified) from my answer to the "related" problem "The Third String".

Execute with:

```
perl -e '$s = ' -E 'sub{$_="a"x length $_[0];$_++while $_ eq$_[0];$_}' -E ';say $s->("z")'
```

Comment: How can it need to increment more than once?

Answer (score 1):

## x86 opcode, 6 bytes

```
    and     byte [ecx], 0xF1
    inc     byte [ecx]
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
s->map(x->x<'b'?'b':'a',s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@5@mYKuQlJqemfe/WNcuN7FAo0LXrsJGPUndHoit1BPVdYo1/6fmpXA5FGfklyukaSglJiYqaSK4SUlJyNzE4pQ0FL5SnKUlsnIw/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```java
s->(s.charAt(0)<49?9:0)+s.substring(1)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lZJZU8IwFIXf@RUBFROW2iouZccVF3BBRWXRdAEKpcUmRRHhr9eAHd6c1PuQaZJzvntyp308xsm@NvBUExMCKtiwpiEADIvqTgerOqgutgDUqGNYXaBC/4OgDDufhdhCKKaGCqrAAjngkWQeEkHtYadEoYiyKbkgp0UUJwJxFbI0Qwl5mYVz5Comc/qAsW1oYMgC@D0aLYz85hNC9aFgu1QYsRtqWtASVBjBROtE0DLJ3yKJFVcEfourmy@Kq8KKqmB@MH4qfh4@gy@ZgwDzEbmacHFtfaMdjUFUOjw6Pjk96xn9gTm07JG0vZPa3ds/kPkQEG5GGCa6CVEsnkgKW@LKnM5kc/lC0YeXzy8uryrV65vbu9r9w2P96fml0Wy22q9vbPqa3umuur87hLrjj8/J1/R7xp@GKIpB/qkAHCkAJ1Cv/xaXWdZN006Auu2YWpirlmWZ/1o@xVfMQjPvBw)

**Explanation:**

If the first character has a unicode value below 49 (space, or one of `!"#$%&'()*+'-./0`), change it to a '9', else change it to a '0'.

```java
s->                 // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  (s.charAt(0)<49?  //  If the first character has a unicode value below 49:
    9               //   Change the first character to a '9'
  :                 //  Else
   0)               //   Change the first character to a '0'
  +s.substring(1)   //  And return the rest of the input-String (if any)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```python
lambda s:'a~'[s<'~']+s[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBDsIgEETv/YoxiguRS@ONyJfUHqhIbFJpw/bihV9H0HeYt5tMZvvsrzVeS7D3srj35B3YkMs08I0yjRceejOWsCYw5ghJbnp40iBUmnOlua80H0/iTMp0SLBYnlGysrY51EvBRQ/JB/v7OmxpjrskkeraP5ggakOjNTSSUuUL)

- Replacing first character with `~`, if the first character is `~` already, it is replaced by `a`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
*h-+QGhQl
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Ah-%2BQGhQl&input=%22%20%21%5C%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29%2A%2B%2C-.%2F0123456789%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5C%5D%5E_%60abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%7B%7C%7D~%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
*h-+QGhQl
   +QG      Stick the alphabet to the end of the input.
  -   hQ    Delete all instances of the first character.
 h          Take the first remaining character.
*       lQ  Multiply by the length of the (implicit) input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
DEF D S
S[0]=@1[S>"2"]END
```

Creates a function named `D` that is called like:

```
STRING$="abcde"
D STRING$
'STRING$ is now "1bcde"
```

The first character is replaced with either `@` or `1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 6 bytes

```
iE;5%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P9PV2lQ17/9/BUUlZRVVNXUNTS1tHV09fQNDI2MTUzNzC0sraxtbO3sHRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXz//gMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomNi4@ITEpOSU1LT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKquqa2joA)

Direct translation of [Jo King's ><> answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152142/78410).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 22 bytes

```c
f(char*s){*s=~1&*s^2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLNaq9i2zlBNqzjOyLr2f25iZp5GZl6JQoUOWF4rsSi9TLOaS0EhTQPEjDaM1bQG8gqKgIqQhWr/JyYl/1dQjFFSVlFVU9fQ1NLW0dXTNzA0MjYxNTO3sLSytrG1s3dwdHJ2cXVz9/D08vbx9fMPCAwKDgkNC4@IjIqOiYmNi08AGpOSmpaekZmVnZObl19QWFRcUlpWXlFZVV1TWwcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 11 bytes

```
0|[!5P5WA:]
```

Idea from Jo King's answer.

Prints the ASCII value of each letter modulo 5.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=0%7C%5B!5P5WA%3A%5D&input=33333)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
ṁ(s%5c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/DnY0axaqmyf///49WSixOSVPSUTIEAiClAAFAVh0IAOnEpOSkRJACkCxIHESDiDoFsHoDIKnooKyiGqempaHp6OTs4urmnpGZlZ2Tm5dfYGhkbGJqZm5hCVKmoBijBFSopq6hqaWto6unbwCXtrK2sbWzd4Bq9/D08vbx9fMPCAwKDgkNC4@IjIqOiYmNi08AuiYlNS0dbn5hUXFJaVl5RWVVdU1tnVIsAA)

Port of [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152142/95126) - upvote it!
Outputs ASCII values MOD 5.

Comment: @Zgarb @Leo I wanted to also submit a (2-byte longer) version using the documented 'if2' usage of ```?``` to make a bijection: ```m?→'~=' ```, but it doesn't seem to infer...  any insight why not?

Comment: You need to mention them on a thread they already commented on (or alternatively, one of their answers)

Comment: @Razetime: Ok - thanks - finally starting to understand how to 'ping' now...

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
C∷ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJD4oi34bmFIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIl0=)

05AB1E port, go read that.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```apl
∊⍕¨'0'=⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO9AEh0PeqdemiFuoG67aO@qSDB/5wFXOqJScnqXCCGoZExhGFgaKAOAA)

*-3 thanks to @Adám*

##### Explanation

```
∊⍕¨'0'=⎕
   '0'=⎕        For each character: 1 if it's '0', 0 otherwise
 ⍕¨             Convert each to string
∊               Flatten into a single string
```

Comment: `~2|⎕UCS` can be written as `'0'=`

Comment: @Adám thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>48</s>  28 bytes

```perl6
{(->{[~] (' '..'~').roll(.chars)}...*ne$_).tail}
```

Generates a sequence of random strings, stopping when one of them doesn't match the input. Returns the last string produced

[Test it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#PU7LTsMwELznK5YQGjtq3JZHAYVWlKe49MSNkipxXBJw7CpOkFCUfAx8R7@pJ87Bpog57OzujGa3Ugzex4QGVv4BPSoTBpOuRv60fmqfAbngEuK2LiaF5BwRmkaFwg0hxBPMWWJSRhlvukqnPDJVBtZKFuB4D3NCZR6jQRjCdvNpbzdfcIEWcw9P/2fHGWCoLQB9eFEwVfESJmA@QDo40EKmRAk7pQ/Osv/XkzUruNVYiRTML/XVTLx0dqSSlW3ZIw1NsIPuWgPNUUzjyBiMavaGTWnh1z/Ude9y3zkIex7Cs6vrm9u7@zR7feO5kOvR4dHxyfj07Hxofwvp04im7Ac)

```perl6
{first *ne$_,(0,1 Xx.chars)}
```

Generates two strings one consisting of only `0`s, the other of `1`s. Returns the `first` that is not stringwise equal to (`ne`) the input (`$_`).

[Test it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#PU3LTsMwELz7K5ZgKjsKacKjgEIRr4K49MSBQ5UqcRwaSOwqThCoaj@mfEe/qZ8Q1hQxh53dnRlNayR8DHwRkeoLekJnEobdIi9q04CrJJ16LPBCePn0xSypDV92LSaepWkikusaqPs09oWuUtaPY9hu1s528w2XbDJ2@dX/TWmfw4IAYMmklqYtGxiCbWN0yiMUCqMa2CkeYOvf7s9lXZIlybSShw22Fuq1cxKT5Q5xAgRSiECCHXBbWSAnqUgTa7Cq/Vu2YwW/fhveu96nB3HPZfzm9u5@9PA4K97ey0rpeXh0fHI6ODu/CJwf)

### Expanded

```perl6
{             # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  first       # return the first value where the following is true

    * ne $_,  # WhateverCode lambda ( ｢*｣ is the parameter )

    (
      0, 1    # list of 0 and 1
      X[x]    # cross ｢X｣ that using the string repetition operator ｢x｣
      .chars  # with the number of characters in ｢$_｣
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 4 bytes

```
'0f=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/convex#@69ukGb7////ktTiksy8dANDAA)

Comment: This appears to fail (on TIO, at least) if the input is purely numeric: `RuntimeException: Long Character f= not implemented`

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>16</s> <s>12</s> 9 bytes

```
=01`
,'pO
```

Run with `-F` to see immediate output (but works without).

#### Explanation:

We read a character, then push the character `0` on the stack and test for equality:

```
=0
,'
```

If equal, we push a 1.

```
  1`
```

We now print the top element (either a one or an implicit zero), and go back to the start:

```
  pO
```

This prints zeroes for any characters that aren't zeroes, and ones for zeroes, e.g.:

```
Input  |  Output
----------------
abcde  |  00000
11111  |  00000
10010  |  01101
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
ＦＳＩＸ⁰⁼ι1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@5@WX6Sg4ZlXUFoSXFKUmZeuoampEABklGg4JxaXaATkl6cWaRjoKLgWlibmFGtk6igoGSppAoH1//@KDsoqqnFqWhqajk7OLq5u7hmZWdk5uXn5BYZGxiamZuYWlgZc/3XL/usW5wAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works by comparing each character to `1`, then taking the result as the exponent of zero, then converting to string. This results in an output `0` for each `1` in the input and a `1` for each other character. Edit: Changes in Charcoal now mean that I can directly cast the result of `Equals` saving 2 bytes: `ＦＳＩ⁼ι0` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLQkuKQoMy9dQ1NTIQDIKNFwTiwu0XAtLE3MKdbI1FFQMlDS1NS0/v9f0UFZRTVOTUtD09HJ2cXVzT0jMys7Jzcvv8DQyNjE1MzcwtKA679uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Actually there was a 6-byte solution all along: `ＦＳ§α℅ι` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLQkuKQoMy9dQ1NTIQDIKNFwLPHMS0mt0EjUUfAvSsnMS8zRyNTU1LT@/1/RQVlFNU5NS0PT0cnZxdXNPSMzKzsnNy@/wNDI2MTUzNzC0oDrv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Port of @FlipTack's Pushy answer. (Also works with lower case of course.)

Answer (score 0):

## Braingolf, 12 bytes

```
.#~e1-:1+|&@
```

Subtracts 1 from the last char's ordinal if it is a tilde, otherwise adds one.

#### Explanation:

```
.#~e1-:1+|&@  Implicit input of string, convert each char to ordinal and push to stack
.             Duplicate last item
 #~           Push tilde ordinal
   e          If last 2 items are equal (consumes last 2 items)
    1-        ..then subtract one
      :       else
       1+     ..add one
         |    endif
          &@  Print entire stack as chars
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 46 bytes

```
_=>(char)(_[0]>32?_[0]-1:_[0]+1)+_.Remove(0,1)
```

Changes first letter to next to previous letter on ASCII table unless it is the first letter, in which case it takes the next one.

Answer (score 0):

### SAS, 34

```
substr(s,1,1)=ifc(s=:'z','a','z');
```

If the first character of the string `s` is `z`, change it to `a`, otherwise change it to `z`. Rubbish compared to the proper golfing languages, but at least it beats C#!

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 45 bytes

```
SELECT STUFF(S,1,1,CHAR(ASCII(S)%7+48))FROM t
```

Takes input from pre-existing table **t** with VARCHAR field **S**, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/70172).

Modifies the first character by taking the remainder MOD 7 of the ASCII value, then converting that back into a digit between 0 and 6. But ASCII(0)=48, which is 6 MOD 7, so the first character never maps back onto itself.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), 23 bytes

```
(~-61/1=7&6:7>4?6@4!@5)
```

Converts the string into `$`s and `-`s.

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
'_._` !{+32}*-
```

Found about 10 interpreter bugs writing this. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/189Xi8@4dACxWptY6NaLd3//9Py8xWSEosA)

```
'_._` !{+32}*-
'                « read string                              »;
 _               « push last char onto stack                »;
  .              « increment                                »;
   _`            « mod by 127 (the "` " evaluates to 127)   »;
      !{...}     « if falsy (char was ~)                    »;
        +32      «  add 32 (make it a space)                »;
            *    « stick char at beginning of string        »;
             -   « pop last char off string                 »;
```

Answer (score 0):

## BrainFuck, <s>49</s> 47 Bytes

```
,>++++[-<-------->]++[<]++++[->++++++++<]>-[.,]
x           0   (x-32) 2                (x-32||2)+31
^           ^(x>32) ^(x==32)
```

Assuming EOF as zero

Comment: You can cut out the first set of `.,` and just go straight into the loop

Comment: ````````Thanks````````

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 + 1 (-p) = 24 bytes

```perl
s/./chr 65+ord($&)%26/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX08/OaNIwcxUO78oRUNFTVPVyEw/9f9/P/@AwKDgkNCw8IjIKEcnZxdXN3cPTy9vH99/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWAAA)

Blatantly steals @FlipTack's method to change the first character to a different upper case letter.

Comment: You can drop one of the digits in 26, at least.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 3](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), <strike>76</strike> 68 bytes

```
let s=readLine()!;print(s.characters.map{$0=="a" ?"b":"a"}.joined())
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/UNQV95549)

Answer (score 0):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 77 bytes

```
CHARACTER(256)A
READ*,A
A(1:1)=CHAR(MOD(IACHAR(A(1:1))+1,94)+33)
PRINT*,A
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v939nAMcnQOcQ3SMDI103TkCnJ1dNHSceRy1DC0MtS0BUlr@Pq7aHg6gpkQYU1tQx1LE01tY2NNroAgT78QkA5XP5f//@tAAAA)

It does what was required... well, with some issues...

1) If the first character is `"`or `<space>`, they will be ignored;

2) If there is `/`, it will be understood as something like "end of transmission";

3) There will be a leading space (which is not part of the output (so do I think), because Fortran always prints a leading space if the output is not formated) and up to 255 trailing spaces. This last problem (i.e., the trailing spaces) can be solved using no more then six bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 71 bytes

```
	INPUT LEN(1) . X REM . S
	X =IDENT(X) 1	:S(O)
	X =0
O	OUTPUT =X S
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9PTLyA0RMHH1U/DUFNBTyFCIcjVF0gHc3FGKNh6urj6hWhEaCoYcloFa/hrggUNuPw5/UNDQNpsI4AKXf1cOP//NwQA)

Replaces the first character of `S` with a `0` unless it's already, `0` in which case it swaps it with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 12 bytes

```
+C+%ChQlG32t
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BC%2B%25ChQlG32t&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22asdf%22%0A%221111%22%0A%22+++++++%22%0A%22%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%22%0A%22abcba%22%0A%221%22%0A%22+%22%0A%22%7E%22%0A%22+%7E%22%0A%22%7E+%22%0A%22++0%22%0A%22%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2a%28%29ABCDEFGhijklmnop1234567890%22%0A%22+%21%5C%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29%2a%2B%2C-.%2F0123456789%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5C%5D%5E_%60abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%7B%7C%7D%7E%22&debug=0)

Python 3 translation:

```
Q=eval(input())
print(chr(ord(Q[0])%26+32)+Q[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 56 bytes

```
proc C s {join [lmap x [split $s ""] {expr {$x==0}}] ""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDZVsJADIbv@xRhrAi4UBZ3q2BVwH3f2oKlgBYLHTpFq@Pw6jWDHv6L/DnJl5ycRK6fJDQMXDCAAe8H3hBMf@BQiMFk1PciUBkQYgPvxjQErsa6rglhY00kUxDHFOKwTo8opIBCgz9hNpFCd9pu25GA7Mq6dBkmMOU1jKnKnDrfTOcy2eq@cXB4VHvz@u/@YBjQQrFUXl1b39iUGKQsgmB6IZPNLS4tr@S1WXtre0ff3av8j9cbxyenZ@cXl1fXN7d39w@PT8@mZdnN1gte0@n2Xmf7RyGLxh@f8dc3/xF4lVYqlhUBnI4jBqaBL7BF8gs)

Approach very similar to last one: replaces every non-zero by a zero and every zero by one.

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 62 bytes

```
proc C s {puts [expr {[string in $s 0]==0}][string ra $s 1 e]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9ZW8JADHzvrwgVEfBgC3hbBet931dbcCkFq6Wsu0XRuvz1mvVgHjL5JjP5ktgL05TxvgcWCEjYIBZg@0PGIbFFzIOoC0EEWQHENU0i3X@RUyUa4LsyDXuUqbCmU9Hu6JpuIJDgF9iNFJBpy2tRZVBTpStWZQQ/foI1U5vITjZyxXyhvmltbe/sPgXPL2Ev6jOjXKnOLywuLSsbZBwdjbmpfKE4PTM7VyLj8crqmrm@UfuL7@0fHB4dn5yenV9cXl3f3N7dP9iO4zaaj3hN2@90x/tfuYgHb@/Dj8/kS@JVpFKuahISC1@V6Tc)

Approach replaces first character by 1 if it is a 0, else it replaces anything else by a 0.

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 83 bytes

```
proc C s {scan [string in $s 0] %c f
puts "[format %c [incr f]][string ra $s 1 e]"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDZVsIwEIbv@xRDBATcWvddtO77vqVBQ6BYbdOaBLdaXr0mqPwX8@fMfJkzM4qFeZ6ImIELElLJKAcslQh4BwIORQk2gRID30q6SgLCfiwiqkwKB5wJ8An55wU1vANtgrI8jGhiOlqIypaPLORoaYNf6VfPSDttsiY1gKmavHETetDnbR0L9aFiqVGuVarrG@7m1vbOU/D8EkY8TpzJqemZ2bn5BYNBwUMaLA9XqrWR0bHxCXtQXlxaXlldq/99393bPzg8Oj45PTu/uLy6vrm9u8eeRxoPj3qaVtvvDPq/Cqm6b@8fn1/pd6anyiDtXwK7elmS5T8)

Answer (score 0):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 36 bytes

```
2a2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2e5p1o1f0x1x2f0a0x1f
```

Works for any input string terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
2a2x1v             # Set variable 1 equal to 2
1x1f               # Function 1
    1r             # Read a byte of input
      3x1v2e       # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
            5p1o   # Otherwise, output it modulo 5
                1f # Jump back to the start of function 1
1x2f               # Function 2
    0a             # Add 0 to the register
1f                 # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `J`, \$ 5 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.12 bytes

```
O2%1_
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSl1LsgqWlJWm6Fkv9jVQN4yHsBTBKKTEpWQnCAQA)

Port of Riley's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
O2%1_  # Implicit input
O      # Ordinals of input
 2%    # Mod 2 (vectorised)
   1_  # Not (vectorised)
       # J flag joins the list
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
É1░¡
```

Converts `1` to `0` and every other character to `1`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9wp@GjaRMPLfz/XymxOCVNiUvJEAiAlAIEAFl1IACkE5OSkxJBCkCyIHEQDSLqFMDqDYCkooOyimqcmpaGpqOTs4urm3tGZlZ2Tm5efoGhkbGJqZm5hSVImYJijBJQoZq6hqaWto6unr4BXNrK2sbWzt4Bqt3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjIqOiYmNi4@AeialNS0dLj5hUXFJaVl5RWVVdU1tSBXgewxUgIA)

**Explanation:**

```python
É     # Foreach over each character of the (implicit) input-string,
      # using 3 characters as inner code-block:
 1░   #  Push 1, and convert it to a string: "1"
   ¡  #  Check whether it's NOT equal to the current character
      # (after which the entire stack is joined together and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `JB`, 1 byte

```
E
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0kpeTUuyCpaUlaboWC12XFCclF0N5C5YqGRgaKEE4AA)

#### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 bytes

```
CEJ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi51dvZYUJyUXQ_kLlioZGBooQTgA)

Port of Riley's 05AB1E answer. Converts to charcodes and checks if even. Then, joins the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

## [(,)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(,)/) `N`, <s>116</s> 108 Chars or \$108\log_{256}(3)\approx21.4\$ Bytes

```
((),()()()()()()())(,,,,(()(),((()()())))(()(),(),(),,(()()),()((),,,,(),,(())))(()(),(),()(),,(()()),()()))
```

[Try It Online!](https://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=N&code=((),()()()()()()())(,,,,(()(),((()()())))(()(),(),(),,(()()),()((),,,,(),,(())))(()(),(),()(),,(()()),()()))&stdin=123cat%20+-%7E&)
Or, without flags, for 138 chars or 27.34 Bytes

```
((),()()()()()()()()()())(,,,,(()(),((()()())))(()(),(),,(())(())(())()(),(()()),(())(())(())(()))(()(),(),,(())(())(())(()),(()()),()()))
```

[Try It Online!](https://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=((),()()()()()()()()()())(,,,,(()(),((()()())))(()(),(),,(())(())(())()(),(()()),(())(())(())(()))(()(),(),,(())(())(())(()),(()()),()()))&stdin=123cat%20-%7E&)
Basically, it outputs 1 (with flags) or \32 (without flags) if the char code is greater than or equal to that of \50 (with flags) or
\40 (without flags), and outputs 2 (with flags) or \40 (without flags) otherwise.
The reason 1 and 2 are written as 1 and 2 rather than as \49 and \50 is because they are outputted numerically, hence the need for the `N` flag to remove seperators. All others are encoded in the code by char code.