# Different number, same weight

Tags: code-golf, number, bitwise

## Background

The [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of an integer is the number of ones in its binary representation. For this challenge, integers are represented with 32 bits, and they are unsigned.

## Challenge

Given an integer between 0 and 2^32-1 (non-inclusive), output a *different* integer within the same range, and also with the same Hamming weight.

## Examples

```
Input (Decimal) | Input (Binary) | Hamming weight | Possible output (Decimal)
       46       |   0b0010 1110  |       4        |      15
       12       |   0b0000 1100  |       2        |      3
        1       |   0b0000 0001  |       1        |      2
        3       |   0b0000 0011  |       2        |      6
      2^31      |   0b1000....0  |       1        |      1
      2^31+2    |   0b1000...10  |       2        |      3
      2^32-5    |   0b1111..011  |       31       |      2^31-1
      2^32-2    |   0b1111....0  |       31       |      2^31-1
        0       |   0b0000 0000  |       0        | None (This case need not be handled)
      2^32-1    |   0b1111....1  |       32       | None (This case need not be handled)
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the solution in the fewest bytes in each language wins.

Comment: I'd suggest adding an odd number between 2^31+1 and 2^32-3, as some answers are failing at that.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123539/8478)

Comment: Since you just added `2^31+2`, I'll repeat that I said an *odd* number. The answers in question only failed when *both* the highest and the lowest bit are `1`.

Comment: I'm a fool. Thank you. Will fix that

Comment: @musicman523 I just happened to be browsing active questions and saw this one. And noticed that you still haven't added the requested test cases.

Comment: @Draco18s I haven't really been active on here in a couple years. Would you like to add the requested test cases?

Comment: They'd be nice! I don't plan on writing an answer, I was just a bit amused and thought I'd ping. :)

Comment: Ok, I added 2^32-5 as a test case

Answer (score 29):

## x86-64 assembly, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
   0:   97                      xchg   %eax,%edi
   1:   d1 c0                   rol    %eax
   3:   c3                      retq
```

A function using the C calling convention that bitwise rotates its argument left by 1 bit.

Comment: Dammit - I was about to post exactly this - well done :)

Comment: assembly beats Jelly :o

Comment: Isn't this multiplying by 2? If so, then my 2 byte Pyth answer probably wins

Comment: @NoOneIsHere No, this is not multiplication by 2. Multiplication by 2 sends half of the inputs outside of the required range, and if you ignore the overflow bit on the left, you’ve decreased the Hamming weight by 1. This is a [bitwise rotation](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitwise+rotation), which brings the overflow bit back in from the right.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976636/whats-the-purpose-of-the-rotate-instructions-rol-rcl-on-x86

Comment: FYI, gcc will emit (almost) exactly this code if you compile `unsigned h(unsigned n){return (n<<31)|(n>>1);}` with `-S -O1`.  The only thing I couldn't figure out is how to get a `rol` instead of a `ror` when rotating by a constant number of bits.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma GCC 4.9.0 and later are smart enough to compile `n << 1 | n >> 31` into `rol` instead of `ror` (saving a byte).

Answer (score 8):

## Python, 20 bytes

```python
lambda x:x*2%~-2**32
```

Bitwise rotation left by 1 bit.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
‘&~^^N&$
```

Swaps the least significant set and unset bit.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rwwy1urg4PzWV/0f3HG5/1LRG4eGO7Y8a5ihEZRYoZOYVlJYoJOalKJRkpCoUpRaX5pQUK@Sngbk5mXnZegqPGuYqHNqqYK3kFAzUrIJkgGNBQSpUp0dibm5mXrpCeWpmekZJMUSX@///JmY6CoZGOgpGWlrGRrpAhqGOgjGEawgA)

#### How it works

```
‘&~^^N&$  Main link. Argument: n

‘         Increment; yield n+1, toggling all trailing set bits and the rightmost
          unset bit.
  ~       Bitwise NOT; yield ~n, toggling ALL bits of n.
 &        Bitwise AND; yield (n+1)&~n, keeping the only bit that differs in n+1 and
          ~n, i.e., the rightmost unset bit.
   ^      Perform bitwise XOR with n, toggling the rightmost unset bit.
       $  Combine the two links to the left into a monadic chain.
     N        Negate; yield -n. Since ~n = -(n+1) in 2's complement, -n = ~n+1.
      &       Take the bitwise AND of n and -n. Since -n = ~n + 1 and n = ~~n, the
              same reasoning that applied for (n+1)&~n applies to -n&n; it yields
              the rightmost unset bit of ~n, i.e., the rightmost set bit of n.
    ^      XOR the result to the left with the result to the right, toggling the
           rightmost set bit of the left one.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
32&B1YSXB
```

Circularly shifts the 32-digit binary representation one step to the right.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39hIzckwMjjC6f9/QwA)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>35</s> 31 bytes

Looks for the first bit transition (0 → 1 or 1 → 0) and inverts it.

```js
f=(n,k=3)=>(n&k)%k?n^k:f(n,k*2)
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,k=3)=>(n&k)%k?n^k:f(n,k*2)

;[ 46, 12, 255, 2**32-2 ]
.map(n => {
  r = f(n);
  console.log((n >>> 0), '=', (n >>> 0).toString(2), '-->', (r >>> 0), '=', (r >>> 0).toString(2));
})
```

### Bit rotation, 14 bytes

Much shorter but less fun.

```js
n=>n>>>31|n<<1
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>n>>>31|n<<1

;[ 46, 12, 255, 2**32-2 ]
.map(n => {
  r = f(n);
  console.log((n >>> 0), '=', (n >>> 0).toString(2), '-->', (r >>> 0), '=', (r >>> 0).toString(2));
})
```

Comment: The JavaScript bitwise operators give 32-bit signed integers rather than unsigned. For example, `f(2147483647)` is `-1073741825` and `(n=>n>>>31|n<<1)(2147483647)` is `-2`.

Comment: It's fine as long as there are no more than 32 bits.

Comment: Can you add an explanation for the first one? I'm trying to learn Javascript, and am kind of at a loss as to how you are calling f with k undefined and still getting a reasonable answer!

Comment: @musicman523 [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105982/58563) is the corresponding tip. Basically, `k` is initially set to `undefined` and we take advantage of the fact that `~undefined` equals `-1`.

Comment: @musicman523 (I'm not using this tip anymore in the updated version. But don't hesitate to ask if you have other questions about the original answer.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 78 bytes

```
(([()()])[[]()]){((){}<({({})({}())}{})>)}{}([(({}(({}){})())<>)]){({}())<>}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0MjWkNTQzNWMzo6FkRVa2hoVtfaaFRrVNdqArGGpmYtkGUHIoFKQSIgGZCkpqaNHVgHWJWNHVDF//9GhibmJhbGZiYWAA)

Returns 2n if n < 2^31, and 2n+1-2^32 otherwise.  Unfortunately, because Brain-Flak doesn't have any fast way to determine the sign of a number, the program times out on TIO if the input differs from 2^31 by more than about 500000.

#### Explanation

First, push -2^32 onto the stack:

```
(([()()])[[]()])                               push (initial value) -2 and (iterator) -5
                {((){}<                >)}     do 5 times:
                       ({({})({}())}{})        replace the current (negative) value with the negation of its square
                                            {}   pop the (now zero) iterator
```

Then, compute the desired output:

```
      (({}){})                        replace n by 2n on left stack
   ({}        ())                     push 2n+1-2^32 on left stack
  (              <>)                  push again on right stack
([                  ])                push its negation on right stack
                      {({}())<>}      add 1 to the top value of each stack until one of them reaches zero
                                {}    pop this zero, and implicitly print the number below it on the stack
```

Answer (score 3):

## dc, 10

```
?2~z31^*+p
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kUJJaXJKcWJyqkJmnYGKmYGikYGJkaWJpZg4kFaoN9fQMDWqtFVLyuRSAoKAoM68kTUFJtVhB105BSUEFphssm5qckY8QUqhRSElW0E1VUP9vb1RXZWwYp6Vd8F@dKyU/L/U/AA).

This is an arithmetic implementation of a 32bit right-rotate:

```
?           # input
 2~         # divmod by 2 - quotient pushed first, then the remainder
   z        # z pushes the size of the stack which will be 2 (quotient and remainder) ...
    31^     #  ... and take that 2 to the 31st power
       *    # multiply the remainder by 2^31
        +   # add
         p  # output
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 12 bytes

```
(2⊥32⍴1)|2×⊢
```

**How?**

```
           ⊢  ⍝ monadic argument
         2×   ⍝ shift left (×2)
(2⊥32⍴1)|     ⍝ modulo 2^32 - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>117</s> <s>17</s> 29 bytes

```
n->n*2%~-(long)Math.pow(2,32)
```

+12 bytes by changing `int` to `long`, because `int`'s max size is `2³¹-1`

<s>100</s> 89 bytes saved by creating a port of [*@AndersKaseorg*'s amazing Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124087/52210).

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##zZO9TsMwFIX3PMVRJCSbEos6bfmJYGBup25FDMYNxSW9jhK3qEXh1YNNOiABc@rBV74@555PlrxWO5XYMqf18q3VhaprzJShjwgw5PLqRekci3AECksraDYNhXjme03kt9opZzQWOOAOLSX3dC7PPhMW5Hym3Kso7TuTF6nkbRYM5fa58Iajb2fNEhufyeauMrR6fILiPwKNnzqaTLPvznxfu3wj7NaJ0otdQcxggBgs9iWQCWcfDKlq301jhod7fosgOAh9bPxv6DSdK@ZdbGAYyhNg6B8hPYFXuPSrf4yb66vJeNQ/x6@PhnTI@6f6A0t6XQLZI1sTNe0X)

Outputs:

```
46 (101110):                                     92 (1011100)
12 (1100):                                       24 (11000)
1 (1):                                           2 (10)
3 (11):                                          6 (110)
10000 (10011100010000):                          20000 (100111000100000)
987654 (11110001001000000110):                   1975308 (111100010010000001100)
2147483648 (10000000000000000000000000000000):   1 (1)
4294967294 (11111111111111111111111111111110):   4294967293 (11111111111111111111111111111101)
```

**Old answer (<s>117</s> 118 bytes):**

```
n->{long r=0;for(;!n.toBinaryString(++r).replace("0","").equals(n.toBinaryString(n).replace("0",""))|r==n;);return r;}
```

+1 byte by changing `int` to `long`, because `int`'s max size is `2³¹-1`

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##zZPBUsIwEIbvPMWaUzLQAAVRydSDZzjhCcdDLAEDJalpigPYZ69J24Mjei457E7@/Lv5NjPZ8gMPdCrUdrUr44RnGcy5VOcOgFRWmDWPBSz9FiDRagMxnvmkCHNa0XEhs9zKGJZwgghKFTyeK6OJBmytDWY3ilr9JBU3x4U1Um1wt2sINSJNXHOMBqiHEKHiI@dJhi/M6sJKvkwUKUaYETY3CgwrSuZJ0vwtcSQN0EHLFezdMLju9PIKnPyYRDrc8WTGKmVxzKzYU51bmjqzTRSW0AUEGLnkR/7NJYk/J1PwhhONG@H/gtpTVyFSX@sZhuEVMLSPMLqCVxi41T7Gw/3d5HbcPgf234TMuX2nqf7EYQ9GQ9IqVRX6fXjmO5GB1br6ydNGrpj/gA5dlwBC1thaYS86RfkN)

Outputs:

```
46 (101110):                                     15 (1111)
12 (1100):                                       3 (11)
1 (1):                                           2 (10)
3 (11):                                          5 (101)
10000 (10011100010000):                          31 (11111)
987654 (11110001001000000110):                   255 (11111111)
2147483648 (10000000000000000000000000000000):   1 (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
Mod@##+Quotient@##&[2#,2^32]&
```

[Try it at the Wolfram sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/)

Rotates left arithmetically: first multiply by 2, which possibly shifts the number out of range, then cut off the out-of-range digit with `Mod[...,2^32]` and add it back on the right with `+Quotient[...,2^32]`.

(Mathematica does have a single builtin that gives the modulus and the quotient in one go, but it's `QuotientRemainder`, which is a bit of a golfing handicap…)

Comment: Mod 2^32-1? (4 more to go)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
·žJ<%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Paj@7xsVP//NzGyNLE0MzeyNAYA)

**Explanation**

Uses the trick to rotate the binary representation left by 1 bit from [Anders Kaseorg's python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124087/47066).

```
·       # input * 2
    %   # modulus
 žJ<    # 2^32-1
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, <s>42</s> 63 bytes

```
function(x){s=x;while(s==x){sample(binaryLogic::as.binary(x))}}
```

Shuffles the bits around randomly, but checks to make sure it didn't return the same number by chance.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>81</s> 80 bytes

(1 byte saved thanks to @Ørjan Johansen reminding me dup is shorter than push 0)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDIAgIgxanACRQCczkVoACsDkFxgoWgSkAagIYocP7/b2RoYm5iYWxmYg4A)

Basically implements a cyclic right bitshift using integer arithmetic. Pushing a large constant is expensive in Whitespace so we save some bytes by pushing 2^8 and squaring it twice. (Saves 1 byte over (2^16)^2 and 10 bytes over pushing 2^32 directly.)

### Explanation

```
sssn  ; push 0
sns   ; dup
tntt  ; getnum from stdio
ttt   ; retrieve n from heap and put it on the stack
sns   ; dup
ssstsn ; push 2
tstt  ; mod - check if divisible by 2 (i.e. even)
ntsn  ; jez "even"
ssstssssssssn ; push 2^8
sns   ; dup
tssn  ; mul - square it to get 2^16
sns   ; dup
tssn  ; mul - square it to get 2^32
tsss  ; add 2^32 so MSB ends up set after the divide
nssn  ; even:
ssstsn ; push 2
tsts  ; divide by 2, aka shift right
tnst  ; putnum - display result
```

Comment: I think you can replace the second `push 0` with a `dup` one command earlier.

Comment: You're right, I just finished adding shortcut syntax to my transpiler so I've been using it too much...

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 89 bytes

Full Program:

```
from random import*;a=list(bin(input())[2:].zfill(32));shuffle(a);print int(''.join(a),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxDsIwDEDRq3SrjaBDQAxEnKRiMKVRjFI7St2B3rtzyPD1pp9/FlVcraHo0hWST4OXrMVOnp6JV4M3C7DkzQBxdI/XsAdOCa4O0a9xCyHNQOhzYbGuBX0/fLVNhGeHtd7uh@hloinOfw)

Suggestions welcome! :)

Comment: That is not valid because it can by chance return the same number again.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 15 bytes

```
n->2*n%(2^32-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P185IK09VwyjO2EjXUPN/QVFmXolGmoaRpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
Ñ%3pH
```

Bitwise rotation, like most answers here.

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0SUzcEg&input=MTI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 39 bytes

```perl
$_=sprintf'0b%b',$_;$_=oct$_.int s/10//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4oCgzryRN3SBJNUldRyXeGiiWn1yiEq8HFFYo1jc00Nf//9/8X35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDAyCdlJkOVPJftwAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>45</s> 39 bytes

*-6 bytes thanx to ceilingcat*

```cpp
auto h(unsigned x){return x%2<<31|x/2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1dC4IwGEav2694UQYbGOmMPlD6Jd3INnVQrzI3GJi/fVlE3p3ncOCR47jvpIyx8W6AnnmcTIdaQeCz1c5bhEBFXZfFKxxEtcTUoHx4pWs5OWWGGyGp0q1BDU5PjgUOozXoWpZQD9TfMclC1q@eE7J6eDYGGScz2X37nFc/Kjb63P2XyLfmehHn8nRc9xLf)

Comment: -6 bytes using `x=` instead of `return`.

Comment: That's not valid in C++.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. This is code golf.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda i:int(f'{i:32b}'[1:]+f'{i:32b}'[:1],2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZRvzPycxNyklUSHTKjOvRCNNvTrTytgoqVY92tAqVhuJa2UYq2Ok@b@gCKRMw9DGxthQU9tQRyELwdHU/A8A)