# The Third String

Tags: code-golf, string

Given two strings, output a third string that is not equal to either of the two inputs, but has the same length (in characters) as either of the inputs. There is guaranteed to be at least one valid output.

## Test Cases

Test cases are quoted to show they are strings. Outputs are one of many possible.

```
input, input -> output

"test", "test" -> "tttt"
"do", "don't" -> "dnut_"
"ye s", "yes" -> "fals"
"yes", "yes" -> "noo"
"maybe", "mayue" -> "false"
"false", "false" -> "truee"
"false", "true" -> "fatr"
"1", "" -> "0"
"", "t" -> "s"
"", "abcabc" -> "testst"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" -> "zbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxya"
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" -> "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
```

### Rules

- You may chose your input domain, but it must be composed of at least printable ASCII, and your output domain must be the same as your input domain.
- The input lengths may be the same or different.
- The output must be valid with probability 1; that is, you may generate random strings until one is valid (and theoretically you might infinite loop), but you can't just output a random string and hope it's valid. Note that this means you output does not need to be deterministic.
- Automatic trailing newlines allowed, but they do not count towards the length of the output.
- Due to questions regarding Memory Errors, it must work within 60 seconds up to input lengths of `6`. An answer that works for that and theoretically works for longer strings is OK, but something that Memory Errors on modern computer for input length `4` is not valid.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123539/same-length-different-string), [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13735#13735)

Comment: Can my code fail for MaxChar in input, but be able to output it?

Comment: @H.PWiz no. if it can be outputted, it has to be able to be inputted, otherwise you could just do `MaxChar.repeat(s1.length)`

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: This seems like another of an interesting new category of questions on this site that are easy for humans and hard for computers. Because computers aren't good at divergent thinking! It reminds me of the Spongebob episode where he's up all night trying to write an essay on what NOT to do at a stoplight.

Comment: Test case: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`. Mine failed for it

Comment: I understand the output domain can be a subset of the input domain, yes?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes.

Comment: Will the two inputs ever both be an empty string?

Comment: @kamoroso94 no, because there is guaranteed to be a valid output.

Comment: Nice question! I like it.

Comment: For `"1", ""` may we output `""`?

Comment: @Quelklef No, that's not different from both inputs.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Of course. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest "", "1" should be added as a test case, since I just realized my answer fails for this even though it works for all the provided test cases

Comment: I'm pretty sure the point of @Slowloris 's request was to have the empty string as the *first* one.

Comment: Suggested test case: both input strings are longer than 256 characters.

Comment: @DLosc added, thanks

Answer (score 13):

## Haskell, 43 bytes

```haskell
x!y=[s|s<-(<$max x y)<$>"abc",s/=x,s/=y]!!0
```

Takes the max (lexicographically later) string, which we know is nonempty; replaces all characters with one of "a", "b", and "c" using `<$`; and returns the first that is neither of the inputs. I think this is similar to [Neil's Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139625/19857) and/or [geokavel's CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139627/19857).

(I've lurked for a while but this is my first time answering on this site; hi!)

Answer (score 9):

## Brainfuck, 97 bytes

```
+>+[-,[>>,]<<[<<]>]>>[>]<<<[<]>[<+>>[-<+<+>>][>]<[->+<]<[-]>>>++<[<]>[.>>]>[>>]]>[+[>]+[<]>[.>>]]
```

[Run code online](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=IyBMZXQgKEtuKSBiZSB0aGUgbnRoIGNoYXJhY3RlciBvZiBLCiMgTGV0ICheKSBkZXNpZ25hdGUgdGhlIHBvaW50ZXIKIyBMZXQgRiBiZSB0aGUgZmlyc3Qgc3RyaW5nIGlucHV0dGVkCiMgTGV0IFMgYmUgdGhlIHNlY29uZCBzdHJpbmcgaW5wdXR0ZWQKCis-K1stICAjIFR3aWNlIGRvCixbPj4sXSAgIyBJbnB1dCBzdHJpbmcgKGNoYXJhY3RlcnMgc2VwYXJhdGVkIGJ5IDEpCjw8Wzw8XT4gICMgR28gdG8gbGVmdCBvZiBiZWdpbm5pbmcgb2Ygc3RyaW5nCl0-ICAjIEVuZCBvbiBmaXJzdCBjaGFyYWN0ZXIgb2Ygc2Vjb25kIHN0cmluZwojIElmIHNlY29uZCBzdHJpbmcgaXMgbnVsbCB3ZSB3aWxsIGVuZCBvbmUgdG9vIGZhciB0byB0aGUgbGVmdAo-Wz5dPDw8WzxdPiAgIyBJZiBmaXJzdCBzdHJpbmcgaXMgbnVsbCB3ZSB3aWxsIGVuZCB0aGVyZSB0b28KIyBXZSB3aWxsIHVzZSB0aGlzIHRvIGRvIGZsb3cgY29udHJvbAoKWyAgIyBPbmx5IHJ1biBpZiBib3RoIHN0cmluZ3Mgd2VyZSBub24gbnVsbAoKIyBUYXBlOiAgICBTMCAnIEYwICcgUzEgJyBGMSAnIFMyICcgRjIgJyBldGMKIyAgICAgICAgICBeCgo8Kz4-ICAjIExldCBGMCogPSBGMCAocGx1cykgMSAgKGlzIDEgYXMgb2Ygbm93OyBGMCB3aWxsIGJlIGFkZGVkIGxhdGVyKQpbLTwrPCs-Pl0gIyBMZXQgQSA9IFMwIChwbHVzKSBGMAojIEEgbWF5IG9yIG1heSBub3QgYmUgemVybwojIEYwKiBtYXkgb3IgbWF5IG5vdCBiZSB6ZXJvCiMgVGFwZTogICAgRjAqICcgQSAnIDAgICcgUzEgJyBGMSAnIGV0YwojICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIF4KCls-XTxbLT4rPF0gICMgTGV0IEIgPSBBIG9yIEYwKgojIEIgbWF5IG9yIG1heSBub3QgYmUgemVybwo8Wy1dPj4gICMgQ2xlYXIgRjAqCiMgVGFwZTogICAgIDAgJyBCICcgMCAnIFMxICcgRjEgJyBldGMgICAgKGlmIEEgd2FzIHplcm8pCiMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBeCiMgT1IgICAgICAgIDAgJyAwICcgQiAnIHMxICcgRjEgJyBldGMgICAgKGlmIEEgd2FzIG5vbnplcm8pCiMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXgoKIyBMZXQgQyA9IEIgb3IgMgojIEMgd2lsbCBiZSBndWFyYW50ZWVkIG5vbnplcm8gYW5kIHVuaXF1ZSBmcm9tIFMwIGFuZCBGMAo-Kys8WzxdPiAgIyBDcmVhdGUgQwpbLj4-XSAgIyBQcmludCAodXNpbmcgUyBvciBGOyBkb2VzIG5vdCBtYXR0ZXIpCgo-Wz4-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-WyAgIyBFeGVjdXRlIG9ubHkgaWYgb25lIHN0cmluZyB3YXMgbnVsbAoKKyAgIyBMZXQgQSA9IEUwIChwbHVzKSAxCiMgQSBtYXkgb3IgbWFueSBub3QgYmUgemVybwojIFRhcGU6IDAgJyBBICcgMCAnIEUxICcgZXRjCiMgICAgICAgICAgIF4KCls-XStbPF0-ICAjIExldCBCID0gQSBvciAxCiMgQiBpcyBndWFyYW50ZWVkIG5vbnplcm8gYW5kICE9IEUwCiMgVGFwZTogMCAnIEIgJyA_ICcgRTEgJyAwICcgRTIgJyBldGMKIyAgICAgICAgICAgXgoKWy4-Pl0gICMgUHJpbnQKCiMgRW5kIG9uIHplcm8gY2VsbCBhcyBub3QgdG8gbG9vcApdICAjIEVuZCBudWxsIGJsb2Nr) (note that "dynamic memory" must be selected in the bottom-right)

Awesome challenge! I thought it would be trivial but it ended up being really difficult. I keep coming back to it because I feel like there *should* be some elegant 20-or-so-byte BF solution. At this point, I'm pretty happy I (seemingly) got it to work at all in BF.

Input is taken as `str1` + `\0` + `str2`, where strings are consecutive non-zero 1-byte characters.

Returns `(first str1 + first str2) or (first str1 + 1) or 2`. This algorithm was thought up by the brilliant @ØrjanJohansen, (presumably) based on my (broken) original one.

Commented:

```
# Let (Kn) be the nth character of K
# Let (^) designate the pointer
# Let F be the first string inputted
# Let S be the second string inputted

+>+[-  # Twice do
,[>>,]  # Input string (characters separated by 1)
<<[<<]>  # Go to left of beginning of string
]>  # End on first character of second string
# If second string is null we will end one too far to the left
>[>]<<<[<]>  # If first string is null we will end there too
# We will use this to do flow control

[  # Only run if both strings were non null

# Tape:    S0 ' F0 ' S1 ' F1 ' S2 ' F2 ' etc
#          ^

<+>>  # Let F0* = F0 (plus) 1  (is 1 as of now; F0 will be added later)
[-<+<+>>] # Let A = S0 (plus) F0
# A may or may not be zero
# F0* may or may not be zero
# Tape:    F0* ' A ' 0  ' S1 ' F1 ' etc
#                ^

[>]<[->+<]  # Let B = A or F0*
# B may or may not be zero
<[-]>>  # Clear F0*
# Tape:     0 ' B ' 0 ' S1 ' F1 ' etc    (if A was zero)
#               ^
# OR        0 ' 0 ' B ' s1 ' F1 ' etc    (if A was nonzero)
#                   ^

# Let C = B or 2
# C will be guaranteed nonzero and unique from S0 and F0
>++<[<]>  # Create C
[.>>]  # Print (using S or F; does not matter)

>[>>]  # End on a zero cells with zero cells all to the right
# This is necessary for the coming functionality
# also as to not loop
]  # End non null block

# Now we consider if one of the strings was null
# Tape:    0 ' E0 ' 0 ' E1 ' etc    (if one string was null)
#          ^
# Tape:    0 '  0 ' 0 '  0 ' etc    (if neither string was null)
#          ^
# Where E is F or S (we don't care)

>[  # Execute only if one string was null

+  # Let A = E0 (plus) 1
# A may or many not be zero
# Tape: 0 ' A ' 0 ' E1 ' etc
#           ^

[>]+[<]>  # Let B = A or 1
# B is guaranteed nonzero and != E0
# Tape: 0 ' B ' ? ' E1 ' 0 ' E2 ' etc
#           ^

[.>>]  # Print

# End on zero cell as not to loop
]  # End null block
```

Comment: Your "fact" is wrong, e.g. `a=2`, `b=1`. You need to add instead of subtracting.

Comment: I think you can fix the `S` empty problem by adding `>` at the start and later doing `[<]>` on the leftmost byte of `S` - if that's nonzero it does nothing, otherwise it switches the strings.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Oh you're right, it can equal `b`. But not `a`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ah, that appears to work! Good thinking!

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Follow up about the fact: Since it's `!= a` only, if I print `S/0, S/1, ...` instead of `S/0, F/1, ...` it should work.

Comment: It could still break if S and F are equal after the first character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64158/discussion-between-quelklef-and-orjan-johansen).

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
żḟ@€ØAZḢ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//xbzhuJ9A4oKsw5hBWuG4ov///0H/QUE)**

#### How?

```
żḟ@€ØAZḢ - Link: list of characters, a; list of characters, b
ż        - zip a and b
    ØA   - uppercase alphabet
 ḟ@€     - filter discard for €ach (swap @rguments)
      Z  - transpose the result
       Ḣ - head
```

Comment: It returns `B` [TIO](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//xbzhuJ9A4oKsw5hBWuG4ov///0H/QQ)

Comment: The algorithm shouldn't anyway, not sure what you did.

Comment: nevermind my brain apparently playing tricks since I don't see any `X` or `Ẋ` in there...

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>62</strike> <strike>47</strike> <strike>57</strike> <strike>54</strike> 51 bytes

**Edit:** - 5 bytes thanks to [@Mr.Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

**Edit:** +10 bytes to fix a bug

**Edit:** -3 bytes thanks to [@betaveros](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/19857/betaveros)

**Edit:** -3 bytes by using max instead of pop

```python
lambda x,y:max({*"abc"}-{x[:1],y[:1]})+max(x,y)[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fYxvzPycxNyklUaFCp9IqN7FCo1pLKTEpWalWt7oi2sowVqcSRNZqaoPkgGo0ow2tYv8XFGXmlWjkaCgp6SgZFippav4HAA)

Comment: `{"a","b","c"}` ==> `{*"abc"}` ([57 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcZLCoAgFADAq8hbaVkU7YJOUi5ePwpMxQwU8ewWzWpMcIdWXZbDlCVe84rE89DTWADOC6QqeoJqJX5sBA9/w9fEaqMNZaUf215kY0/lqKTg7LMBhx3lvQFj@QU))

Comment: `(x[1:]or y[1:])` ==> `max(x,y)[1:]`?

Comment: Or just `(x or y)[1:]`, I think you only need to avoid the empty string.

Comment: Incidentally, it's a shame Python 2 doesn't have starred set literals, because I really wanted to golf `{*"abc"}` into ``{*`id`}``...

Comment: Save 1 with `*len(x or y)` instead of `+max(x,y)[1:]`.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 111 bytes

```
(c=Characters;a=#2;While[f=Alphabet[]~RandomChoice~Length@#;f==#||f==c@a]&[#&@@c@{##}~MaximalBy~Length];""<>f)&
```

[try it online](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/) (paste code with ctrl+v, place input at the end and hit shift+enter)

input

> ["test","me"]

*thanx **@Not a tree** for checking and golfing -21 bytes*

Comment: How do I test this online again?

Comment: added link+info

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Seems to fail if the first string is the empty string

Comment: @HalvardHummel fixed!

Comment: why the downvote???

Comment: I downvoted because there's still a lot of easy golfing that can be done to this: try `(While[f=Alphabet[]~RandomChoice~Length@#;f==#]&[#&@@Characters@{##}~MaximalBy~Length];""<>f)&`. But after looking at it some more, I think it's invalid — if the two strings are equal in length there's a small chance of returning one of them, since you only check if the random string is equal to one of the two.

Comment: @Notatree fixed. If you think that "easy golfing" is a reason for downvoting then you are welcome to do so

Comment: …I suppose that was quite harsh of me. I'm sorry. Downvote reversed.

Comment: you don't have to upvote either... anyways I'll try to implement your version.thanx

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
ＦＥα×ι⌈⟦ＬθＬη⟧¿¬№⟦θη⟧ιＰι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYkxDoMwDAD3vsKjI5kXdOxKmFgAMVgIGksJgZAgfu@C1JtOd5PjNEX2qktMgJY3ZIJWwnygEFi@JJSAQz2v3@xwNwR/dWY0NyALYBMzfmJZMw47gRsJ5Fm2@CxbkruLeat23avvtTq1OvwP) Link is to verbose version of code. Generates all strings of uppercase characters repeated to the length of the longer input and overprints all those that don't appear in the input. In other words, the output is normally `ZZZ...` unless that is one of the inputs, in which case it's `YYY...` unless that is the other input, in which case it's `XXX...`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>51</s> <s>47</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

***-4** bytes by using builtin array `argv`, **-10** bytes by using prefix removal and `RC_EXPAND_PARAM`, **-1** byte by inlining the brace expansion.*

```sh
<<<${${${:-{1..3}${^@#?}}:|argv}[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcjRCoIwGIbh813Fhwn/kcLqzAZ1H1Gw2l8OxiZOFFy79qUQ78nLs8a@LL11jJG1gbOezzBB8KwdIk9oGlT1zlVRStVpr2uSbNtTrtPjerjk3H31@JnzTd5zMcFzkTgKIkghQSToHQKeeiT8b92MvYkANlvs1CMO@sUbkPgB)

First, this was an awesome challenge, I went through a ton of ideas before landing on this one.

```sh
<<<${${${:-{1..3}${^@#?}}:|argv}[1]}
       ${:-             }            # empty fallback
                 ${ @#?}             # remove first character from each parameter
                 ${^@  }             # enable brace expansion (set -P)
           {1..3}${^@#?}             # expand to 1foo 2foo 3foo 1bar 2bar 3bar
     ${                  :|argv}     # Set difference with 'argv'
   ${                           [1]} # The first found element
<<<                                  # print to stdout
```

`@` and `*` are not identifiers, so `${  :|@}` and `${  :|*}` don't work, hence the use of `${  :|argv}`

> This method will work up to 93 inputs and find a 94th which is unique. Simply replace the `{1..3}` with the maximum possible range `{~..!}`.

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>48</s> 47 bytes*

```c
for ((;$#i<${#${1:-$2}}||$@[(I)$i];i++)):
<<<$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPDWkU500alWlml2tBKV8WotramRsUhWsNTUyUz1jpTW1tT04rLxsZGJfM/EBgaAAA)

Completely new method courtesy of JoKing's Perl 6 submission, but doesn't work on large strings (n>20) due to integer size restrictions. `$@[(I)$i]` is reverse array lookup to largest index, it will output zero (falsy in arithmetic expansion) if $i is not found in the command line parameters.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>38</s> 30 bytes

```perl6
{(1 x.max.comb...*∉$_).tail}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1rDUKFCLzexQi85PzdJT09P61FHp0q8pl5JYmZO7f/ixEqFNI1oJUNDQyUdIGmkFKtpzQUTtQSKWRgYoIgp6SgolaQWl6AIggWAEmDB/wA)

Anonymous codeblock that takes input as a list of two strings, and returns the first number from `1111...` with a non-empty amount of 1s that isn't in the input.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                          }   # Anonymous code block
  1 x.max.comb                 # String multiply 1 by the size of the non-empty string
              ...              # Create a sequence increasing by 1
                 *∉$_          # Until the number is not in the input
 (                   ).tail    # And take the last number
```

Comment: Is the incrementor a bigint type, or will this overflow for sufficiently large strings?

Comment: @GammaFunction In Perl 6, the default number type is Int, which has infinite precision

Comment: Oh, nice. I was going to adapt this to Zsh, but it uses `long long` unfortunately.

Comment: You can trim 6 bytes by just taking the first of 00..,111..,22.. instead of counting and sequences: https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzots6i4REHrUUenSryORpyxQkSFtl5uYoVecn5ukmbt/@LESoU0jWglQwMDJR0gaagUq2nNBRO1BIpZAmWQxZR0FJRKUotLUATBAkAJFEFDIAAaYGAANeE/AA

Comment: @PhilH Good idea! I've shortened it a bit more by keeping with the sequence idea

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
c"1Y2@X-1)&h
```

Input is a cell array of strings containing printable ASCII chars. The output is formed from the letters `'ABC'`, and so belongs to the input domain.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P1nJMNLIIULXUFMt4///avXEpGR1HQV1RydnF1f1WgA)

#### Explanation

The output is as long as the longest input string. Its *n*-th character is the first letter from `'ABC'` that is different from the *n*-th character of both input strings.

```
c        % Concatenate the two strings vertically. If one is shorter it is
         % right-padded with spaces. Gives a 2-row character matrix
"        % For each column
  1Y2    %   Push the string 'ABC...Z' (the upper-case letters)
  @      %   Push current column
  X-     %   Set difference
  1)     %   Get first character
  &h     %   Horizontally concatenate the results so far
         % End (implicit). Display stack (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
øvAyм¬?
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8I4yx8oLew6tsf//Pzk/JZUrPT8nDQA)

Comment: Does this work when one input is the empty string?

Comment: Doesn't work if the first string is empty. [TIO](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8I4yx8oLew6tsf//nysxEQA)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>56</s> <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```
x#y|_:t<-max x y=[c:t|c<-"abc",c:t/=x,c:t/=y]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9DsIgFIV3n@L2doGEqnNT3kAnx6ZpAGs0FtIgJJD03RHRDi7n58vJuYvXc5rnlEId17F1XaNFgACR96p1q@oaFFIhy@XAw9fiUFXHpMXDAActlvMIZPHu4uzJ7L1R3tpIakqh3wEAQTHdkOE1K2U/8rlEmXUjyLIV/r/BnDciCykbGNIb)

Replace the first char of the maximum of the two input strings with `a`, `b`and `c` and pick the first one that is different from both input strings.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 53 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{([?a,?b,?c].map{|e|e*[a,b].max.size}-[a,b])[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxLCoMwEAbgvacIKlRLlPYArQexLhKdgFAfmAi16tltxidqZ5HM/80wVc2bwRaP1@A9GeWtEwaMBpwGceRnrGw76OAa6gnGjy/TL/TemN3wFvVDAoIokMrR5BpEV1krSUwRWi3z01yWEKueEqvla4rIQ2dbTGcXNQ3IE8PAY8TE16TzP1tSoCRFflmpASIRG5AbHSVjDQc03dSwqGBvOerUHFVV2yrDQpyaf3pCjrXoHWVdGce7FO/SeoyfN5cw7Q0/)

Basically generates the strings `a...a`, `b...b`, and `c...c` and selects the first not in the input.

Comment: Fails if the first input is the empty string.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo fixed

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcxLDoIwEAbgPadoiolgsNEDoAdBFi1MExN5hJYgAmfHjkgJ4iza@b9Op6pFO@5keBuPl0PTed6VM3ZNfJbxsuuhh0Nj2idT9xcMx8aPTvEwpiCJBqU9HgjfIabKWitCZeR2nN1zVUKih4C4nbApJqHJOxmZP7FV6kCeOg4uIxRPGnzvr6UFSlrke0stEIXYglroVzLeCkAzTQ2zSv5QH52aX9XVMsqxEKfmn25QYM16RrEjn@dVSlbJLhPbyTlMc@Mb)

Answer (score 3):

## ES6, 54 bytes

```
a=>b=>(a[0]+b[0]|0?'a':9-(a[0]^b[0]))+(a||b).substr(1)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 7 <s>8</s> bytes

```
hC-LG.T
```

*1 byte thanks to Jakube*

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hC-LG.T&input=%22test%22%2C+%22test%22+-%3E+%22tttt%22%0A%22do%22%2C+%22don%27t%22+-%3E+%22dnut_%22%0A%22ye+s%22%2C+%22yes%22+-%3E+%22fals%22%0A%22yes%22%2C+%22yes%22+-%3E+%22noo%22%0A%22maybe%22%2C+%22mayue%22+-%3E+%22false%22%0A%22false%22%2C+%22false%22+-%3E+%22truee%22%0A%22false%22%2C+%22true%22+-%3E+%22fatr%22%0A%221%22%2C+%22%22+-%3E+%220%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22test%22%2C+%22test%22+%0A%22do%22%2C+%22don%27t%22+%0A%22ye+s%22%2C+%22yes%22+%0A%22yes%22%2C+%22yes%22+%0A%22maybe%22%2C+%22mayue%22+%0A%22false%22%2C+%22false%22+%0A%22false%22%2C+%22true%22+%0A%221%22%2C+%22%22+%0A%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22%2C+%22aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa%22&debug=0)

We use `.T`, length preserving transpose, rather than `C`, truncating transpose, so that it works on inputs where one string is empty.

Given two strings as a tuple, we transpose them (`.T`), then map the resulting pair of characters or single character by subtracting the character(s) from the lowerase alphabet with `-LG`, then transpose the resulting list of strings of unused characters with `C`, then return the first such string with `h`. This consists of the first letter alphabetically that is not in either string, for each position.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>100</s> 73 bytes

-27 bytes thanks to @Nevay's magical touch! :)

```java
a->b->{b=b.length<1?a:b;if(a.length<1||(b[0]^=2)==a[0])b[0]^=1;return b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJRb4IwEMef56e4kJjBosTCmwjLsmRve9qjuqRoURy2pC0uRPnsrrXo3I2kubvfXf@9cLejBzoWNeO79de53NdCatgZFja6rMKi4StdCh4@JYO6yatyBauKKgXvtORwHAD0VGmqjTmIcg17k/M/tCz5Zr4EKjcquJQCvPVys9WWyvlyhGNnsgyK9EzHWT7OjnmahxXjG72dkWc6zZOy8OmNnE5@Pp8sP9MoSFNqvMCFJJFMN5JDnnTn5PL2tSHTkmZKK0hNUw9HzwbeCJztRhathQVrwR@vpGWgLGuZuhEE9rTNmUXGaVgPC1qpC3QOglq6Qrh8R49YeA9sTO7BxBuZg8C/igiDGL3yV4NgDYI1CNaIsEaENSKsEWGNGGvEWCPGGvG9RufmWgj5u2x2iFM33@vOmcm3SrN9KBod1qZOF7638IZqYf6uszDOem/IDbTXzRb1DjEOZ9/9/vhFSOu6av2@KNTi1Szti5S09YPgPklwMghcx93Anu78Aw)

Input domain = Printable ASCII + codepoint 127.

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZJRb4IwEMef56e4kJjBosTCmwjLsmRve9qjuqRoURy2pC0uRPnsrrXo3I2kubvfXf@9cLejBzoWNeO79de53NdCatgZFja6rMKi4StdCh4@JYO6yatyBauKKgXvtORwHAD0VGmqjTmIcg17k/M/tCz5Zr4EKjcquJQCvPVys9WWyvlyhGNnsgyK9EzHWT7OjnmahxXjG72dkWc6zZOy8OmNnE5@Pp8sP9MoSFNqvMCFJJFMN5JDnnTn5PL2tSHTkmZKK0hNUw9HzwbeCJztRhathQVrwR@vpGWgLGuZuhEE9rTNmUXGaVgPC1qpC3QOglq6Qrh8R49YeA9sTO7BxBuZg8C/igiDGL3yV4NgDYI1CNaIsEaENSKsEWGNGGvEWCPGGvG9RufmWgj5u2x2iFM33@vOmcm3SrN9KBod1qZOF7638IZqYf6uszDOem/IDbTXzRb1DjEOZ9/9/vhFSOu6av2@KNTi1Szti5S09YPgPklwMghcx93Anu78Aw "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program, takes input as a 2-element nested list.

```apl
⊃¨⎕A∘~¨,⌿↑⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKNdIe3/o67mQyse9U11fNQxo@7QCp1HPfsftU0ECoDk/3OmcWmoOzo5q2tqqLu4uqlrcoFFUvJBAin5eerqJTAxR5AQjANiAwUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <strike>23</strike> 22 bytes

```
+.)-.{<G3.{,<Q1<KE1t|K
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B.%29-.%7B%3CG3.%7B%2C%3CQ1%3CKE1t%7CK&input=%22abc%22%0A%22abd%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22test%22%0A%22test%22%0A%0A%22do%22%0A%22don%27t%22%0A%0A%22ye+s%22%0A%22yes%22%0A%0A%22yes%22%0A%22yes%22%0A%0A%22maybe%22%0A%22mayue%22%0A%0A%22false%22%0A%22false%22%0A%0A%22false%22%0A%22true%22%0A%0A%221%22%0A%22%22%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 22 bytes

```
+eS-.{<G3.{,<Q1<KE1t|K
```

**[Test Suite!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BeS-.%7B%3CG3.%7B%2C%3CQ1%3CKE1t%7CK&input=%22abc%22%0A%22abd%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22test%22%0A%22test%22%0A%0A%22do%22%0A%22don%27t%22%0A%0A%22ye+s%22%0A%22yes%22%0A%0A%22yes%22%0A%22yes%22%0A%0A%22maybe%22%0A%22mayue%22%0A%0A%22false%22%0A%22false%22%0A%0A%22false%22%0A%22true%22%0A%0A%221%22%0A%22%22%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

---

## Explanation

```
+.)-.{<G3.{,<Q1<KE1t|K  - Full program.
      <G3               - Yields the String "abc"; Alphabet[:3].
    .{                  - Set formed by the above.
         .{,<Q1<KE1     - Set formed by input_1[:1] and input_2[:1]
   -                    - Set subtraction.
 .)                     - Pop the last element.
+                       - Append.
                   t|K  - input_1[1:] or input_2[1:], relying on the result of Logical OR.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 56 bytes

```
->a,b{a,b=b,a if a<b;a[0]=([?a,?b,?c]-[a[0],b[0]])[0];a}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 119 bytes

Lambda (curried) from `String` to lambda from `String` to `String`. Assign to `Function<String, Function<String, String>>`.

```java
s->t->{String r=s.length()>t.length()?s:t;while((s+t).contains(r))r=r.substring(1)+(char)(Math.random()*128);return r;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##jVJNj9owED1nf8U0EpJdwIJeWm02VFXV3va0x10OJhhimjjUMwEhNr@djmOCqHqpZMnPz/Px5mOnD3ra7I3brX9d9u2qsgUUlUaEZ20dnB@SvbcHTQaQNPHnjh1US7ZSm9YVZBunfl7B0wt567aT/7KJ92IBVFq/ji/ILzhd0HRxvr59jqoybkulkAu6wa/4SNmxtJURAsckVdE4YrkovJQ@9wrbFfYRxFyORVFqL8WzplJ57dZNLeTH@acvMvOGWu/AZ90lyR641Fj/tdJDY9dQc1gR1bwuQfstytCUZKCYLDQahBycOcIdHaySc0oGKZ1AvLtJJGt9WpnAMmjNjX5rZ7PPPd@jTfzogrRk03i4E/Kdk8JjzB0VJS8nJFOrpiXFM3NUDcIV@9aaRDrCCYyQ3UbISfoYr7PlgOaM7oah9H5fncRgJf96z5dSyiyIu2kLXYaC@zDL@HoC7nAA4xzmg8A4VF6r@2aJAINz6FnR9VEHU66Fbf8VZd0gJ02jg92ACJUPKwIfOC@8v4cQyvxudYXB66okodI3x17EN0Tjw2b@8L7xIkbr@sr4dJc/)

### Ungolfed lambda

```java
s ->
    t -> {
        String r = s.length() > t.length() ? s : t;
        while ((s + t).contains(r))
            r = r.substring(1) + (char) (Math.random() * 128);
        return r;
    }
```

This solution rotates random ASCII characters into the longer string until the required conditions are satisfied. Inputs are UTF-8 and outputs are ASCII.

I don't know the gritty details of Unicode, but it seems plausible to me that this solution could fail when an appended `char` joins the preceding code point to form a single code unit. If someone who knows more about this can verify this, I'll change the input domain to ASCII.

## Java 8, 126 bytes

Same type as above.

```java
s->t->{String r;for(byte[]o=(s.length()>t.length()?s:t).getBytes();(s+t).contains(r=new String(o));o[0]%=128)o[0]++;return r;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##jVJNj9owED1nf8U0EpIjwIJeWm02qdqqvfW0R5aDCQZMg009E1aIzW@n4zihVL1UiuTnl/l48zx7dVJTd9R2v/55PTar2lRQ1QoRfihj4fKQHL05KdKApIh/7jlBNmRquWlsRcZZ@b0HT8/kjd1O/ismnmUJtDN@HW9QXHFa0rS89Hefb5wXqzPpxdIVAmWt7ZZ2IivpBj/hI2Vyq@kLh6HIcoFjJipniSdA4QurX/t2wmVZ7haz5aiYv/@YBTQe515T4y03a69J/sATRxv6gU/OrOHApUSssViC8lvMgjfJQDFZKdQIBfzp1tEhKrmkLI3SCcSznUTyoM4rHVgGjb7RL81s9qHjO7SJP9ogLWE/4E7IV24Kj7F3VJQ8n5H0QbqGJD@dpXoQLjn3oEikI5zACDlthNykq8FGDGjO6O5NpDoe67MYorK/7vNlxoYGcTdt1U55qNiHWc7HE7DPAYwLmA8C49vydt2bJQIMycGzqu2qDqE8C8f@K8rYQU6axgSzAREmH5YD3nFfeHsLJaT@1agaQ1avJKGdd6@diM@I2ocF/eY9r1ys1naT8ddefwM)

### Ungolfed lambda

```java
s ->
    t -> {
        String r;
        for (
            byte[] o = (s.length() > t.length() ? s : t).getBytes();
            (s + t).contains(r = new String(o));
            o[0] %= 128
        )
            o[0]++;
        return r;
    }
```

This increments the first byte of the longer string, wrapping within ASCII, until the required conditions are met. Inputs and outputs are ASCII strings.

Comment: Given the output of your third test case, it outputs a string of length three: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHBasMwDD2nX2EKBYemZr02SwYb7LZTjyUHN3VTd4kdLKUllHza2CftEzKlTrfuNjBIetaT3rOP8iQXtlbmuHvv62Zb6pzlpQRgb1IbdpkEtdMniYoBSqTLIxFEg7oU@8bkqK0Rr2PyuEanTRH9q8fHNGV40G7nK5b0sEhxkV62LapNZhMOolSmwAMPU/xJn2CFoSgUPlMb8DAe6S4@H3SpOIc53efWIHkA7hKjzuNCbsMwtJuHbD6PncLGGWJ1fRBPyKm3Pxo9Wb1jFQ3gnrnJmHQFhMObBDeIwFyCApaw3x1XeOgKLlPSh9OI@dhFHqxku1UDSkmjfuCvz48B9HU3KAr21rG7/S@0i638Si8kWLeAqhK2QUE/ZbC86RXErSTy6QwiNgOizYDGX2eQ/1u2pOzuC4Ss67Llt67wT73M6PHiQdyETtd/Aw "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah, crap. Now I'm going to have to learn how Unicode works in order to fix this without exploding the byte count...

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, <s>82</s> 79 bytes

```
sub{$_=$_[0];$_=$_[1]||$_ if/^(xz*)?$/;s/[^z]/z/||s/./y/;$_ eq$_[1]&&s/./x/;$_}
```

Takes input as two separate arguments and returns the third string.

The subroutine attempts to produce a string very similar to the first string but with the first non-`z` character replaced with a `z`. Then it deals with corner cases by replacing the first character with `y` or `x`, as needed, if it finds that one of the inputs was in fact a sequence of all `z`'s.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>89</s> 67 bytes

*@Giuseppe saved 9 bytes, @user2390246 saved 13 bytes*

#### function

```
function(x,y)sub("^.",letters[!letters%in%substr(c(x,y),1,1)][1],x)
```

#### demo

```
# define function
f <- function(x,y)sub("^.",letters[!letters%in%substr(c(x,y),1,1)][1],x)

# test cases
f("test","test")
[1] "aest"
f("do","don't")
[1] "ao"
f("ye s","yes")
[1] "ae s"
f("maybe","mayue")
[1] "aaybe"
f("false","false")
[1] "aalse"
f("false","true")
[1] "aalse"
f("1","")
[1] "a"
f("art","bug")
[1] "crt"
```

Comment: You can put `x` and `y` within the same `substr` command. Also, curly braces and `return` are unnecessary: `function(x,y)sub("^.",letters[!letters%in%substr(c(x,y),1,1)][1],x)`

Comment: You can get rid of `return` since this is a function, and the braces since it's a one liner.

Comment: Shoot, I just realized that `f("","1")` yields `""`, which is equal to the first input... maybe this should be added as another test case

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 68 bytes

```
sub{$_="a"x length $_[0]||$_[1];$_++while $_ eq$_[0]||$_ eq$_[1];$_}
```

Explanation:

- starts with (string of letter "a" as long as first string) or second string if that is false i.e. zero-length
- keeps incrementing that until it's different from both first and second

Starting from "a"s was to avoid incrementing to point where Perl lengthens the string; with only two strings to avoid being same as, it couldn't overflow.

Execute with:

```
perl -e '$s = ' -E 'sub{$_="a"x length $_[0]||$_[1];$_++while $_ eq$_[0]||$_ eq$_[1];$_}' -E ';say $s->("z", "true")'
```

Comment: I think this will fail if the first string is empty.

Comment: Quite right! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <del>70</del> <del>65</del> <del>73</del> <del>67</del> 61 bytes

The function needs the provided strings to be mutable (i.e. either arrays or dynamically allocated).

```c
f(a,b)char*a,*b;{a=*a?a:b;*a=*a>70?33:99;*a+=*a==*b;puts(a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY1BbsIwEEX3PsXIG@I0lahYVMEKHKTqYuzYkJbEqe3Quoizpw5CqmpRgfDK/81/M/JxI@U46gwLweQWbY5FLvgBqxzXuBQ8n36r5/l6sViWZYwPMVdV7PSDdxkyfhybzkOLTZftTVMzOJBpEWhjXsryFSqgXjlPCxBo/xBOAHQWe6cR4yRm563swwnS2lBWnEEsTKCbecp@vYtaUOASMSh3g3aP1WIQKvEiG9RVU@POpeaZ3WF6e8PJp0S6KqCQtdKbbfP2vms7039Y54f951f4Tjbhv@/iDav8YDuYc3Ik4w8)

Works for the standard ASCII range

Explanation:

```c
a=*a?a:b           // If a is empty, point to b instead
*a=*a>70?33:99     // Choose a different value for the 1st character of a,
                   // while giving enough space to increment it without 
                   // going back to its previous value
*a+=*a==*b         // Increment the 1st character of a if the arbitrary
                   // chosen value is equal to the value of the 1st 
                   // character of b
puts(a)            // Outputs a
```

Comment: I'm not sure this can be given a consistent input domain satisfying the rules. What if `*a==255` and `*b==0`?

Comment: You're right. Fixed, at the cost of 8 bytes.

Comment: There. I couldn't let this solution have the same bytecount than the Java one! :-)

Comment: If you don't restrict to printable ASCII then you could use single-digit numbers.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, that would be against this challenge rules.

Comment: Hm I don't understand it that way, see Luis Mendo's question comment. You must be able to input any character you output, but not vice versa.

Comment: Of course, but there is also the first rule: `You may chose your input domain, but it must be composed of at least printable ASCII`. And I don't see characters 0 to 6 (included) as printable ASCII characters, leaving us with only 3 "printable" characters (this is debatable for chars 7 & 8). And I need at least 4 consecutive chars to force a different one for one of the provided strings.

Comment: The first rule means that you have to accept all printable ASCII characters. You can accept whatever other characters you want, otherwise there would be nothing to choose.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <s>115</s> .. 77 bytes

Replaces first char of the first (non-empty) input string with 1,2,3 until no match is found to either input. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##dYxBDoIwEEX3PcVPbTK6wKSww5h4D@MC6JgSsRCLigHOjkVjogtn@d@bl2feTndbVowLZwZV6XgDUwu@ZRU8t4giSDXPcuq2UvU6jVQ8SnGsL/AoHXq9XidjIF2qw95jv4fy2GK3VHpQ8QqHwzDkIX/ajIILW4egl9PVzflujghTO56IQHxu2gfh@xYg/VoFsTMeCNq9bC18kxXs6SW8gfj809@EDjD@pW8hIfEE)

***-9, -12, -9, -8*** bytes all thanks to [GammaFunction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86147/gammafunction)

```
x="${1:-$2}"
for s in {1..3}"${x:1}"
{ [[ $s = @($1|$2) ]]||break;}
echo "$s"
```

(quite an improvement over the [original...](https://gist.github.com/roblogic/c856c9607b5d29ff856d1c45c8807a75))

Comment: Nice method! You can use `=` and `||` in the last line, and use `${x:-empty_fallback}` to remove the starting ternary. Also, you do need quotes on the ending echo for the case of trailing spaces. [Obligatory TIO](https://tio.run/##Pco7CoAwDADQvacIJaAiDhUna09SHPxiFwPqUIg9exQHxwdvHM5NJDqNbFqTtFrpyHMbyrJrbFGwIocBObYVcv2GpLwHJHCABvr@vn/WHxmWaSPQSNouMVw2qSQihkBmgj27Hg "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't figure out how to use "empty fallback" though

Comment: [Here's the TIO link](https://tio.run/##Pco7CoAwDADQvacIJaAiDhUna09SHPxiFwPqUIg9exQHxwdvHM5NJDqNbFqTtFrpyHMbyrJrbFGwIocBObYVcv2GpLwHJHCABvr@vn/WHxmWaSPQSNouMVw2qSQihkBmgj27Hg "Bash – Try It Online"), 94 bytes

Comment: I like what you're going for with the `shift`, [I got it to tie my method](https://tio.run/##Pcc7CoAwDADQvacIGrDFKeJk9STi4Jd2MaAdhLZnj@Dg294y305Ea4wlZWNSup0/gjr40tr6uu5ba0xUPKDHSB1lNY6ADAMgwTSl9Lf5GmFfHUOBXNj98cFmlUWEGGRjOKvwAg "Bash – Try It Online") in [two different methods](https://tio.run/##Pce9CoMwFAbQPU/xoRequPRKp6b2RUKG@keyeKFmKMQ8@y04eLYzfvaguoe4JpCjXHN5371Z5ds0Nnbd62HbNhsZKFLmJxfjHEgwgBjeH8fV/mzGMgVBRVLZ5ReTLaaoKgt0Fmy39Ac "Bash – Try It Online").

Comment: [Whoops, I found another change: `@($1|$2)` pattern matching](https://tio.run/##Dco7CoUwEADAPqdYwoIJYhGxMi/gPcTCL6ZxwWcR2OTsq1PPMv9PkRQ0sutd0eqg2xgf6/rXeWtZUcCInPoGuf1CUeMISBBgMOgythamKWeGfT0JNJL2e4qPL6qIiCOQjeCqnhc "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I never knew about [fallback](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts/122878) and [@-pattern-matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

Comment: [Umm, I.. uh... did some more things](https://tio.run/##dYxBDoIwEEX3PcVPbTK6wKSww5h4D@MC6JgSsRCLigHOjkVjogtn@d@bl2feTndbVowLZwZV6XgDUwu@ZRU8t4giSDXPcuq2UvU6jVQ8SnGsL/AoHXq9XidjIF2qw95jv4fy2GK3VHpQ8QqHwzDkIX/ajIILW4egl9PVzflujghTO56IQHxu2gfh@xYg/VoFsTMeCNq9bC18kxXs6SW8gfj809@EDjD@pW8hIfEE "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
∋l~lℕṫ.&≡ⁿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FHd05dzqOWqQ93rtZTe9S58FHj/v//o5UMDZR0FICkgVLs/wgA)

#### Explanation

There may be a better way to do this, but I've been fighting Brachylog strings for a while now and this solution works.

```
∋           For some element of the input list
 l          get its length
  ~l        That is also the length of
    ℕ       some positive integer
     ṫ      Converting that integer to a string
      .     is the output
       &    Also:
         ⁿ  It is not true, for any X in the input list
        ≡   that the output equals X
```

Outputs strings like `"100"`. If `"100"` is already in the input list, goes to `"101"`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 79 + 1 (-p) = 80 bytes

```perl
$"=<>;chop;$_=length($,=$_)>length$"?$_:$";s/./chr$&+65+$i++/e while/^($"|$,)$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcexCoMwFAXQ3a8o4VKU2L7JDo1R7Ic0gzyaQDDBBFz67X0dPNvJvMdBBMqOk1l9ygbORt4@1bfoLVw3nYOa4Z5QptCdVr/jqh@DRtCa@HL4EJneLdQXfQcSeZXaLFzqL@Ua0lbklv8)

Comment: Fails if the two strings are of different length

Comment: I noticed that.  Just revised it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 17 bytes

```
;B¬£ñl g1 çXÃkU v
```

Repeats the letters `A-Z` to the length of the longer input, removes the values in the input, and get the first item in the array.

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0Kso/FsIGcxIOdYw2tVIHY=&input=WyJhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5eiIsICJBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQSJdCi1R)

### Old solution, 18 bytes

```
;@!UøX}a@ñl g1 çBö
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0AhVfhYfWFA8WwgZzEg50L2&input=WyJCIiwgIiJdCi1R)

Chooses a random character from the alphabet and repeats it to the length of the longer input string, until it is not present in the input.

Comment: Failed for `["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"]`. When running it multiple times, it returned `"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"` (just like my Pyth answer did, until I fixed that)

Comment: It fails for ["D", ""]. if you run it several times you'll get "D"

Comment: Thanks, I figured there were some cases I hadn't tested. Fixed for only +1 byte.

Comment: `Ì` should work in place of `g1 ` for a 2 byte saving (in a 2 element array `g1`=`gJ`) but there appears to be a bug with `Ì` when using `;`.

Comment: @Shaggy Yeah, I think that's cause `J` is no longer `-1` because of the `;` changing it to `,`. That's why I used `1` in the first place.

Comment: Ah, of course, hadn't thought of that being the problem.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 23 bytes

```
q~:A:e>,3,sf*{A\f=:+!}=
```

Takes printable ASCII as input. Outputs either a string of 0's, 1's, or 2's that is the same length as one of the input strings. The logic is that one of those can't be either of the input strings!

[Try it Online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3AA%3Ae%3E%2C3%2Csf*%7BA%5Cf%3D%3A%2B!%7D%3D&input=%5B%22000%22%20%22111%22%5D)

```
q~:A    e# Store input array as var 'A'
:e>,    e# Take the length of the lexicographically greater string in the input array
3,s     e# Generate "012"
f*      e# Repeat each number as many times as the longer string length, yielding something like ["000","111","222"]
{       e# Search array of number strings for first that returns true for this function
A\f=    e# Map each string in the input array to whether it equals the current number string (0,1)
:+!     e# Add up the array of bits and take the logical not. This returns true iff both array values were not equal to the current number string.
}=      e# Return the first number string that returns true.
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on how to return true only if both bits in the array are false (NOR)? Currently, I'm doing `:+!`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <strike>74</strike> 73 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Step Hen

```
def f(x,y,i=1):
 while i*10<10**len(x or y)or str(i)in x+y:i*=2
 print(i)
```

Prints lowest integer with the same length as the first of the inputs that has nonzero length.

Comment: Save a byte with `i` as a default function parameter: `def f(x,y,i=1):`. I think you can save another byte with `while10*i` but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can replace  `while i*10<10**len(x or y)or str(i)in x+y` with `while i<10**~-len(x or y)or str(i)in x+y`  ([72 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcgxCoAgFADQ3VN8nNQM0paIvE2KH0TFhHTp6ubyhpd79SnuY9zWgWNNdolG8ZPA6zFYwEttQnxrsJE1SAU6nzy1MOQYoS39RGE0gVww1pnDMar0QSWlfPw))

Comment: And you can also use recursion to save bytes: `f=lambda x,y,i=1:(i<10**~-len(x or y)or str(i)in x+y)and f(x,y,i*2)or i` ([71 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcsxCoQwEEDRqwypZmIE4zYiepiIBgd0lJgiabx6Vm1@8/hnjushv1L8uLl9mh0kkw2PtkcebKP1XW@LYIIjQKYnVwzIxAKpyuRkBo/fodtXuZyBJaJHZdtOGaWIyh8))

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 77 bytes

```
a=input()
b=ord(a[0][0])+1
if b==ord(a[1][0]):b+=1
print unichr(b)+a[0][1:-1]
```

I think it has some potential. The idea is that it adds 1 to the 1st char in the 1st string, then checks if the other input's 1st char is the same.

**Note, ^ doesn't handle 0 length strings, so it doesn't really work at this length.

Here's a super long solution that works with 0 length

## 146 Bytes

```
a=input()
def c(i):print unichr(ord(a[i][0])+1)+a[i][1:];exit();
for x in range(2):if len(a[x-1])<1:c(x)
if a[0]==a[1]:c(1)
print a[1][0]+a[0][1:]
```

Any improvements would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 94 bytes

```cs
s=>t=>{var r=s!=""?s:t;while(r==s|r==t)r=r.Substring(1).Insert(0,(char)(r[0]+1)+"");return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNb8IwDIbv/AqvlyWCVbDjSroD0qRJTJrGYQfUQ2gNRGrTKU6ZKtbf3jV0A8oq5oM/8ry2HMd0l@U6r7XMkD5kjLAoyWI22A@gsTiVRPB6yNsXZ2SlVTHscpXAi1Sa8SM6iZw9FTqekjVKb0bdoo1hCGsQNYnQinC/kwaMoBvheY/0YIPPrUqRGSHoq3GWG2H8RbFqW9mE@8@a0Fg2HrF4Kw1nZjmOhhM@9DweGLSF0WCCqg4GnaXa/mUEFsnOJCGB6Ai6f3DmOak3@o1/eZI7muT6theXCOQEJVI/vkYzWa7Q8SYpsE@xlikdFD/JFYU1/SMmDl6A6uJw69wAU9qCAgHjoAnT0w39OeqN3brXoYB7/s9FZ7mmPEX/3SiLc6WRrdlx1lJF/LyCIUwizoPudt3lfge@oUwO887k1aD1Vf0N)

Comment: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZBNT8JAEIbv/RVjL3YDNODRsvVAYmKCiZGDB9LD0k5hk3ZrdrYYgvWv1y5VoNjgHOZjn3cmsxPTKC9UUSuRI72LGGGxI4O5s3egsTgTRPByyNsXa2SEkTFsC5nAs5DKY0d0Ell7LFU8JaOlWg@7RRvDEFLgNfHQ8HC/FRo0pxvuug90b4KPjczQ05zTZ@MM01z7i3LVtnoT5j8pQm288dCLN0Kz0ZdejqOB67JAoym1Ah1UdeB0Vmq7lxEYJDMThAS8I@j@wJprpe7wN/7lSWFpUqjbXrxDICvYIfXjazQXuxVa3iQl9ilSkdFB8ZNcURjdP2Ji4QWoLg6XFho8qQxI4DAOmjA93dCfo1qbjX0dcLhj/1x0VigqMvTftDQ4lwq91DvOWsqInVcwgEnEWNDdrrvc78BXFMlh3pm8clpf1d8 "C# (Mono C# compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[k for k in"abc"if k not in b[:1]+a[:1]][0]+(a or b)[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBEoIgEIbvPcUOl3T0kNPNmZ6EPIBCkgomWNHLE@hMk2Yc4N/v2@WwvTW1kkfH4QRn15KOVgRISnPcAFcDNCAkIrREgvsslfE1UJxnRULCXeBDkUQEfCuNcZYXrh@ENBGPkGHaoBTmN453H1GpgCsl90tuGehgLNMrvok7YikLwoeRLRQnrZ7UHDaVGVZDWaALMrX9EL@NsJBv7OuK8Ustrk3bSdXfBm3G@@NpX9PA37P4pBQoRVR45t4)

Picks the first character of `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"` which neither string begins with - all three characters can't be the first character of one of two strings. The first character of `a` is then replaced with that character, unless `a` is empty, in which case the first character in `b` is replaced instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 16 bytes

```
T#iN#*g&iNIg++ii
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/RDnTT1krXS3TzzNdWzsz8////zmpeeklGbrFmRX/M/MKSkuKAQ)

Increments the number `i` until `i` has the same length as one of the inputs and does not equal either of the inputs, and then prints `i`. Takes about 30 seconds on TIO to output `100000` for length-six input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 16 bytes

```
YMXgRXX9WyNg--yy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0jciPSgiwjK80i9dV7ey8v///7oF/y0tLYDYEgA)

Different approach from [my first submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182203/16766) (and much faster):

```
   g              List of command-line args     ["abc" "9999"]
    R             Replace
     XX           any character (regex `.`)
       9          with 9                        ["999" "9999"]
 MX               Get the max                   9999
Y                 Yank it into y variable
        W         Loop while
         yNg      y is in the cmdline args:
            --y    Decrement y
               y  Output y                      9998
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>(a[0]&1^b[0]&2^7)+(a||b).slice(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/e9m@z/R1i7J1k4jMdogVs0wLglEGcWZa2prJNbUJGnqFedkJqdqGGr@T87PK87PSdXLyU/XcNNQSlbS1FBS0tT8DwA)

Obvious source the 3rd byte

Answer (score -1):

## Haskell, 41 bytes

```
n[]_=[]
n _[]=[]
n(i:c)(h:t)=succ i:n c t
```

Comment: The empty string isn't a valid output if one of the inputs is an empty string...

Comment: It fails if the string starts with `'\1114111'`.